# Test a number for narcissism

Tags: code-golf, math, decision-problem

A [Narcissistic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) is a number which is the sum of its own digits, each raised to the power of the number of digits.

For example, take \$153\$ (3 digits):

> \$1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 153\$

\$1634\$:

> \$1^4 + 6^4 + 3^4 + 4^4 = 1634 = 1 + 1296 + 81 + 256 = 1634\$

**The Challenge:**

Your code must take input from the user and output True or False depending upon whether the given number is a Narcissistic Number.

Error checking for text strings or other invalid inputs is not required. 1 or 0 for the output is acceptable. Code that simply generates a list of Narcissistic Numbers, or checks the user input against a hardcoded list, does not qualify.

[**OEIS A005188**](https://oeis.org/A005188)

Comment: Is it ok if I output `True` if it's such a number, but anything else (in this case the number itself) if not?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### APL (15)

```
∆≡⍕+/(⍎¨∆)*⍴∆←⍞
```

Outputs `1` if true and `0` if false.

Explanation:

- `∆←⍞`: read a line (as characters), store in `∆`
- `(⍎¨∆)*⍴∆`: evaluate each character in `∆` and raise it to the power `⍴∆`
- `∆≡⍕+/`: see if the input equals the string representation of the sum of these

Comment: what did i just read

Comment: @LagWagon God's language

Answer (score 21):

#### GolfScript, 16 characters

```
~.`:s{48-s,?-}/!
```

Input must be given on STDIN, output is 0 or 1 indicating non-narcissistic / narcissistic number.

Explanation of the code:

```
~              # Evaluate the input to get a number
.              # Accumulator (initially the number itself)
`:s            # Convert number to string and assign to variable s
{              # Loop over characters of the string
  48-          # Reduce character value by 48
  s,           # Push length of input number
  ?            # Power
  -            # Subtract result from accumulator
}/
!              # Not! (i.e. iff accumulator was zero it was a narcissistic number)
```

Comment: I did a double-take on `` ~.` `` but it seems impossible to improve. Nice one.

Answer (score 15):

## Mathematica, 43 chars

```
Tr[#^Length@#&@IntegerDigits@#]==#&@Input[]
```

Answer (score 14):

### Perl, 38 characters

```
perl -lpe '$@=y///c;$s+=$_**$@for/./g;$_=$_==$s'
```

A pretty straightforward implementation.

Here's a slightly different version that fits in 35 characters:

```
perl -lpe '$@=y///c;$s+=$_**$@for/./g;$_-=$s'
```

This version outputs a *false* value if the input is narcissistic, otherwise it outputs a (Perl-accepted) true value. One might argue that this backwards version falls within the limits of the challenge description, but upon reflection I decided not to. I'm not that desperate to improve my score. Yet.

Comment: “Error checking for text strings or other invalid inputs is not required.” – So why not suppose the input will be valid number, without trailing newline? `echo -n 153 | perl -pe '…'` will work without `-l`.

Comment: I think so long as you define what your true and false outputs are, it should be legal

Comment: Strictly speaking, the wording of the challenge text does leave a bit of ambiguity as to what True/False or 0/1 should mean, so I'll let this one pass. A different script of equal length that returns true for narcissistic values would have the advantage, though.

Comment: Same idea but shorter: `perl -pe'map$s+=$_**@y,@y=/./g;$_=$_==$s'`

Answer (score 13):

## J, 23 chars

```
(".=+/@("."0^#))(1!:1)1
```

`(1!:1)1` is keyboard input (returning a string).

`".` converts input to a number; `"0` specifies a rank (dimension) of 0, in other words, taking each character and converting it to a number.

`^` is the power function and `#` is the length function, thus taking each digit to the power of the length of the string (equivalently, the number of digits).

`+/` is just sum, and `=` is comparing the sum and number.

Comment: "Your code must **take input from the user** and output True or False depending upon whether the given number is a Narcissistic Number." (emphasis mine)

Comment: @JanDvorak My bad -- added keyboard input.

Answer (score 13):

## Ruby, 34+5=39

With command-line flags

```
ruby -nlaF|
```

Run

```
p eval [$F,0]*"**#{~/$/}+"+"==#$_"
```

Outputs true or false.

Comment: This may be the most Ruby flags I've ever seen in a legitimate code golf :P

Answer (score 11):

### R, <s>71</s> <s>69</s> <s>66</s> <s>56</s> 48

Reduced by 8 bytes thanks to [@Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)! The idea was to perform the integer division before the modulo operation.

```
i=nchar(a<-scan()):0;a==sum((a%/%10^i%%10)^i[1])
```

**(3-year) old version with corresponding explanation:**

```
i=nchar(a<-scan()):1;a==sum(((a%%10^i)%/%10^(i-1))^i[1])
```

`a<-scan()` takes a number (integer, real,...) as input (say `153` for the example).
`i` becomes a vector containing 3 to 1 (the number of characters of `a` being 3).
`%%` is vectorized so `a%%10^i` means `a` modulo 1000, 100 and 10: it therefore gives `153, 53, 3`.
`(a%%10^i)%/%10^(i-1)` is the integer division of that vector by 100, 10, 1: therefore, `1, 5, 3`.
We elevate that with the first element of `i` which is the number of characters (here digits) of `a`, i. e. `3`, thus giving a vector containing `1, 125, 27` that we `sum` and compares to `a`.

Comment: Does the integer division always round down? Otherwise, you could run into problems with e.g. 370 (a narcissistic number) turning into 4,7,0 (which would return false) or 270 (non-narcissistic) turning into 3,7,0 (returning true).

Comment: Integer division doesn't round... The integer division of 370 by 100 is 3 with the remainder of 70 and not 3.70.

Comment: [48 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9M2LzkjsUgj0Ua3ODkxT0NT08rAOtHWtrg0V0MjUVVf1dAgLlMVSGrGZUYbxmr@/w8A "R – Try It Online")...somebody bumped this to the homepage!

Answer (score 9):

## Python 3, 56 bytes

Not very obfuscated, but a simple solution.

```
s = input()
print(int(s)==sum(int(c)**len(s)for c in s))
```

Comment: The `[` and `]` are unnecessary, and you can drop the space in front of `for` too, so: `sum(int(c)**len(s)for c in s)`

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You can save two characters by removing the spaces in `s = input()` and another one by moving this to 2.7 where `print` isn't a function.

Comment: Good point, edited.

Comment: I think you should point out that adding braces to `print` (hence one character more) would make this a valid Python 2.x and Python 3.x solution.

Comment: In Python 2.7 first row must by `s=raw_input()`

Comment: You're absolutely right. Rather than add the four characters, I'll just switch it back to Python3 where it was 57 chars.

Comment: Was workin on the same approach:(

Comment: [Fixed your byte count.](https://ethproductions.github.io/bytes/?e=ascii&t=s%20%3D%20input%28%29%0Aprint%28int%28s%29%3D%3Dsum%28int%28c%29**len%28s%29for%20c%20in%20s%29%29) Also, you can remove those 2 spaces on the first line.

Comment: Wouldn't `lambda s:int(s)==sum(int(c)**len(s)for c in s)` work?

Comment: You can actually get [43 bytes](https://tio.run/##RZDBbsMwCIbvewrUk135YGxscKU8yTapXbdokdK0SrLDnj6DTNouCPg/@BGP7/XzPqWt71628XJ7e7/Aclq67rx83dwwre7qj8fxY3KL7@8zXGGYYPHn7TGbeBlH17tlnd3gPRgwGPCMAVKAHIAClAA1AAeQAC0AFm1njhYUo6gK1qygpGgIsQ1ptCJxUr3lKHtTxEBkQk66lxJGQeMkamJkSzWjSokqSyzxL1MvkdIysRlSLYi7H3HKuTTWmZKJGknWcxumJmW/VcfVn9nOygkrRWrVFv8X@Or90@9HenfAUg7ebz8 "Python 2 – Try It Online") using Python 2

Answer (score 8):

### PHP, <s>80</s> <s>74</s> 66 chars

Very straightforward PHP solution:

```
<?for(;$i<$l=strlen($a=$argv[1]);)$s+=pow($a[$i++],$l);echo$s==$a;
```

It assumes `error_reporting` doesn't include notices, otherwise quite a few extra characters will be needed to initialize `$s=0;` and `$i=0`.

Thx @manatwork for shortening many chars.

Comment: Don't assign $a and $l in separate statements. `<?for($i=0;$i<$l=strlen($a=$argv[1]);$i++){$s+=pow($a[$i],$l);}echo$s==$a;` is shorter.

Comment: As you already have a statement which generate a notice, just add another: remove the loop control variable initialization. Incrementing the loop control variable also not need to be a standalone statement. And the braces are definitely not needed: `<?for(;$i<$l=strlen($a=$argv[1]);)$s+=pow($a[$i++],$l);echo$s==$a;`.

Comment: @manatwork: Thank you for the warm welcome to codegolf :)

Comment: Can be golfed to this `for(;$i<$l=strlen($a=$argn);)$s+=$a[$i++]**$l;echo$s==$a;`

Answer (score 8):

## K, <strike>24</strike> 23

```
{x=+/xexp["I"$'a]@#a:$x}
```

Shaved 1 char with reordering

```
{x=+/{x xexp#x}"I"$'$x}
```

Answer (score 8):

## Dc: 48 characters

```
[1pq]Sr?d0rdZSz[d10/r10%lz^rSh+Lhd0!=c]dScx+=r0p
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ dc -e '[1pq]Sr?d0rdZSz[d10/r10%lz^rSh+Lhd0!=c]dScx+=r0p' <<< '153'
1

bash-4.1$ dc -e '[1pq]Sr?d0rdZSz[d10/r10%lz^rSh+Lhd0!=c]dScx+=r0p' <<< '1634'
1

bash-4.1$ dc -e '[1pq]Sr?d0rdZSz[d10/r10%lz^rSh+Lhd0!=c]dScx+=r0p' <<< '2013'
0
```

Comment: Never actually used `dc`, save for frantic typos in attempt to write `cd`

Answer (score 8):

## R, 53 bytes

```r
sum(scan(t=gsub("(.)","\\1 ",x<-scan()))^nchar(x))==x
```

The `gsub` regex inserts spaces in between characters, so that the `scan` function will be able to read the number into a vector of digits.

Comment: +1 i would have never thought of doing that, it's brilliant.

Answer (score 6):

## Kona, 18

...

```
{x=+/(0$'u)^#u:$x}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Powershell, <strike>75</strike> <strike>63</strike> <strike>62</strike> <strike>60</strike> 58**

Edit: Updated per @Iszi's comment <strike>(note: this counts on `$x` not existing)</strike>

Edit: Added @Danko's changes.

```
[char[]]($x=$n=read-host)|%{$x-="$_*"*$n.length+1|iex};!$x
```

**<strike>58</strike> 56 chars**

If input is limited to 10 digits (includes all int32)

```
($x=$n=read-host)[0..9]|%{$x-="$_*"*$n.length+1|iex};!$x
```

Comment: I was wondering if someone was going to do PowerShell before I did.

Comment: Save 12 characters by adding another variable `$x` and using `+=` to do your summing instead of `measure -sum` then test `$x-eq$n`.

Comment: @Iszi - Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer.

Comment: For future reference, if `measure -sum` is ever actually necessary, you could get away with just `measure -s`.

Comment: More tips for PowerShell you might want to check out. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/191/9387 I'm going to have to go edit some of my other answers, now.

Comment: 62 chars solution that doesn't count on $x not existing: `$x=$n=read-host;$n-split''|%{$x-=[math]::pow($_,$n.length)};!$x`   You set `$x=$n initially, subtract from `$x` in the loop, and then compare it to `0` at the end.

Comment: 61 chars: `($x=$n=read-host)-split''|%{$x-=[math]::pow($_,$n.length)};!$x`

Comment: @DankoDurbić, Nice! Type coercion often comes in handy with PoSh code golfing. I only get 62 though when I run `'($x=$n=read-host)-split""|%{$x-=[math]::pow($_,$n.length)};!$x'.length`

Comment: @Rynant Good point. I ran your length check in PowerShell and came up with 62 as well. When running a length check similarly against the *actual* script, it comes up 61. This is probably because of how PowerShell handles the `''` which you replaced with `''`. I took the original script into Excel to double-check with `=LEN("($x=$n=read-host)-split''|%{$x-=[math]::pow($_,$n.length)};!$x")` and got 62 also. Of course, we could always count it manually - but who really does that?

Comment: Correction: "...how PowerShell handles the `''` which you replaced (appropriately, for the purposes of counting characters) with `""`."

Comment: You can shorten `[math]::pow` with mutiplication. For example, `[math]::pow(2,3)` is `"1*2*2*2"|iex`, or generally `[math]::pow($a,$b)` is `"1"+"*$a"*$b|iex`, which is two characters shorter. With this little trick, I get `[char[]]($x=$n=read-host)|%{$x-="1"+"*$_"*$n.length|iex};!$x`  which should be 60 characters, if I'm counting right. This doesn't quite work with `-split''` because split returns empty strings at the beginning and the end (why?) `"123"-split''` is actually `"","1","2","3",""`.

Comment: @DankoDurbić I don't know why `-split''` does that, but that's why my [Keith Number Checker](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15243/9387) pipes it to `?{$_}`. I used to use `?{$_-ne''}` but Rynant pointed out that (for some reason I don't understand either) `-ne''` is not needed. I like that, by sending `[char[]]` objects through `iex`, you're completely side-stepping the issue of object type - in fact, you're leveraging it to your advantage to build out the exponent equations! I'll have to remember that!

Comment: @DankoDurbić Thanks, updated again. @Iszi - `?{$_}` works because the result of the ScriptBlock for the `Where-Object` CmdLet is coerced to a bool, and empty strings evaluate as False (see `[bool]''`). You have to be careful when filtering integers because `0` evaluates to False (try `0,1,2|?{$_}` vs `'0','1','2'|?{$_}`)

Comment: @Rynant Great information. So, I just have to keep in mind only to use filtering like that when working on numbers as strings, not integers, and I'm good?

Comment: Just realized that you can replace the `{$x-="1"+"*$_"*$n.length|iex}` part with `{$x-="$_*"*$n.length+1|iex}` which saves another two characters.

Comment: Since PowerShell's default number type is int32, are your solutions really any different in limitations?

Answer (score 5):

### Python 2.x - 51

Same concept as crazedgremlin's solution for Python 3.x:

```
s=input();print s==sum(int(c)**len(`s`)for c in`s`)
```

Answer (score 4):

### C - <strike>97</strike> 93 characters

```
a,b;main(c){scanf("%d",&c);b=c;for(;c;c/=10)a+=pow(c%10,(int)log10(b)+1);printf("%d",a==b);}
```

With indentation:

```
a,b;
main(c) { 
  scanf("%d",&c);
  b=c;
  for(;c;c/=10)
    a+=pow(c%10,(int)log10(b)+1);
  printf("%d",a==b);
}
```

Comment: You don't have to define `int` for global variables.

Comment: Woah. You're reading the input into `argc`.

Comment: Also, shouldn't having to do `-lm` at compile-time count +1 byte?

Comment: @Blacksilver the `-lm` flag is not required for C89 compilers.

Comment: Aha. Learn a new thing every day.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 7 bytes

```
DSDgmOQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fJdglPdc/8P9/Q1NjAA)

-2 bytes thanks to @daHugLenny

Comment: You can replace `§1ô` with `S`

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell 2010 - 76 characters

```
main=do x<-getLine;print$(==x)$show$sum$map((^length x).(+(-48)).fromEnum)x
```

Comment: You shouldn't post the number of ms to run the code, but the number of chars you used. ;)

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, 64 chars

```
for((a=$1;a>0;s+=(a%10)**${#1},a/=10));do :; done;echo $[s==$1]
```

<strike>a=$1;p=${#a};for((;a>0;a/=10));do s=$((s+(a%10)**p));done;echo $((s==$1))</strike>

Comment: You are using variable p in a single place, so no need for it. You can move the initialization of variable a into the `for` to spare its separate `;`: `for((a=$1;a>0;a/=10));do s=$[s+(a%10)**${#1}];done;echo $[s==$1]`.

Comment: By moving the evaluation into the `for` one more character can be shortened: `for((a=$1;a>0;s+=(a%10)**${#1},a/=10));do :; done;echo $[s==$1]`.

Comment: Oh, curious! I tried something like that, but it didn't work. Curious what went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

## Awk: <s>40</s> 39 characters

```awk
{for(;i<NF;)s+=$(i+++1)**NF;$0=$0==s}1
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ awk -F '' '{for(;i<NF;)s+=$(i+++1)**NF;$0=$0==s}1' <<< '153'
1

bash-4.1$ awk -F '' '{for(;i<NF;)s+=$(i+++1)**NF;$0=$0==s}1' <<< '1634'
1

bash-4.1$ awk -F '' '{for(;i<NF;)s+=$(i+++1)**NF;$0=$0==s}1' <<< '2013'
0
```

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript - <del>70</del> 58 characters

```
for(i in a=b=prompt())b-=Math.pow(a[i],a.length)
alert(!b)
```

> **Note:**
>
> If you're testing this in your dev console on Stack Exchange, be aware that there are a number of non-standard properties added to `String.prototype` that will break this solution, such as `String.prototype.formatUnicorn`. Please be sure to test in a clean environment, such as on `about:blank`.

Comment: I count 70 characters there.

Comment: @manatwork, whoops, forgot to count the newline.

Comment: Great trick that decrementation!

Comment: it always returns `true` for me, regardless of input

Comment: @koko, I've added a note to explain why you're receiving incorrect results.

Comment: You can save some bytes by using the ** operator instead of Math.pow

Answer (score 3):

### Lua (101 chars)

Lua isn't known for being concise, but it was fun to try anyway.

```
for n in io.lines()do l,s=n:len(),0 for i=1,l do d=n:byte(i)s=s+(d-48)^l end print(s==tonumber(n))end
```

Improvements welcome.

Comment: As it is not required that your program can handle and process a list of numbers, I would not use bytes to implement that functionality. Replacing the loop `for n in io.lines()do [...]end` with `n=io.read()` saves some bytes ([TIO](https://goo.gl/Ur7xG4)).

Answer (score 3):

## Delphi - 166

```
uses System.SysUtils,math;var i,r,l:integer;s:string;begin r:=0;readln(s);l:=length(s);for I:=1to l do r:=round(r+power(strtoint(s[i]),l));writeln(inttostr(r)=s);end.
```

#### With indent

```
uses System.SysUtils,math;
var
  i,r,l:integer;
  s:string;
begin
  r:=0;
  readln(s);
  l:=length(s);
  for I:=1to l do
    r:=round(r+power(strtoint(s[i]),l));
  writeln(inttostr(r)=s);
end.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java - 84 bytes

```
(a,l)->{int s=0;for(byte c:a.getBytes())s+=Math.pow(c-48,l);return a.equals(""+s);};
```

Non-lambda version: 101 bytes:

```
boolean n(String a,int l){int s=0;for(byte c:a.getBytes())s+=Math.pow(c-48,l);return a.equals(""+s);}
```

Called like this:

```
interface X {
    boolean n(String a, int l);
}

static X x = (a,l)->{int s=0;for(byte c:a.getBytes())s+=Math.pow(c-48,l);return a.equals(""+s);};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(n("153",3));
    System.out.println(n("1634",4));
    System.out.println(n("123",3));
    System.out.println(n("654",3));
}
```

Returns:

```
true
true
false
false
```

Comment: You can remove the parenthesis around the lambda arguments, `a,l->` works exactly the same.

Comment: I know you've answer this almost a year ago, but you can golf two bytes: `(a,l)->` can be `a->l->` and `byte` can be `int`: [`a->l->{int s=0;for(int c:a.getBytes())s+=Math.pow(c-48,l);return a.equals(""+s);}`](https://tio.run/##lY4xT8MwEIX3/opTJlttLCBphQjJ0AGJoVNHxHC4bnBwbGNfiqKqvz2kIoDEVE43vHt3T/c1eMDUeWWb3dugW@8CQTN6oiNtxL6zkrSz4mESxUwajBE2qO1xBhAJSUv4Xt9vKWhbL36NR0uqVmEBa@eMQltVIKGEAdPKpNVRW4JYXhV7F9hZyzsUtaJ1TyoyzuO83CC9Cu8@mEzz24XhRVDUBQso1HuHJrIkmUdenIZixBnbdy9mJJrADk7voB1h2RfZ0zNgqCOHM/y5tn0k1QrXkfDjARnLpEDvTc@S62WW8GnIOC8uiayy/CeTX5i5@feb1TL/GznNTsMn)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>14</s> <s>9</s> 7 bytes

```
¶ì_xpZÊ
```

[Try it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=tuxfeHBayg==&input=MTUz)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of integer `U`.

```
ì_
```

Convert `U` to an array of digits (`ì`), pass it through a function and convert back to an integer after.

```
xpZÊ
```

Reduce by addition (`x`), raising each element to the power (`p`) of the length (`Ê`) of the array in the process.

```
¶
```

Check if the result is strictly equal to `U`.

Comment: I think `¥U¬®n pUlÃx` would work for 11 bytes ;)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
f⁰Le∑=
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C6%9BI%3B%E2%81%B0Le%E2%88%91%3D&inputs=153&header=&footer=)

```
f      # Map each digit to integer
   e   # (for each) to the power of 
 ⁰L    # Input length
    ∑  # Is sum...
     = # Equal to
       # (Implicit input)?
```

-2 thx to lyxal.

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJMdmXiiJE9IiwiIiwiMTYzNCJd) for 5 bytes

Answer (score 2):

### F# - 92 chars

```
let n=stdin.ReadLine()
n|>Seq.map(fun x->pown(int x-48)n.Length)|>Seq.sum=int n|>printf"%b"
```

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp - <strike>116</strike> 102 characters

```
(defun f(m)(labels((l(n)(if(> n 0)(+(expt(mod n 10)(ceiling(log m 10)))(l(floor n 10)))0)))(= m(l m))))
```

Formatted:

```
(defun f(m)
  (labels((l(n)
            (if(> n 0)
               (+(expt(mod n 10)(ceiling(log m 10)))
                 (l(floor n 10)))
               0)))
    (=(l m)m)))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Smalltalk - <strike>102</strike> 99 characters

```
[:n|a:=n asString collect:[:e|e digitValue]as:Array.^n=(a collect:[:each|each raisedTo:a size])sum]
```

At the Workspace, send `value:` with the number, and Print It.

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 117

```
using System.Linq;class A{int Main(string[] a){return a[0].Select(c=>c-'0'^a[0].Length).Sum()==int.Parse(a[0])?1:0;}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Retina, 118 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
.*
$0 $0¶$0
(?<=^\d*)\d
x
(?=.*$)
¶
0¶

\d+
$*
¶(1+)
¶$1 $1
{`^x ?

}s`(?<=x.*)1(?=1* (1+))
$1
 1*

1¶1
11
^(1*)¶+\1\b
```

[**Try it online**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LioKJDAgJDDCtiQwCig_PD1eXGQqKVxkCngKKD89LiokKQrCtgowwrYKClxkKwokKgrCtigxKykKwrYkMSAkMQp7YF54ID8KCn1zYCg_PD14LiopMSg_PTEqICgxKykpCiQxCiAxKgoKMcK2MQoxMQpeKDEqKcK2K1wxXGI&input=MTYzNA)

---

**Explanation**

```
.*                          # Copy number 3 times. For Length, Unary, and Digits
$0 $0¶$0
(?<=^\d*)\d                 # Convert first copy to x's (Length)
x
(?=.*$)                     # Split up digits of last copy, each on their own line
¶
0¶                          # Remove zeros, because they leave blank lines

\d+                         # Convert to unary
$*
¶(1+)                       # Duplicate each separated digit
¶$1 $1
{`^x ?                      # While x's exist, remove an x ...

}s`(?<=x.*)1(?=1* (1+))     #     and multiply each value by the digit (nth power)
$1
 1*                         # Remove original digits

1¶1                         # Remove lines between digits
11
^(1*)¶+\1\b                 # Match if values are equal
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>68</s> 66 bytes

```
d 0=[]
d n=mod n 10:d(div n 10)
sum.(\a->map(^length a)a).d>>=(==)
```

Usage:

```
*Main> sum.(\a->map(^length a)a).d>>=(==) $ 1634
True
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
D*L$S=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@@i5aMSbPv//39DU2MA)

```
D        Get the digits of the input
 *L$     Raise each element to power of its length
    S    Sum
     =   Equals input?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 8 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Tacit prefix function taking the input as a string.

```apl
⍎≡1⊥⍎¨*≢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHvX2POhcaPupaCmQdWqH1qHMRUEJB3dDUWJ0LTJtAaDNjYxjDRB0A)

`⍎` is the evaluated argument

`≡` identical to

`1⊥` the sum (lit. convert from base-1) of

`⍎¨` the evaluated characters (i.e the digits)

`*` raised to the power of

`≢` the tally of characters (i.e. digits)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 32 bytes

```julia
!n=sum(digits(n).^ndigits(n))==n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVDLasQwDLz3K7S3BMxiPWzJh3xJ2ZbQLiUlNaXOQv8@K@ewexEjaUYz6Pu2LjP@7/upTu32M3wuX8vWhjqe3@oDj9NU9@3atvePuV0bTPCKASgAB5AAKUAOoAEsQAmAycessRenSfQNZnaiUewU0S7y2htS8n3haMfQrBNRBZX8rhBGw86z6KAzC2VGX5FktZjiA7mXWSos2g0lJ8TDT5SYU1HXJBYpYuxxC1KxdGR1ufur9lhMmCVKyf3ws8HLy@/fUrdhXtfhfHr@Yhz3Ow)

Answer (score 2):

## Uiua, 12 bytes

```
=/+ⁿ⧻.-@0°⋕.
```

[Try it](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAgPS8r4oG_4qe7Li1AMMKw4ouVLgoKRiAxCkYgMTIzCkYgMTUzCkYgMTYzMwpGIDE2MzQK)

Explanation:

```
-@0°⋕.
```

Convert the number to a list of digits.

```
ⁿ⧻.
```

Raise each to the power of the list's length.

```
=/+
```

Is this list's sum equal to the original?

Answer (score 1):

Not the sortest but my take.

## Python 2.7: 59 <s>60</s> chars

```
a=input();(0,1)[sum(int(i)**len(str(a))for i in str(a))==a]
```

Comment: It's supposed to output true or false (also needs to take input).

Comment: @Timtech or 1 and 0

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu Still needs to take input.

Comment: @lszi now should work ;)

Comment: Yes, it seems to work now.

Comment: For converting boolean value to integer `int(BoolExpr)` is shorter than `(0,1)[BoolExpr]`. `+(BoolExpr)` even shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth/blob/master/pyth.py), 13 characters

```
JwqvJsm^vdlJJ
```

Explanation:

```
Jw                J=input()
       ^vdlJ      eval(d)^len(J)
      m^vdlJJ     map each character in J to eval(d)^len(J)
  qvJsm^vdlJJ     print(eval(J)==sum(map each character in J to eval(d)^len(J)))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Python, 90 Bytes**

```
a,z=input(),[]
for x in list(a):z.append(int(x)**len(a))
print(1 if sum(z)==int(a) else 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>252</s> <s>220</s> <s>225</s> 111 bytes

```c
int f(char *a){for(int i=0;i<strlen(a);i++){r+=((int)a[i]);for(int j=0;j<strlen(a);j++)r*=r;}return r==(int)a;}
```

Returns 0 if `false` and 1 if `true`. Thanks to @DrMcMoylex for saving many bytes and explaining stuff.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Some tips for you: 1) You have a lot of unnecessary whitespace. You could remove most of the newlines and spaces/indentation and it would still run fine. 2) A function is allowed, so you could return '1' or '0' instead of printing it. That would save a lot of bytes. 3) Since you're only doing one thing in each 'for' loop, you could join the inner code with the loop itself. For example: `for(int i=0;i<strlen(a);r+=a[i++])`

Comment: @DrMcMoylex How would you know the output if I used `return`? There's nothing printed in the terminal...

Comment: You could write a small wrapper to print the return value of the function

Comment: @DrMcMoylex Using `printf` instead of making a new function uses less bytes, I believe. Thanks for the welcome, btw!

Comment: No that's not what I meant. I meant you don't need to print anything. Returning is a valid form of output. You could print the return value for testing, but your submission can just be a function. Then you won't need to parse input or print the output. For example `int f(char *a){for(int i=0;i<strlen(a);i++){r+=((int)a[i]);for(int j=0;j<strlen(a);j++)r*=r;}return r==(int)a;}`

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 56 characters

`n=prompt();n.split('').reduce((a,i)=>a+i**n.length,0)==n`

This makes use of the exponentiation operator, so you have to be running a modern browser for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 27 +3 = 30 bytes

Run with `-F`.  Older versions of Perl might require you to run with `-nF` instead, if `-F` does not imply `-n`.

```
grep$;+=$_**$#F,@F;say$_==$
```

Prints 1 if narcissistic, prints nothing otherwise.

(thanks to @Dada for byte-count correction, and for -2 bytes)

Comment: `grep$;+=$_**$#F,@F;say$_==$` to save two bytes (`$;` instead of `$a`, and `grep...,@F` instead of `grep{...}@F`). However, note that `-F` counts as 3 bytes (`-`, `F` and a space).

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 85 bytes

```clojure
#(= n(int(reduce +(vec(map#(Math/pow(Character/digit % 10)(count(str n)))(str n))))))
```

Usage is like so:

```
(#(...) {number})
```

Ungolfed (with commentary):

```clojure
(defn narcissistic [n]
  ; The function is altered a bit, to improve readability.
  ; The double arrow means that a result of a function will get "chained"
  ; onto the next function as the last argument:
  ; (->> 1 (* 2) (+ 3)) -> (->> (* 2 1) (+ 3)) -> (+ 3 (* 2 1))
  (->> n
    ; Converts it to a string, for the next function
    ; 153 -> "153"
    str
    ; Converts the string to an array of characters,
    ; which is then raised to the powers equal to the length of the number:
    ; 153 -> (1.0 125.0 27.0)
    (map (#(Math/pow (Character/digit % 10) (count (str n)))))
    ; Converts the array to a vector (reducing only works with vectors)
    ; (1.0 125.0 27.0) -> [1.0 125.0 27.0]
    vec
    ; Reduces the vector by adding them
    ; [1.0 125.0 27.0] -> 153.0
    (reduce +)
    ; Turns that into an integer
    ; 153.0 -> 153
    int
    ; Checks if that's equal to the original n
    ; 153 = 153 -> true
    (= n)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge 98, 58 bytes

```
1-00p&:a\v
 00g1+00p>:a%\a/:!kv
 \:9`kv00gk:00gk*+>
@.!-$<
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/#xZst4)

I'm sure this can be golfed further. I will take another look at it and add an explanation later...

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 16 bytes

```
L,BDdbLdXBcB`sA=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99Hx8klJcknJcIp2Smh2NH2////hmbGJgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 22 bytes

```
{x~+/*/'(#:r)#'r:10\x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqrqiTltfS19dQ9mqSFNZvcjK0CCmovZ/moKhqTEXkDQzNgFRpkb/AQ)

Comment: there's no need for a `:` after a monadic verb, `#:r` -> `#r`

Comment: Can get it down to 18 bytes with `{x~+/*/&[10\x]'$x}`

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 51 bytes

```
ns>lS0sp11[ppl:Isp>l<ysp>l<sp>,^<l`sy,=!]>&+s<<l=fp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@v2C4n2KC4wNAwuqAgx8qzuMAux6YSTAIJnTibnITiSh1bxVg7Ne1iG5sc27SC//8NzYwB)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
lg;?↔z^ᵐ+?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/Pyfd2v5R25SquIdbJ2jb//9vbGRoZmJgYmlmaggA)

The predicate succeeds if the input is an Armstrong number and fails if it is not. If run as a full program, success prints `true.` and failure prints `false.`

```
lg;?↔z     A list of pairs [a digit of input, the length of input].
      ^ᵐ   A list of numbers where each is a digit of the input raised to the power of its length.
        +  The sum of those numbers.
         ? Attempt to unify that sum with the input.
```

Comment: Originally, this was nine bytes, but I realized that if I gave it a number more than nine digits long it would stop acting correctly, as previously I hadn't put `g` in there and it worked by virtue of single-digit lengths being length-1 sequences of themselves.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 5 bytes

```
Lᵛ*∑=
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCJM4bWbKuKIkT0iLCIiLCIxNTMiLCIzLjQuMiJd)
cool

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 5.9, 82 bytes

```swift
let f={n in"\(n+0)".reduce(0){i,y in"\(n)".reduce(1){x,_ in Int("\(y)")!*x}+i}==n}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2.7 - 57 chars

```
i=`input()`
print`sum(map(lambda x:int(x)**len(i),i))`==i
```

There is a shorter Python answer, but I might as well toss in my contribution.

```
i=`input()`
```

`i` is set to `input()` surrounded by backticks (which is surprisingly hard to type through SE's markdown interpreter). Surrounding `x` with backticks is equivalent to `str(x)`. `[backtick]input()[backtick]` saves two characters over `raw_input()` in any case where we can assume the input is an int, which we're allowed to do:

> Error checking for text strings or other invalid inputs is not required.

Once `i` is a string containing the user's input, the next line is run. I'll explain this one from the inside out:

```
map(lambda x:int(x)**len(i),i)
```

`map` is a function in Python that takes a function and an iterable as arguments and returns a list of each item in the iterable after having the function applied to it. Here I'm defining an anonymous function `lambda x` which converts `x` to a string and raises it to the power of the length of `i`. This `map` will return a list of each character in the string `i` raised to the correct power, and even nicely converts it to an int for us.

```
`sum(map(lambda x:int(x)**len(i),i))`
```

Here I take the sum of each value in the list returned from the `map`. If this sum is equal to the original input, we have a narcissistic number. To check this, we either have to convert this sum to a string or the input to an int. `int()` is two more characters than two backticks, so we convert this to a string the same way we did with the input.

```
print`sum(map(lambda x:int(x)**len(i),i))`==i
```

Compare it to `i` and print the result, and we're done.

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 115 bytes

```
(let*((l(number->string n))(g(string-length l))(m(for/sum((i l))(expt(string->number(string i))g))))(if(= m n)1 0))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f n)
  (let* ((l (number->string n))
         (g (string-length l))
         (m (for/sum ((i l))
              (expt (string->number(string i)) g))))
    (if (= m n) 1 0)))
```

Testing:

```
(f 153)
(f 1634)
(f 123)
(f 654)
```

Output:

```
1
1
0
0
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](//github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes (non-competing)

```
D*DL$S⁼
```

[Try it online!](//jelly.tryitonline.net#code=RCpETCRT4oG8&args=MTUz)

Or alternatively (uses 2 chains):

```
Dµ*LS⁼Ḍ
```

Explanation of the first code:

```
 D* DL$S⁼  Main link (monadic). Arguments: z
⁸          (implicit) z
 D         List of digits of z
   ⁸       (implicit) z
    D      List of digits of z
     L     Length of z
      $    Last two links as a monad
  *        Exponentiation with base x and exponent y
       S   Sum of z
         ⁸ (implicit) z
        ⁼  Check if x equals y
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 103 Bytes

Golfed:

```
bool N(int n){double a=0;foreach(var d in n+""){a+=Math.Pow(int.Parse(d+""),n+"".Length);}return a==n;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
public bool N(int n)
{
  double a = 0;

  foreach (var digit in n.ToString())
  {
    a += Math.Pow(int.Parse(digit + ""), n.ToString().Length);
  }

  return a == n;
}
```

Testing:

```
Console.WriteLine(new NarcissisticNumber().N(153));
True

Console.WriteLine(new NarcissisticNumber().N(1634));
True
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 110 bytes

```clj
(fn[](let[s(read-line)p #(Integer/parseInt(str %))](=(p s)(reduce + 0(map #(int(Math/pow(p %)(count s)))s)))))
```

Reads in the user input, maps over the digits, raising each to a power equal to the number of digits in the number, then checks that the sum of the digits equals the number itself.

Ungolfed (and neatened up):

```clj
(defn narcissistic? []
  (let [n-str (read-line)
        parse #(Integer/parseInt (str %))
        pow #(int (Math/pow % (count n-str)))
        powd-digits (map #(pow (parse %)) n-str)]
    (= (parse n-str) (reduce + 0 powd-digits))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript ES6, 50 bytes

```
v=>[...s=v+""].map(x=>v-=Math.pow(x,s.length))&&!v
```

Convert the number to a string and iterate through the digits, 
subtract the power computation from the original number
use the ! operator to invert the logic so that a 0 result returns true and non-zero returns false.

Answer (score 0):

## k, 24 bytes

```
{x=+/*/(#$x)#,"I"$'$x}
```

Answer (score 0):

### R, 173 Bytes

```
a=readline()
b=as.numeric(strsplit(as.character(a),"")[[1]])
x=(b)^length(b)
if(sum(x)==as.numeric(paste(b,sep="",collapse=""))){
   print("true")
} else{
  print("false")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Factor, 90 bytes

```
[ read [ length ] [ >array [ 1string ] map [ 10 base> ] map ] bi [ swap ^ ] with map sum ]
```

More readable and explained:

```
[ 
    read                                  ! input 
    [ length ]                            ! a function which gets the length 
    [ >array [ 1string ] map [ 10 base> ] map ] ! another which turns a number into an array
    bi                                    ! apply both to the string input
    [ swap ^ ] with map sum               ! raise each digit to the length power and sum
]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 8 bytes (noncompeting)

```
YQ`lL^sq
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=YQ%60lL%5Esq&input=153)

```
 Q`l     -   len(str(input))
    L^   -  map(^ ** V)
Y        -   digits(input)
      s  -  sum(^)
       q - ^ == input
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 56 bytes

```js
eval(`${n=prompt()}0`.split``.join(`**${n.length}+`))==n
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 9 bytes

Note that this answer is non-competing as Pushy postdates the challenge. However, I thought I'd post it because it's interestingly short for a simple stack-based language:

```
VsLKeS^=#
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/pushy#@x9W7OOdGhxnq/z//39DM2MTAA)

It works like this (how the two stacks would look for the example input is shown on the right):

```
    \ Implicit input, for example 1634.  [1634], []
V   \ Copy into second stack.            [1634], [1634]
s   \ Split into individual digits       [1,6,3,4], [1634]
L   \ Push stack length                  [1,6,3,4,4], [1634]
Ke  \ Raise all to this power            [1,1296,81,256], [1634]
S   \ Take sum                           [..., 1634], [1634]
^=  \ Check equality with initial input  [..., True], []
#   \ Output this boolean (as 0/1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 30 bytes

```
{$_==sum .comb.map(* **.comb)}
```

Pretty straightforward.  The `chars` method would be more typically used to get the number of characters in the input string, but `comb` returns those characters as a list, which evaluates to the number of characters in numeric context, and saves us a byte.

Comment: [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1ol3ta2uDRXQS85PzdJIUJLSxvMqv1fnFipkF6UWgBUqKMQZ2hgYGD9HwA "Perl 6 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>43</s> 38 bytes

Takes input as a string.

```js
n=>n==eval([...n,0].join`**n.length+`)
```

---

### Try It

```js
f=
n=>n==eval([...n,0].join`**n.length+`)
o.innerText=f(i.value="153")
oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(i.value)
```

```html
<input id=i type=number><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 54 bytes

```bash
echo $[ `printf "+%c**${#1}" $(fold -w1<<<$1)` == $1 ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@anJGvoBKtkFBQlJlXkqagpK2arKWlUq1sWKukoKKRlp@ToqBbbmhjY6NiqJmgYGuroGKoEPv//39DM2MTAA)

Takes input as parameter, outputs 1 if is narcissist, 0 if not.

fold prints each digit one per line, printf adds +`<digit>`**`<length>` forming the arithmetic expression which is evaluated and compared to the original input.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 44 bytes

I think this is the shortest you can get for Python. Uses a `lambda` rather than a full program.

```
lambda s:sum(int(x)**len(`s`)for x in`s`)==s
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQbFVcmquRmVeiUaGppZWTmqeRUJygmZZfpFChkJkHYtvaFv8vKAKpSNMwNDXW1OSC8ww0Nf8DAA)**

Based off [@danmcardle's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15247/66833).

**Original answer, 51 bytes**

```
lambda s:sum(map(lambda x:int(x)**len(`s`),`s`))==s
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQbFVcmquRm1igARWosMrMK9Go0NTSyknN00goTtDUARGatrbF/wuKQHJpGoamxpqaXHCegabmfwA)**

Comment: You could use strings as input and [save a byte](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKqG4NFcjM69Eo0JTSysnNU@jWDMtv0ihQiEzT6FYM8HWtvh/QRFIPk1DydDUWElTkwvBNwBy/wMA).

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
qsm^sdl`Q`
```

**[Verify the test cases.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=qsm%5Esdl%60Q%60&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=153%0A1634%0A12&debug=0)**

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 24 bytes

21 bytes of code + 3 for `-pF` flags

```perl
for$i(@F){$_-=$i**@F}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8tv0glU8PBTbNaJV7XViVTS8vBrfb/f0NT43/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@6xa4AQA)

Answer (score 0):

### **Swift 3.2: 107 characters**

Of course Swift is absolutely not a quick language but I thought I would try:

```
func n(s:String){let c=s.utf8.map{Double($0)-48};print(c.reduce(0){$0+pow($1,Double(c.count))}==Double(s))}
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 46 bytes

```js
F=n=>![...n].reduce((x,c)=>x-(+c)**n.length,n)

console.log(F("153") == true)
console.log(F("370") == true)
console.log(F("371") == true)
console.log(F("152") == false)
console.log(F("150") == false)
```

Comment: Is it necessary to convert `c` into number?

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
ĐĐḶ⌊⁺⇹ą⇹^Ʃ=
```

Explanation:

```
                      Implicit input
ĐĐ                    Duplicate the input twice
   Ḷ⌊⁺                Get number of digits in the input
      ⇹ą              Convert input to array of digits
        ⇹^Ʃ           sum the digits raised to the power of the number of digits
           =          equals input?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yIQjEx7u2Paop@tR465H7TuPtAKJuGMrbf//NzQ1BgA)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 7, 41 Bytes

```
s=>[...s].map(x=>N+=x**s.length,N=0)|N==s
```

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 12 bytes

```
{_Ab_,f#:+=}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fWPe/Ot4xKV4nTdlK27b2f91/QzNjEwA)

Explanation:

```
{          }   anonymous block, input: 1634
   b           get digits in base
  A              10: [1 6 3 4]
     ,         take the length: 4
       #       and raise
      f          each element
    _              of the list of digits
               to that power: [1 1296 81 256]
        :      fold over
         +       addition: 1634
          =    and compare
 _               to the original: 1 (true)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 60 bytes

```kotlin
map{Math.pow(it-'0'+0.0,length+0.0)}.sum()==this.toInt()+0.0
```

### Beautified

```kotlin
map {
    Math.pow(it - '0' + 0.0, length + 0.0)
}.sum() == this.toInt() + 0.0
```

### Test

```kotlin
fun String.f() =
map{Math.pow(it-'0'+0.0,length+0.0)}.sum()==this.toInt()+0.0

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    (0..1000).filter { it.toString().f() }.forEach { println(it) }
}
```

### TIO

[TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##JY7BCsIwEETv+Yrcuou6rFexggcPHjz5BUGaJpgmJd0iUvrtNbVzGmaGx7yTBB8XZceon5J9bMkC6nrpTD89jDjq0we8HCqudky8D01sxa0WZxrGDrCuxfmBJN2jAK7NhuuMj2ByO5z0NWfzPW/8C+pJ6SJgoiMzI1kfpMl60l4KZpsB/o/MZFO+mZcrbV9yCbG8KbmalVLLDw)

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (ES6) 46 bytes - Not competing

```
n=>(s=[...''+n]).forEach(v=>n-=v**s.length)|!n
```

Explanation:

```
n=>
(s=[...''+n])        // Convert input to array of chars and assign to s
  .forEach(v=>       // Loop over s (returns undefined)
    n-=v**s.length)  // reduce input by char^length
  |                  // undefined is falsy, so we OR
  !n                 // OR with negated input 
                     // returns 1 if 0, 0 otherwise
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 30 bytes

```
n->[n-=d^#s|d<-s=digits(n)];!n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmD7P0/XLjpP1zYlTrm4JsVGt9g2JTM9s6RYI08z1lox739BUWZeiUZ0Xk2ejW60oZ6eoYGBQaxOGkha8z8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 77 bytes

```
proc N n {expr [join [lmap d [split $n ""] {expr $d**[string le $n]}] +]==$n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WcFPIU@hOrWioEghOis/M08hOic3sUAhRSG6uCAns0RBJU9BSSkWqkIlRUsrurikKDMvXSEnFSgXWxuroB1ra6uSV/u/oLSkWCHaT8HQ1DiWC8ExQeKYGQN5/wE)

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 44 bytes

```
=A1=SUM(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)^LEN(A1))
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](http://=A1=SUM(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)%5ELEN(A1)))

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 6 bytes

```
dDl*S=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWy1JccrSCbZcUJyUXQ4UWLDY0NYYwAQ)

##### Explanation

```python
dDl*S=  # Implicit input     ->  153
d       # Cast to digits     ->  [1, 5, 3]
 Dl     # Push the length    ->  [1, 5, 3]  3
   *    # Exponentiate       ->  [1, 125, 27]
    S   # Sum the list       ->  153
     =  # Equals the input?  ->  1
        # Implicit output
```