# Is a number divisible by each of its digits?

Tags: code-golf

My friend and I were working on a lab in our AP Computer Science class and decided to code golf one one the problems since we still had half the class free after we finished. Here is the question:

> Given a number n, is n divisible by each of its digits?

For example, 128 will pass this test- it is divisible by 1,2, and 8. Any numbers with a zero automatically disqualify the number. While you may use other languages and post solutions with them if you like, we are most interested in seeing how compact people can make the program in Java, as that is the language we use in the class. So far, we both have 51. Here is my current code:

```java
public boolean dividesSelf(int n){for(int p=n;n%10>0;)n/=p%(n%10)>0?.1:10;return n<1;}
// 51 characters

// Breakdown:
// for(int p=n;         Saves one semicolon to put declaration into for loop
// n%10>0;)             Basic check-for-zero
// n/=                  Pretty simple, discarding one number off of n at a time
// p%(n%10)>0?          If p (the given value) is not divisible by n%10 (the current digit)...
// .1:10;               Divide by .1 (multiply by 10) so it fails the check next iteration. If it is divisible, divide by 10 to truncate the last digit
// return n<1           If the number was fully divisible, every digit would be truncated, and n would be 0. Else, there would still be non-zero digits.
```

### Requirements

The method signature can be whatever you want. Just count the function body. Make sure, though, that the method returns a boolean value and only passes in *one numeric* parameter (not a string).

The code must be able to pass all of these cases (in order to stay true to the directions of the original question, *only* boolean true and false values count if the language supports booleans. If and only if your language does not have boolean variables you may represent false with 0 and true with any nonzero integer (preferably 1 or -1):

```
128 -> true
 12 -> true
120 -> false
122 -> true
 13 -> false
 32 -> false
 22 -> true
 42 -> false
212 -> true
213 -> false
162 -> true
204 -> false
```

Also, we didn't count whitespace, so feel free to do the same, unless the whitespace is essential to the working of the program (so newlines in Java don't count, but a single space between `int` and `x=1` does count.)
Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! A few suggestions: 1. Not counting functional whitespace is a bad idea. Any answer written in [Whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_%28programming_language%29) will automatically win. 2. Should our submission print/return `true` and `false` or are [truthy/falsy](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey) values OK as well? 3. The `java` tag doesn't really apply here, as the challenge itself is unrelated to Java.

Comment: Okay. sorry for the issues. Just to clear it up, would you consider the space in 'int p=n' to be functional, because I did not previously. I will fix the other issues you pointed out.

Comment: _All_ whitespace required for the code to work is functional.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the response!

Comment: `Just count the calculation inside the brackets` - does this apply to all languages that can define functions?

Comment: Yes, only count the code that is actually doing work, so ignore anything that defines the function but does not contribute to the actual implementation. Hopefully that clears it up.

Comment: Note that 0 is a multiple of 0, which makes me wonder how the answers would change if you didn't specifically exclude that.

Comment: One parameter, ok, but string type or numeric?

Comment: Numeric inputs only.

Comment: @RickyDemer: since 0 would be an exceptional input in that case (it's the only number with `0` digits that is a multiple of each of them), I imagine most answers would just get longer in an uninteresting way to include a check for it. So I like the problem as posed by the title better (divisible by its digits, rather than being a multiple of its digits, which excludes 0).

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest the alternate interpretation of the question, in which dividing 123412341234 by 3 yields [12, 412, 412, 4].

Comment: Found an OEIS sequence for this: [A034838](https://oeis.org/A034838)

Answer (score 22):

## Perl 6, 13

```
sub golf($_) {
   $_%%.comb.all
}
```

Uses the implicit variable `$_` — `$_ %% .comb.all` is equivalent to `$_ %% all($_.comb)`. `%%` is the "is divisible" operator, and `comb` with no additional argument returns a list of the characters in a string. As an example, if the argument is 123, then the function evaluates

```
123 %% all(123.comb)
```

which is

```
123 %% all(1, 2, 3)
```

junction autothreading makes it

```
all(123 %% 1, 123 %% 2, 123 %% 3)
```

which is

```
all(True, False, True)
```

which is false in boolean context because it's an "all" junction and clearly not all of its elements are true.

It should be possible to coerce the return value to `Bool` and hide the junction-ness from callers by making the function signature `sub golf($_ --> Bool())`, but coercions in function signatures don't work yet in Rakudo. The return value is still correctly true or false, it's just not `True` or `False`.

Comment: If you want to make it return a `Bool` just add `so` to the front of the code `so$_%%.comb.all`.

Answer (score 21):

## C# and System.Linq - 26 / 40

Per the rules, not counting the method declaration itself.

```
bool dividesSelf(int i) { 
    return(i+"").All(d=>i%(d-48d)<1);
}
```

Showing that once again, C# is the superior choice when Java is under consideration... I kid, I kid!

Unfortunately, this function (and many in other answers) will not produce correct results for negative input. We can fix this, but the solution loses a lot of its charm (and grows to 46 characters in length):

```
return(i+"").All(d=>d>48&&i%(d-48)==0||d==45);
```

**Edit**: shaved off one character with Tim's suggestion.

**Edit**: with the introduction of [expression-bodied members](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) in C# 6, we can pare this down further by cutting out the `return`:

```
bool dividesSelf(int i) =>
    (i+"").All(d=>i%(d-48d)<1);
```

for a total of 26 characters (in my opinion, the `=>` should not be included any more than braces would be). The version handling negative numbers can be similarly shortened.

Comment: Why `.0`? There's no need for anything other than integer modulus.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: There is if you want the shortest program -- `i % 0` with `i` an integer gives a `DivideByZeroException`.

Comment: And with a double it gives NaN! Nice!

Comment: `48d` is the same as `48.0`, but one less character (d for double).

Comment: Nice solution... good to see someone finally bring it with C#

Comment: @JeroenMostert :) hehe well that'll teach me to blurt out stuff without checking myself. (eh, probably not, seems i've learned that particular lesson about 1,000 times.) tks for the response. i have deleted my comment so that it wouldn't be there to confuse the issue if someone didn't read further.

Comment: Are you allowed to use lambda syntax to get rid of the pesky `return` and trailing semi-colon? i.e. `Func<int, bool> dividesSelf = (i) => (i+"").All(d=>i%(d-48d)<1)`. In the negative case, you perhaps could use the non short circuit version of`&` vs `&&` :)

Comment: @StuartLC: lambdas aren't methods; their scope is different, so I think that's bending the rules too far. But since C# 6 (which this answer predates), we have expression-bodied members, which do allow us to shorten the definition. For the negative case, we can't use `&`, precisely because `&` doesn't short-circuit -- you'll get a divide by zero exception on the `%`. We can fix that by making it a double (with `d`), but then we've lost one character again.

Comment: Good point :) One day we'll hopefully not need explicit `return` keyword and possibly also allow for functional return type inference, to bring us inline with other functional languages.

Answer (score 17):

### APL (<s>13</s> 11)

(apparently the brackets don't count)

```
{0∧.=⍵|⍨⍎¨⍕⍵}
```

Explanation:

- `⍎¨⍕⍵`: evaluate each character in the string representation of `⍵`
- `⍵|⍨`: for each of those, find the modulo of it and `⍵`
- `0∧.=`: see whether all of those are equal to `0`

Testcases:

```
      N,[.5] {0∧.=⍵|⍨⍎¨⍕⍵} ¨ N←128 12 120 122 13 32 22 42 212 213 162 204
128 12 120 122 13 32 22 42 212 213 162 204
  1  1   0   1  0  0  1  0   1   0   1   0
```

Comment: APL can do `X%0` ? without throwing ?

Comment: @Optimizer: yes. `0|X` gives `X`.

Comment: Sweet. Also your answer is 11 bytes, not 13

Comment: Also, you are using 4 bytes in the final computation. Do you have a sum of array method ? If yes, do that and Boolean not it.

Comment: @optimizer: That doesn't work in APL. Boolean not (`~`) expects an actual boolean value (0/1) and will give a `DOMAIN ERROR` if given something else. You could do `~×+/` (*not* of sign of sum) but that's also 4 bytes.

Comment: Only APL would not give an error on modulo by 0, and crash on evaluating a non-bool as a bool ;)

Comment: One character shorter with a train instead of dfn: `(0∧.=⍎¨∘⍕|⊢)`

Answer (score 15):

### Python 2: 43 chars

```python
f=lambda n:any(n%(int(d)or.3)for d in`n`)<1
```

Checks whether the number has any nonzero remainders modulo its digits, and outputs the negation of that. Zero digits are handled strangely: since computing `%0` causes an error, digits of `0` are replaced with `.3`, which seems to always give a nonzero result due to floating point inaccuracies.

The function body is 32 chars.

Answer (score 14):

### Perl - 27 bytes

```
sub dividesSelf{
    $_=pop;s/./!$&||$_%$&/ger<1
}
```

Not counting the function signature, as instructed.

**Sample Usage:**

```
use Data::Dump qw(dump);
for $i (128, 12, 120, 122, 13, 32, 22, 42, 212, 213, 162, 204) {
  printf "%3d -> %s\n", $i, dump(dividesSelf $i);
}
```

**Sample Output:**

```
128 -> 1
 12 -> 1
120 -> ""
122 -> 1
 13 -> ""
 32 -> ""
 22 -> 1
 42 -> ""
212 -> 1
213 -> ""
162 -> 1
204 -> ""
```

---

Addressing the problem specification: "Only boolean true and false values count. Truthy/falsey values do *not* count."

```
use Data::Dump qw(dump);
dump(1 == 1);
dump(0 == 1);
```

Outputs:

```
1
""
```

'True' and 'False' are defined as `1` and `""`.

**Erratum:**
As Brad Gilbert [rightly points out](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/41902#comment97962_41906), perl defines *true* as a scalar which is both the integer `1` and the string `"1"` simultaneously, and *false* as a scalar which is both the integer `0` and the string `""` simultaneously.

Comment: This can be shortened by not using `$_`: `pop=~s///ger<1`. I don't know whether the OP will agree that `1` and `""` are valid results. If not, then it can be fixed with two more bytes: just add `|0`.

Comment: `perl -pe'$_=s/./!$&||$_%$&/ger<1|0'` is 26 bytes including the `|0` and `-p` flag. You don't have to use a function.

Comment: @hvd the inner logic contains `$_` as well. Using `"@_"` in both places is one byte longer.

Comment: @chilemagic this reads from `STDIN` and writes to `STDOUT`, rather than being a function as requested. I was tempted to include `my($n)=@_;` as part of the 'method signature', but it seems a bit of a stretch.

Comment: I can't link to a comment, but op's comment on this [answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41905/29438) says it is okay if it isn't a function. I guess it is unclear whether `STDIN` to `STDOUT` is allowed.

Comment: @primo Oops, you're right. I did test before commenting, but the way I tested was wrong: I was calling the sub in a loop with `$_`. Sorry about that. Normally I'd delete my earlier comment, but the part about `|0` may still make it worth leaving up.

Comment: Actually the *True* and *False* values are more like `dualvar(1,'1')` and `dualvar(0,'')`.

Comment: @BradGilbert That is interesting. I am reasonably familiar with perlguts, but I wasn't aware that _true_ and _false_ were special cased. They're actually 'triple scalars', marked as `SVIV` (int), `SVNV` (double), and `SVPV` (string).

Comment: Actually the first time you use a string as a number or a number as a string, the variable gets modified to hold that additional data. That is why you only get a warning the first time you use `'abc'` as a number (assuming you have `use warnings;` enabled. )

Comment: @BradGilbert Indeed: http://codepad.org/9VszodfA

Answer (score 13):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>39</s> <s>32</s> 28 bytes

```
v=>[...""+v].every(x=>v%x<1)
```

Thanks core1024 for the suggestion to replace `(""+v).split("")` with `[...""+v]`, and openorclose for suggesting the use of `every` function.

The answer currently doesn't contain one bit of my code :O

#### Previous solution

```
v=>[...""+v].filter(x=>v%x|!+x)==""
```

`==""` is not a valid way to check if an array is empty, since `[""]==""` returns `true`, but the array is guarantee to contain non-empty string, so it works here.

The rest are quite standard shorthand type conversion in JavaScript.

Comment: You can save some characteras by replacing `(""+v).split("")` with `[...""+v]`.

Comment: Why not use the `every` method? `v=>[...""+v].every(x=>v%x<1)`;

Comment: @openorclose: Thanks. Never had a chance to use it in JS, so I never thought of searching for such function.

Comment: `v=>![...""+v].some(x=>v%x)`

Comment: @l4m2 Since `v%0` returns `NaN` and `NaN == false`, so in your case numbers that contains 0, such as `10`, may return `true`.

Comment: Btw shouldn't the answer be 28 bytes long?

Comment: @user71546: Fixed the character count.

Answer (score 13):

## CJam, <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
{
    _Ab:df%:+!
}:F;
```

This defines a function named `F` and discards the block from the stack.

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7B_Ab%3Adf%25%3A%2B!%7D%3AF%3B%20e%23%20Define%20function.%0A%5Bq~%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%23%20Read%20input.%0A%7BF%7D%25%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%23%20Execute%20F%20for%20each%20integer.%0Ap%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%23%20Print.&input=128%2012%20120%20122%2013%2032%2022%2042%20212%20213%20162%20204)

#### Test cases

```
$ cjam <(echo '{_Ab:df%:+!}:F;[128 12 120 122 13 32 22 42 212 213 162 204]{F}%p')
[1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
```

#### How it works

```
_      " Copy the integer on the stack.                                          ";
Ab     " Push the array of its digits in base 10.                                ";
:d     " Cast each digit to Double.                                              ";
f%     " Take the integer on the stack modulus each of its digits.               ";
:+     " Add the results.                                                        ";
!      " Push the logical NOT of the sum.                                        ";
```

Comment: Did CJam have the features you used for the 10-byte solution when the question was written?

Comment: @ThomasKwa: Yes it did. I've tested the code in version 0.6.2, which was released in July 2014.

Answer (score 9):

### Java 8, 46 Bytes (method body)

Using [Jeroen Mostert](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41918/21777)'s converting to double trick.

```
public static boolean dividesSelf(int n) {
    return(""+n).chars().allMatch(x->n%(x-48d)<1);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

## Pyth, 12 bytes

```
!f|!vT%vzvTz
```

This filters the characters in the string for being either zero (`!vT`) or not dividing the input (`%vzvT`), then takes the logical not of the resulting list.

[Try it here.](http://isaacg.scripts.mit.edu/pyth/index.py)

Comment: No, I'm fine if a function is not used. I just wanted to point out to anybody that was using functions that they do not need to count the declaration, and only the code inside.

Answer (score 8):

## Ruby, 44 bytes (function body: 37)

Probably has potential to be golfed further.

```
f=->n{n.to_s.chars.all?{|x|x>?0&&n%x.hex<1}}
```

Input taken through function `f`. Example usage:

```
f[128] # => true
f[12]  # => true
f[120] # => false
...
```

Comment: You can change `.to_i` to `.hex`, since single-digit numbers are the same in base 16, and can change `==0` to `<1`.

Answer (score 8):

## Python - <s>59</s> <s>50</s> <s>49</s> 47 bytes

```
f=lambda n:all(c>'0'and 0==n%int(c)for c in`n`)
```

I'm sure there's a faster way... oh well.

*Edit* - Thanks to FryAmTheEggman for the golfing tips.

*Edit 2* - FryAmTheEggman may as well have written this at this point, oops

*Edit 3* - Hands up if you didn't even know genexps were a thing. ...Just me?

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! I keep forgetting about all those things. (I also didn't realize you could less-than chars in that way.)

Comment: Oh, flipping the logic also seems to shorten it a bit: `f=lambda n:all([c>'0'and 0==n%int(c)for c in\`n\`])`. And no problem :)

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize there even *was* an `all` method.

Comment: Would `1>n%int(c)` work?

Comment: Why a list-comprehension? Using a genexp: ``all(c>'0'and 0==n%int(c)for c in`n`)`` does exactly the same, with 2 char less and even saving the allocation of the list.

Answer (score 8):

### [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth) 11

```
!f%Q|vT.3`Q
```

This combines [@isaacg's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41905/31625) and [@xnor's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41915/31625) answers. It filters out digits from the input by checking the value of `input % (eval(current_digit) or .3)`. Then it checks if the resulting string is empty or not.

Came across another couple same-length variants:

```
!f%Q|T.3jQT
!f|!T%QTjQT
```

[Try it online.](http://isaacg.scripts.mit.edu/pyth/index.py)

Answer (score 5):

## Bash + coreutils, 44 bytes

The full function definition is:

```
f()((`tr 0-9 \10<<<$1``sed "s/./||$1%&/g"<<<$1`))
```

I'm not sure how to score this as normally shell functions use a single set of `{}` or `()` to contain the function body.  I found here I could also use double `(())` to contain the function body which causes an arithmetic expansion which is what I need here.  So for now I am counting just one pair of those brackets - further discussion of this is welcome.

#### Output:

```
$ for i in 128 12 120 122 13 32 22 42 212 213 162 204; do f $i; printf "%d " $?; done
1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 $
$
```

Comment: Uh - its not clear to me whether 1s and 0s are acceptable or if I have to print `true`/`false`?

Answer (score 4):

## J - 14 char

The function body is the portion after the `=:`. If we want to minimize the character count for the whole function, that's the 15 char `*/@(0=,.&.":|])`.

```
f=:0*/@:=,.&.":|]
```

`,.&.":` is the shortest way in J to expand as number into a list of its decimal digits: convert to string, separate the digits, and convert each digit back into a number. `,.&.":|]` takes the input number (`]`) modulo (`|`) those digits. `0*/@:=` returns true if all the results were 0, else gives a false.

```
   f 162
1
   f every 204 212 213
0 1 0
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java - <s>121</s> <s>102</s> <s>97</s> <s>79</s> 78 bytes

I just *know* this will get clobbered later. Oh well.

```
boolean b(int a){int m=10,j,t=1;for(;m<a*10;m*=10){j=10*(a%m)/m;if(j==0||a%j>0)t=0;}return t>0;}
```

I'll be back.

Comment: You can now name your function whatever you want. I changed the rules so you only count the calculations inside the actual function, but the function *must* return a boolean type. So that is currently at 86 characters.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell - <strike>100</strike> <strike>54</strike> 38

```
f x=all(\y->y>'0'&&x`mod`read[y]<1)$show x
```

Still learning, critiques appreciated

Comment: I had a comment here, but I accidentally deleted it somehow... Anyway, some suggestions:
1) Drop the `length`s, they are unnecessary.
2) Replace `t` by its definition.
3) `elem y s` is unnecessary.
4) `/='0'` can be moved to the left filter, in place of `elem y s`.
5) In this case, `/='0'` is equivalent to `>'0'`, since every letter is a digit.
6) Put `mod` in backticks, so it becomes infix.
7) Put everything on a single line.

Comment: 1 and 3 were from when I was trying to do it a different way and salvaged code. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: my suggestions: instead of using `s==filter(...)s` you should use `all(...)s`. now, because `s` only appears once in the expression, you can replace it with it's definition and drop `where`. also, instead of `==0` you could use `<1`.

Comment: great improvement from the first version!

Comment: I think you can still lose one byte if you replace `all(\y->...)$show x` by `and[...|y<-show x]`.

Comment: You actually gain a byte. `and[y|y<-show x,y>'0'&&x\`mod\`read[y]<1]`

Answer (score 3):

### Julia <strike>32</strike> <strike>25</strike> 23

#### Improved using digits

Also fixes problem with negative numbers

```
selfDivides(x)=sum(x%digits(x).^1.)==0
```

#### Old method

All digits divide if the sum of all the remainders is 0.  Like others, has a problem with negative numbers.

```
selfDivides(x)=sum(x.%(Float64["$x"...]-48))==0
```

### Output

```
[selfDivides(x) for x in [128,12,120,122,13,32,22,42,212,213,162,204]]
12-element Array{Any,1}:
  true
  true
 false
  true
 false
 false
  true
 false
  true
 false
  true
 false
```

#### Improved method also handles BigInt

```
selfDivides(BigInt(11111111111111111111111111111111111111112))
true
```

however

```
selfDivides(BigInt(11111111111111111111111111111111111111113))
false
```

because

```
BigInt(11111111111111111111111111111111111111113) %3
1
```

Comment: it is for a very old julia (0.4 i think), here is an actualized 23 bytes version: ```selfDivides(x)=sum(x.%digits(x).^1.)<1```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
SÖP
```

Only `1` is [truthy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/52210) in 05AB1E, so this will output `1` if the input-integer is divisible by each of its digits.

For falsey test cases it either outputs `0`, or a multiple of the input if it contains `0`s (due to division by zero errors). If you want a distinct falsey output of `0`, you can add a trailing `Θ` (`== 1` builtin).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/@PC0gP//DY0sAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/@DD0wL@6/yPNjTSMTLSMQRjCx1DMyAXKGRqbm6qY2isY2ykYwKSMdAxMjAByhjrGBoYGMYCAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
S    # Convert the (implicit) input-integer to a list of digits
 Ö   # Check for each digit if it evenly divides the (implicit) input-integer
     # (results in 1 for truthy; 0 for falsey; and itself for division by zero errors)
  P  # Take the product of this list to check if all are truthy
     # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 15 bytes

```
{_Abf{_{%}1?}1b!}
```

`{}` is the closest thing to a function in CJam. I am just counting the body of the function

Use it like this:

```
128{_Abf{_{%}1?}1b!}~
```

To get either `1` (if the number is divisible) or `0` (if the number is not divisible by its digits).

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

**Explanation**

```
_Ab                "Copy the number and split it to its digits";
   f{      }       "For each digit, run this code block on the number";
     _{%}1?        "If the digit is 0, put 1, otherwise perform number modulus digit";
            1b     "We now have an array of modulus corresponding to each digit. Sum it up";
              !    "Negate the sum. If all digits were divisible, sum of modules will be"
                   "0, thus answer should be 1 and vice versa";
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but after quickly reading up on CJam, some things seems to not make sense: how does `Ab` split the digits? It seems to just convert it to base 10. Also, how does % know to mod by the number, and not just the next digit, since it seems that the next digit would be next on the stack?

Comment: Answering all your question will be tricky. It would be super easy to learn by putting ed after each character in the code. Try running `128{ed_edAedbedf{ed_ed{ed%ed}1ed?ed}ed1edbed!ed}~`

Comment: Answers to particular questions : doing base 10 gives an array of base 10 converted numbers, which are the digits themselves in this case. `%` simply take the last two numbers (in this case) and calculate the mod. Last two numbers here are the actual number and digit (always)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

## C89, 43 bytes

```
unsigned char d(int n, int c) {
        int a=n%10;return!n||a&&!(c%a)&&d(n/10,c);
}
```

C89 doesn't have a boolean type. Hope that works.
Also I used a second parameter to pass a copy of the original number through the stack, but the definition can be anything. To get the correct result you just have to call the function with the same value for both parameters (`d(128, 128)`).

**EDIT:** Applied suggested edits by an anonymous user

Comment: Take a look at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/17160 , someone gave you some golfing suggestions

Comment: Specifically against the rules. *One* parameter.

Comment: Yup, this post is actually why I decided to make that rule, as it didn't seem right that the user should do the duplication instead of the program.

Comment: I guess I'll have to add a wrapper function. Does the declaration of that function add to the byte count?

Answer (score 2):

## C / C++, 58 bytes (44 in body)

**Invokes Undefined Behaviour** (see comments)

```
int d(int i){int j=i;while(i&&!(j%(i%10)))i/=10;return!i;}
```

`true` and `false` **are** 1 and 0, but feel free to add one character to the signature to return a `bool`.

And for fun, a recursive version which is smaller if you allow calls of the form `r(128,128)`

**Edit**: Now disallowed by the rules:

### C / C++, 53 bytes (33 in body)

```
int r(int i,int j){return!i||!(j%(i%10))&&r(i/10,j);}
```

Comment: #1 dies with a floating point exception for numbers containing a 0 because j%(i%10) will be illegal for i%10 = 0.

Comment: A **floating point** exception? Weird. It works perfectly on my compiler but you're right, it's undefined behaviour. Not sure what the general PCG stance on compiler-dependent UB is.

Comment: What's "compiler-dependent UB"? Either it's UB or it isn't (and division by zero, or rather modulo zero, is indeed UB). UB shouldn't be allowed because literally anything could happen. We may assume your program will run on a machine that will blow up and kill everyone around it when a division by zero happens. Now, I'm sure you want us all to live... C does have a concept of implementation-defined behavior, but dividing by zero doesn't fall under that.

Comment: @etheranger: Division by 0 is called floating point exception for historical reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928942/why-does-integer-division-by-zero-result-in-a-floating-point-exception

Comment: @JeroenMostert: I'd say over 90 % of all C answers on this site invoke UB. As long as it works with *some* compiler on *some* machine, the answer is considered valid.

Comment: @etheranger: What compiler did you use?

Comment: @sudo: then I'd say the C golfers need more discipline. It's one thing to have a clever hack that only works on the Foobar Bletchley because only that has programmable degaussing coils, and another to do something that renders your entire program susceptible to irreversible mangling by an optimizing compiler. That said, I suppose this sorts itself out by voting and setting appropriate rules in the question (and if all else fails, ignoring pundits like me :-)).

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳  Neat, nice history lesson :D

Comment: @sudo Green Hills for ARM - kind of niche, I know.  
@ JeroenMostert I meant the results were compiler/cpu dependent, not the defined-ness. And I would tend to agree with avoiding it - terrible practice for anywhere but PCG and I wouldn't have posted in the first place if I'd noticed. I'm leaving it as-is for now given how unimportant the content of the answer actually is.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 15 bytes

```
{_Abf{_g{%}*}:|!}
```

This is a block, the closest thing to a function in CJam. I'm only counting the body (i.e. omitting the braces). You can use it as follows:

```
128{_Abf{_g{%}*}:|!}~
```

Or if you want to test a series of inputs, you can do

```
[128 12 120 122 13 32 22 42 212 213 162 204]{{_Abf{_g{%}*}:|!}~}%
```

The block leaves `0` (falsy) or `1` (truthy) on the stack to indicate the result. (CJam doesn't have a Boolean type.)

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Explanation:

```
_               "Duplicate input.";
 Ab             "Get base-10 digits.";
   f{      }    "This maps the block onto the list of digits, supplying the input each time.";
     _g         "Duplicate digit, get signum S (0 or 1).";
       { }*     "Repeat this block S times.";
        %       "Take input modulo digit.";
                "This leaves an array of zeroes for divisible digits, non-zeroes
                 for non-divisible digits, and non-zero junk for zeroes.";
            :|  "Fold OR onto this list. One could also sum the list with :+";
              ! "Logical NOT. Turns 0 into 1, and non-zero values into 0.";
```

## Alternative, also 15 bytes

```
{:XAb{X\_X)?%},!}
```

Explanation

```
:X              "Store input in X.";
  Ab            "Get base-10 digits.";
    {       },  "Filter this list by the result of the block.";
     X\         "Push another copy of X, swap with digit.";
       _        "Duplicate digit.";
        X)      "Push X+1.";
          ?     "Select digit itself or X+1, depending on whether digit is 0 or not.";
           %    "Take modulo. X%(X+1) will always be nonzero for positive integers.";
              ! "Logical NOT. Turns an empty list into 1 and a non-empty list into 0.";
```

Answer (score 2):

## C11 - 44 Bytes in function body

Another C version, non recursive and without a floating point exception.

```
bool digit_multiple(int i)
{
    for(int n=i;i%10&&n%(i%10)<1;i/=10);return!i;
}
```

This will also work in C++, Java, and most other C-like languages.

Edited to include the improvement of primo's comment.

Comment: A version that compiles in Java (1.7.0_45-b18): `int n=i;for(;i%10>0&&n%(i%10)<1;i/=10);return i<1;`, one byte shorter than the OP's code.

Answer (score 2):

### R: <s>72</s> <s>67</s> 65

The function

```
f<-function(a)!(anyNA(a%%(d=as.double(strsplit(paste0(a),"")[[1]])))|sum(a%%d))
```

Thanks to @AlexA and @plannapus for the savings

Test run

```
i=c(128,12,120,122,13,32,22,42,212,213,162,204)
for(a in i){print(f(a))}
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] FALSE
[1] TRUE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] TRUE
[1] FALSE
[1] TRUE
[1] FALSE
[1] TRUE
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: I count 70 bytes in your function body currently, not 72. But you can get it down to 67 using `d=as.double(strsplit(toString(a),"")[[1]]);!(anyNA(a%%d)|sum(a%%d))`. :)

Comment: @AlexA. Thanks.  One of my first attempts wih R.  Will definitely revisit:)

Comment: @MickyT `paste(a)` instead of `toString(a)` gives the same result.

Comment: @plannapus Thanks, neat little trick.  Must remember that

Answer (score 2):

## PHP: 45 Characters

The character count is for the body of the function.

It is necessary to only pass the first parameter.

```
function t($n, $k=true, $s='str_split'){foreach($s($n)as$b)$k=$k&&$n%$b===0;return$k;}
```

Comment: "and only passes in one numeric parameter"

Answer (score 1):

## GNU Awk: 53 characters

The counted part:

```
for(;++i<=split($1,a,//);)r=r||!a[i]||v%a[i];return!r
```

The entire function:

```
function self_divisible(v, i, r)
{
    for (; ++i <= split($1, a, //); )
        r = r || ! a[i] || v % a[i]

    return ! r
}
```

As Awk has no boolean values, returns 1 tor true and 0 for false.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6) 30

Function with one numeric parameter. Using % and subtraction, no need to special case '0' because 0%0 is NaN in JavaScript.

*Edit* Saved 1 char thx DocMax

```
F=n=>[for(d of t=n+'')t-=n%d]&&t==n
```

Just for fun, abusing the rule about not counting function signature, 4

```
Check=(n,t=n+'',q=[for(d of t)n-=t%d])=>t==n
```

**Test** In FireFox/FireBug console

```
console.log([128, 12, 120, 122, 13, 32, 22, 42, 212, 213, 162, 204]
.map(x=>+x + ' -> ' + F(x)).join('\n'))
```

*Output*

```
128 -> true
12 -> true
120 -> false
122 -> true
13 -> false
32 -> false
22 -> true
42 -> false
212 -> true
213 -> false
162 -> true
204 -> false
```

Comment: I'm going to say no to inputting a string.

Comment: The Firefox console is happy with the replacement of `of(t=n+'')` with just `of t=n+''` to save 1.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP: 85 bytes (64 bytes on the body)

For this function to work, simply pass a string or a number.

`0` will correctly return false.

The code:

```
function f($n,$i=0){for($n.='';$n[$i]&&$t=!($n%$n[$i++]););return$t&&$i==strlen($n);}
```

Please, DO NOT SET THE 2ND PARAMETER!

## Javascript: 76 bytes (61 bytes on the body)

This is a rewrite of the previous function.

Not much changed between both versions.

Here is the code:

```
function f(n){for(i=0,n+='';n[i]/1&&(t=!(n%n[i++])););return t&&i==n.length}
```

---

## Polyglot: Javascript+PHP 187 <del>217</del> bytes (<del>76</del> 84 bytes without boilerplate):

Why I made it?

Because of reason and maybe because I can!

<del>Just ignore the error on PHP: it works anyway!</del>
No longer needed, this was fixed by removing 3 bytes.

Here is the masterpiece:

```
if('\0'=="\0"){function strlen($s){return $s['length'];}}
function toString(){return'';}
function f($n){for($i=0,$n=$n.toString();$n[$i]/1&&($t=!($n%$n[$i++])););return $t&&$i==strlen($n);}
```

You can run this code both on your console and on a PHP interpreter!

---

Old version:

```
if('\0'=="\0"){function strlen($s){return $s['length'];}}
function s($s){return('\0'=="\0")?$s+'':str_replace('','',$s);}
function f($n,$i){for($i=0,$n=s($n);$n[$i]/1&&($t=!($n%$n[$i++])););return $t&&$i==strlen($n);}
```

Comment: "and only passes in one numeric parameter". Without this you can eval($x) and pass whole code in $x

Comment: @abc667 Sorry, but I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 33 (39 including function setup)

Using numeric-to-matrix conversion:

```
f=@(a)sum(mod(a./(num2str(a)-48),1))==0
```

Divide number elementwise by matrix X, where X is made by converting number to string and subtracting 48 to go from ASCII values to numbers again. Take modulo 1 to get decimal part of each division, confirm that all of these are zero (if any are NaN because of /0, the sum will be NaN and hence not zero).

Sample input using www.octave-online.net:

```
f=@(a)sum(mod(a./(num2str(a)-48),1))==0
for j=[128,12,120,122,13,32,22,42,212,213,162,204]
f(j)
end
```

Output:

```
ans =  1
ans =  1
ans = 0
ans =  1
ans = 0
ans = 0
ans =  1
ans = 0
ans =  1
ans = 0
ans =  1
ans = 0
```

Comment: How can we test this?

Comment: http://octave-online.net/ - enter the code definition from above and then (for example) f(128). Will add output

Comment: I had found the compiler and tried it before asking. But it seems to work fine (except for `f(123)`, which is divisible by 1, 2 and 3). But it does work for the test-cases provided.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP - <strike>74</strike> <strike>71</strike> 64 Characters

Golfed:

```
function t($n){while($n>1){if(!($b=$n%10)||($n%$b)){return 0;}$n/=10;}return 1;}
```

Less Golfed:

```
function t($n){
    while($n>1){
        if( !($b=$n%10) || ($n%$b) )
            { return 0; }
        $n/=10;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Test Results:

(Code)

```
$ans = array(128,12,120,122,13,32,22,42,212,213,162,204);
foreach($ans as $a)
{ echo "$a -> ".(t($a)?"True":"False").PHP_EOL; }
```

(Output)

```
128 -> True
12 -> True
120 -> False
122 -> True
13 -> False
32 -> True
22 -> True
42 -> True
212 -> True
213 -> True
162 -> False
204 -> False
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB - 39 characters

```
function [b] = dividesSelf(i)
b=all(~mod(i,sscanf(num2str(i),'%1d')))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**BASH - 117 characters**

```
f(){ [[ $1 =~ 0 ]]&& return 0 || r=;n=$1;for((i=0;i<${#n};i++));do r=$(($r+${n}%${n:$i:1}));done;return $(($r==0));}
```

tests

```
for N in 128 12 120 122 13 32 22 42 212 213 162 204; do
  f $N
  echo "${N} ->  $?"
done

128 ->  1
12 ->  1
120 ->  0
122 ->  1
13 ->  0
32 ->  0
22 ->  1
42 ->  0
212 ->  1
213 ->  0
162 ->  1
204 ->  0
```

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript ES6, 33

```
n=>(""+n).replace(/./g,x=>n%x)==0
```

Test:

```js
f=n=>(""+n).replace(/./g,x=>n%x)==0
console.log(
           [128, 12,  120,  122, 13,   32,   22,   42,  212, 213,  162, 204]
.map(f) == "true,true,false,true,false,false,true,false,true,false,true,false"
)
```

Comment: @Optimizer I've updated language name, sorry for dissonance.

Comment: `JavaScript, ES6` would be the best choice :)

Comment: @Optimizer Ok :)

Comment: The `f=` does not count towards the bytecount, since it's not a recursive function. This is actually 33 bytes.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, thanks, updated.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
Ñ¨K0‹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f5fDEQyu8DR417Pz/38jQGAA)

## Explanation

```
Ñ¨K0‹  full program with implicit input  [213]
Ñ      push divisors                     [1, 3, 71, 213]
 ¨     remove the last element           [1, 3, 71]
  K    push a without b                  [2]
   0   push 0                            [2] [0]
    ‹  push a < b                        [0]
       output implicitly
```

`K` uses the implicit input `[213]` as a and the current stack `[1, 3, 71]` as b.

Comment: You answer seems to fail for `297` (not divisible by 2).

Answer (score 1):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 11 bytes in the function body

```
[:10 tb\|all]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYfBCsIwGIPvfYqAhyko9G@HSA@y99gKVucuTjrW39vevYsk@ZIUTa/Pe6y1D2Khz2FL8xxrFyZzFHeDONoybA/vwNGS8o@HXNm2PaE3QIDmoisaymNJIwZMOPNd7sThgfxTE/FNS90B)

Takes a number from the stack and returns `1` if they are all divisible or `0` otherwise.

### Explanation

```
[:10 tb\|all]
[           ]   anonymous function (the function body)
 :10 tb         push digits of the number (*t*o *b*ase 10)
       \|       vectorized "divides" test
         all    ensure all are truthy (i.e. not 0)
```

Comment: *The method signature can be whatever you want. Just count the function body.* I think this is 11 bytes.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer thanks, what an odd rule

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 14 bytes

```
0=1#."."0@":|]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DWwNlfWU9JQMHJSsamL/a3KlJmfkK6QpGBpZIJiW/wE)

Small improvement on existing J answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
fḊg
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiZuG4imciLCIiLCIxMjhcbjEyXG4xM1xuMjA0XG4xNjIiXQ==)

#### Explained

```
fḊg
f   # flatten input to get list of digits
 Ḋ  # divisible by
  g # minimum value of the individual lists whether the digit is divisible or not. 
    #   If it is, `1`, if not `0`. So if 1 digit is not divisible, it returns `0` in the list, and the program takes it as the minimum.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Handling `0`s cost a couple of bytes (`x/0 = Infinity`).

```
ìeÈ©UvX
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=7GXIqVV2WA&input=MTIw)

```
ìeÈ©UvX     :Implicit input of integer U
ì           :Convert to digit array
 e          :Does each return true
  È         :When passed through the following function as X
   ©        :  Logical AND with
    UvX     :  Is U divisible by X
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 32 bytes

```ruby
->n{n.digits.all?{_1>0&&n%_1<1}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3FXTt8qrz9FIy0zNLivUSc3Lsq-MN7QzU1PJU4w1tDGtroeriChTcog2NLGIVlIFaFEqKSlO5IEKYIgZQobTEnGKYGKYyY2RVEFsWLIDQAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$3\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 2.469 bytes

```
a%f
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJhJWYiLCIxMjgiXQ==)

I really gotta fix `a`.

```
a%f # Returns 0 for truthy, "true" for falsey
 %  # Modulo the number
  f # By each of its digits
a   # Any != 0?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
dḊp
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWS1Me7ugqWFKclFwMFVmw2NDIAsIEAA)

##### Explanation

```python
dḊp  # Implicit input   ->  128
d    # Cast to digits   ->  [1,2,8]
 Ḋ   # Divisible?       ->  [1,1,1]
  p  # Product          ->  1
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, ~<strike>85</strike> ~83 characters (<strike>~75</strike> ~73 just the function body)

Staying all numeric; count includes newlines and spacing.

```
def t(n):
 r=n
 while r:
  r,i=divmod(r,10)
  if not i or n%i:return 0>1
 return 1>0

assert(t(128)==True)
assert(t(12)==True)
assert(t(120)==False)
assert(t(122)==True)
assert(t(13)==False)
assert(t(32)==False)
assert(t(22)==True)
assert(t(42)==False)
assert(t(212)==True)
assert(t(213)==False)
assert(t(162)==True)
assert(t(204)==False)
```

Alternative, 88 characters in the function body:

```
def t(n):return '0' not in `n` and not reduce(lambda a,b:a or b,[divmod(n,int(x))[1] for x in `n`])
```

The approach feels shorter with map/reduce but with Python code it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

## J (16)

```
+/@:|~_1&(10&#.)
```

Returns 0 when true, another number otherwise

Answer (score 0):

## **Java 7, Score = <del>96</del> 76**

Since I can't compete with your number based method, I used a character based method instead. `a` has the input integer in it.

```java
int c=0;for(char e:(""+a).toCharArray())c+=(e-=-48)<1||a%e>0?1:0;return c<1;
```

Here it is golfed indented with structure code:

```java
public class T{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(new T().test(Integer.parseInt(args[0])));
    }

    boolean test(int a){
        int c=0;
        for(char e:(""+a).toCharArray())
            c+=(e-=-48)<1||a%e>0?1:0;
        return c<1;
    }

}
```

Here it is completely expanded:

```java
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(new Test().test(Integer.parseInt(args[0])));
    }

    boolean test(int number){
        String numberString = "" + number;
        int failed = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < numberString.length(); a++){
            int charAt = numberString.charAt(a) - '0';
            if (charAt == 0 || number % charAt != 0){
                failed++;
            }
        }
        return failed < 1;
    }

}
```

**Edit:** Used Mathew Kirschbaum's suggestions to shorten code size.

Comment: On first glance, I see a few places where you can shorten this by relatively large amounts. First, you can change `for(;d<b.length();d++)` to `for(char d:b)`. That form of for is essentially a foreach loop. That will also  shorten `b.charAt(d)` to just `d`, as well as remove the declaration of d in your second statement. Since b isn't used anywhere in the code other than the for condition anymore, you can get rid of it entirely and just replace the previously changed `for(char d:b)` to `for(char d:a+"")`. That brings you to 62 or so.

Comment: According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2, you cannot use a for each loop to iterate over a string. You can only iterate over collections and arrays. I'll try to find something that is similar, though.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP - 91 characters

```
function divides($n) {
    foreach(array_map('intval', str_split($n))as$i)if($i==0||$n%$i!=0)return false;return true;
}

foreach ([128, 12, 120, 122, 13, 32, 22, 42, 212, 213, 162, 204] as $n) {
    echo "\n" . $n . ' -> ' . divides($n);
}
```

Comment: This is code golf, so please shorten your code as much as you can (e.g. by removing unnecessary whitespace) and include byte count in your answer.

Comment: You could golf it to $x=1;foreach(str_split($n)as$i)$x&=$i&&$n%$i==0;return(bool)$x;

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 53 bytes (46 byte body)

```
f[x_]:=AllTrue[IntegerDigits@x,#!=0&&Divisible[x,#]&]
```

Comment: `f@x_ := Tr[x~Mod~IntegerDigits[x]] == 0`

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 59 Characters

Where `$n` is the number you're checking

```
foreach(str_split($n)as$v)if($n%$v!=0){echo 0;exit;}echo 1;
```

Comment: You can reduce this code further `echo 0;exit;` can simply be `die('0');`

Comment: One of the requirements is to return the boolean value if supported by the language and PHP certainly has `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 55

```
let f x =(\s->all(>'0')s||all((<1).(x`mod`).read.(:[]))s)$show x
```

Counting characters after the `=` sign as per the rules.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 41 bytes

Size not including `f=lambda j:`.

```
f=lambda j:all(j%int(i)==0if i>"0"else 0for i in`j`)
```

Argument supplied must be an integer.

Basically what this does is iterates through the integer (after converting it to a string) and checks the divisibility.

Comment: `i>"0"` Lexicographical comparisons are your friend :)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Great, thanks!

Comment: You know.. sometimes I think I must be crazy. This is twice that I've seen the lexical golf, but not the numeric one... `j%int(i)>0` ... :/

Comment: I mean `j%int(i)<1` >_<

Answer (score 0):

### Java 104

Uses recursion. This test (i==0) is required to stop divide by zero error.

```
public boolean d(int n,int k)
{
int i=k%10;return (k<10)?(k>0)&&(n%k==0):(i==0)?false:(n%i==0)&d(n,k/10);  
}
```

Comment: All `==0` can be shortened to `<1`. `(i==0)?false:` can be replaced by `(i>0)&&`.

Comment: `(k<10)?(k>0)&&(n%k==0):` can be replaced by `(n>0)&(k<1)||`. We will let the function recurse once more and check the base case there.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch - 202 Bytes

Takes input from stdin - `C:\div.bat 128`.

```
@echo off&setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion&set s=%1&set c=%1&set l=0
:c
if defined s set/Al+=1&set "s=%s:~1%"&goto c
for /l %%a in (1,1,!l!)do set/aa=%c%%%%%a&if !a!==1 echo false&goto :EOF
echo true
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java - (64)

This is the shortest I can come up with:

```
boolean t(int a) {
    int x=a,t=0;do t+=x%10>0?a%(x%10):0;while((x/=10)>0);return t<1;
}
```

If you don't count the method overhead, just the body, it scores 64.

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 38 characters

```
def isDivisibleByAllDigits(n: Int) = n.toString.forall(d=>d>48&&n%(d-48)<1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## ES6, not exactly a golf, just screwing around with the Y-combinator

```
let dividesSelf = v =>
  !(l =>
    (f => f(f))
    (f => l(n => f(f)(n))))
  (f => n => n + v % n)
  (v >> 1);
```

A little minified, 52 characters long

```
let dividesSelf = v =>
  !(l=>(f=>f(f))(f=>l(n=>f(f)(n))))(f=>n=>n+v%n)(v>>1)
```

The fact I beat about half of the answers is surprising.

Answer (score 0):

## Go - 47 chars

```
func dividesSelf(i int) bool {
    for n:=i;i%10>0&&n%(i%10)<1;i/=10{};return i==0
}
```

Runnable on Go Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/67DQXWnwOT

Answer (score 0):

### Bash, 49

Exits with 0 if the number is divisible, other exit code (and a warning) if not.

```
f () { [ `<<<$1 sed "s/./+$1%\0/g"|cut -c2-|bc` -eq 0 ]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 71 bytes

```
(fn[n](every? integer?(map #(if(=\0 %1)1.1(/ n(- 48(int %1))))(str n))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JAGL](http://github.com/globby/jagl) Alpha 1.2 - 24 bytes

Obviously this wouldn't count in a real contest, because the language came out after the question, but I'm still gonna answer just for fun. Assumes that the number is the only value on the stack, and sets the top value of the stack to 1 or 0, depending on whether the number is divisible by its digits or not.

```
dg{i}/d0en{{SdcS%n}/A}Sf
```

Explanation:

```
dg                         Duplicate number and convert to string
  {i}/                     Convert that to an array of digits
      0en                  If 0 is in the array, push 0, else push 1
         {                 Block to be run if 0 not in array
          {SdcS            Swap, duplicate, cycle, swap
               %n}         Push 1 if divisible by digit, 0 otherwise
                  /A       Map over list and push 1 if all values are 1, otherwise 0
                    }Sf    Run block if 0 not in array
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, <s>89</s> <s>81</s> 70 bytes

```
function d(n){a=(n+"").split("");for(i in a)if(n%a[i]||1/0==n/a[i])return!1;return!0}
```

Comment: 1. Sorry for that. 2. I don't see the problem here. Can you please explain? 3. Ok, I'll recalculate.

Comment: Why dud you roll back your edit?

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, <s>82</s> <s>81</s> 80 bytes

```
a=prompt(q=1);b=a.split('');while(d=b.pop())q=q&!(a%d);alert(a.indexOf(0)+1?0:q)
```

Answer (score 0):

## R, 40 chars

```
f=function(n)all(n%%scan(t=gsub("(.)","\\1 ",n))%in%0)
```

`%%` is vectorized. `scan(t=gsub("(.)","\\1 ",n)` is a trick that I stole from an [old answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15284/6741) by flodel, to split a number into its digits. `%in%0` instead of simply negating the results allows for detection of NA (resulting from mod 0; `NA==0` gives `NA`, `!NA` gives `NA` but `NA%in%0` gives `FALSE`).

```
> f(120)
Read 3 items
[1] FALSE
> f(128)
Read 3 items
[1] TRUE
> f(12)
Read 2 items
[1] TRUE
> f(213)
Read 3 items
[1] FALSE
> f(212)
Read 3 items
[1] TRUE
> f(42)
Read 2 items
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

## TI-BASIC, 29

Adapted from my answer to [Generate Monday Numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/59014/39328).

```
Input X
int(10fPart(X10^(-randIntNoRep(1,1+int(log(X
not(max(remainder(X,Ans+2Xnot(Ans
```

To disqualify numbers that contain zeroes, I replace all zeroes with `2X`, which will not divide X.

I don't count the `Input X` in the code size, because it is analogous to a method signature.

Answer (score 0):

## [Hassium](http://HassiumLang.com), 130 Bytes

```
func i(n){m=n.toString();if(m.contains("0"))return false;foreach(d in m)if(n%d.toString().toDouble()!=0)return false;return true;}
```

Run and see expanded version [here](http://HassiumLang.com/Hassium/index.php?code=17b4aa5856ce236627dcc3761d824b75)

Answer (score 0):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 13 bytes

**Solution:**

```
f:{~+/(48!$x)!'x}
```

**13** bytes excludes function definition (+4) per specification.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/6fZlVdp62vYWKhqFKhqaheUWv9P03B0Mji/38A)

**Examples:**

```
f 1024
0
f 128
1
f 333
1
f 334
0
```

**Explanation:**

Evaluation is performed right-to-left.

Convert (e.g.) `128` => `1 2 8`. `128` mod each `1 2 8` => `0 0 0`. Sum of this is `0`. Not of this is `1`:

```
f:{~+/(48!$x)!'x} / the solution including function definition
f:{             } / assign lambda function to f
               x  / implicit single parameter
             !'   / mod (!) each-left with each-right
      (     )     / do this together
          $x      / string x, 128 => "128"
       48!        / mod ascii values with 48, "128" => 1 2 8
    +/            / sum over results
   ~              / not, 0 => 1, anything else => 0
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 44 bytes

```php
function f($n,$s=str_split){
    foreach($s($n)as$d)$f|=!$d||$n%$d;return!$f;
}
```

[Try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f589e9025ef3bb7e7c7a6979371d93f21f2ac6ba).

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ọDẠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7l6Xh7sW/P//39DMCAA)

This is a link, i.e. a function in Jelly. Since Jelly doesn't have specific boolean values, this returns `1` for `True` and `0` for `False`.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2: <s>36</s> 38 Bytes

Excluding `f=lambda n:`

```
f=lambda n:all([not n%(int(a)or n-1)for a in`n`])
```

Similar to the other python solution.
Works because `x or 0` returns `x` if `x != 0`.

Maybe some edge cases around 0-3 or something.

Edit: Didn't work, fixed it

Comment: [``all(n%(int(a)or~-n)<1for a in`n`)``](https://tio.run/##HYzBCsIwEETP@hVzCd1ACk1TRIr2S3poRIKFuCmxHrz46zHrYd@8mcNun/2RuC/hGv3zdvfgEXPxMRIrWnknr1P@tqwvNqQMj5UXXnSRwrXA9mdTIdcJxJyBqyk@SNo/6mpPYt0wHg9brt/RKPdGO0G9GigQGwRircsP "Python 2 – Try It Online") saves a few bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## J, 18 Bytes (21 with function definition)

```
d=:0:=+/@:(|~"."0@":)
```

Explanation:

```
d=:                     | Define d
                  ":    | Format into string
             "."0       | Turn into array of digits
           |~           | Starting Number mod each element
      +/                | Sum
   0:=                  | Test if it’s equal 0. Returns 1 for true, 0 for false
```

Other characters are for ensuring functions compose properly.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 53 bytes

```python
lambda s:all(s%int(i)==0 if i!='0'else 0 for i in`s`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcoxDoAgDADAr9TB0G7oaMJPHMAo2AQLARx8PcbEmy8/7Uwy92DWHt217Q7q4mLEOrI0ZDJGA3vgwSitjlgP0OBTAQYWWy31XL4YkCXfDYmoT78X)

Comment: [43 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfbhvzPycxNyklUaHYylA3Ma9SI9NG3VA9v0ihWDUzr0QjUzMNyM5UyMxLKE7Q/F9QBBJM18jMKygt0dDU1OTCEPlvCAVchpYA)

Answer (score -1):

## Mathematica - 93ish characters

[Robert G Wilson v](http://oeis.org/wiki/User:Robert_G._Wilson_v) gives us the following for Mathematica:

Function definition:

```
fQ[n_] :=
  Block[{id = Union[IntegerDigits[n]]},
   Union[IntegerQ[#] & /@ (n/id)] == {True}];
```

To call:

```
Select[Range[487], fQ[#] &]
```

Output (ignoring divide by zero complaints):

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 15, 22, 24, 33, 36, 44, 48, 55, 
66, 77, 88, 99, 111, 112, 115, 122, 124, 126, 128, 132, 135, 144, 
155, 162, 168, 175, 184, 212, 216, 222, 224, 244, 248, 264, 288, 312, 
315, 324, 333, 336, 366, 384, 396, 412, 424, 432, 444, 448}
```

Comment: How can you have -ish on a character count?

Comment: Converting to Community Wiki, as this is not your own work.

Comment: Oh, dear, the hallway monitor police are out. I gave full full credit, but I've broken some mysterious "rule" and so get castigated. This is precisely why I've given up even trying to contribute to StackExchange: aside from the privileged core who got in early, they just look down their noses at anyone new. Thanks for the -1.

Answer (score -1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 44 bytes

```scala
def f(n:Int)=n+""forall{k=>k>48&&n%(k-48)<1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY5BCoMwFET3nuITrCRUwWgoUlRw2UUPkWoEa/hKzKIl5Oyp6WJmHjObOUapZdhebzVaeMoFQX2swumAYd9dmNQMM8X7Ay3r8ErIvBmptVu7fu1Fk2V4oWshGtZyH84NKEJbwGCM/FJeNTnwKqqMFqnOoT4zsojJ/3a2/BapFIyBSwB2s6DVSA@SInQ9pO68wTxhiU98@AE)

Comment: error: recursive method f needs result type