# Is it a Lynch-Bell number?

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem

You will be given a positive, whole number (that will never contain a 0) as input. Your task is to check whether it is a Lynch-Bell number or not.

A number is a Lynch-Bell number if all of its digits are unique and the number is divisible by each of its digits.

In fact, there are actually only 548 Lynch-Bell numbers, so hard-coding is a possibility, but will almost certainly be longer.

126 is a Lynch-Bell number because all of its digits are unique, and 126 is divisible by 1, 2, and 6.

You can output any truthy and falsy value.

### Examples:

```
7 -> truthy
126 -> truthy
54 -> falsy
55 -> falsy
3915 -> truthy
```

This is [OEIS A115569](https://oeis.org/A115569).

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/59014/8478) (Asks for all the numbers instead of posing a decision problem.)

Comment: Can I take input as a string?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Of course you can, that's a silly question.

Comment: @Okx Not all challenge posters are as flexible in their allowed inputs as you so always worth an ask.

Answer (score 27):

### Mathematica, 42 bytes

```
0!=##&@@d&&##&@@((d=IntegerDigits@#)∣#)&
```

I think `0!=##&@@d&&##&@@` is a new low in readability for Mathematica...

#### Explanation

Some of the basic syntactic sugar used here:

- `&` has very low precedence and turns everything left of it into an unnamed function.
- `&&` is just the `And` operator.
- `#` is the argument of the nearest enclosing unnamed function.
- `##` is a *sequence* of all of the function's arguments.
- `@` is prefix notation for function calls, i.e. `f@x == f[x]`.
- `@@` is `Apply`, which passes the elements of a list as individual arguments to a function, i.e. `f@@{a,b,c} == f[a,b,c]`.

With that out of the way...

```
(d=IntegerDigits@#)
```

This should be fairly self-explanatory: this gives us a list of the input's decimal digits and stores the result in `d`.

```
(...∣#)
```

This tests the input for divisibility by each of its digits (because the divisibility operator is `Listable`). This gives us a list of `True`s and `False`s.

```
...&@@...
```

We apply the function on the left-hand side to the list of booleans, such that each boolean is a separate argument.

```
...&@@d
```

We apply another function to `d`, so that the individual digits are given as separate arguments. The function is `0!=##&`, i.e. `Unequal[0, d1, d2, ...]`. It checks that all the digits are distinct (and that they are distinct from `0` but that's given by the challenge, and if it wasn't, it wouldn't be a divisor anyway). `0!=##&` is really just a 1-byte saver on using `Unequal` itself, and it works because there's a 1-byte element (`0`) that we know is not present. So this first thing checks that the digits are unique. Let's call this result `U`

```
...&&##
```

Again, this is really just shorthand for `And[U, ##]`. With `##` being a sequences, the individual booleans from the initial divisibility check are expanded into the `And`, so we get `And[U, d1∣n, d2∣n, ...]` which checks that both the digits are unique and each digit divides the input.

Comment: `##&@@d&&##&@@`? What does that even do?

Comment: @Okx Added an explanation.

Comment: May be you can replace `0!=` by  `0<` ?

Comment: @sergiol I'd have to sort the digits to do that.

Comment: New low in readability indeed, normally Mathematica looks like a bunch of syntax-sugar around a few function names I can understand, I was unaware you could make a program entirely out of the sugar :p (of course, your excellent explanation let's me see that its of course not all sugar, but still, very impressive!)

Comment: Please post an ungolfed version.

Comment: Also, `I` is always `Unequal` to digits.

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 56 bytes

```python
lambda n:any(int(n)%int(x)for x in n)or len(n)>len({*n})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjGvUiMzr0QjT1MVRFVopuUXKVQoZOYp5GkCWTmpeUApOxBVrZVXq/m/oAikLE1D3VxdU5MLzjM0MkPhm5qgck1RuMaWhiCB//8B)

Output `False` if it's IS a Lynch-Bell number, `True` otherwise.

Comment: Is this inputting as a string?

Comment: This has two problems: 1) it doesn't give truthy/falsey answers as specified (it's just 4 bytes!); 2) it throws an exception on the input "10". Otherwise, very nice and concise!

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Yes.

Comment: @CRDrost 1) the ouput well defined so there is no problem (usually) 2) there will never be `0` in the input

Comment: 1) I mean, there is a problem, which is that they asked for X and you did not give it. 2) Ah, you're totally right, I missed that completely.

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>6</s> 4 bytes

```
Dg⁼Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98l/VHjnsD/R/ccbn/UtMb9/39zHQVDIzMdBVMTIDbVUTC2NDQFAA)

#### How it works

```
Dg⁼Q  Main link. Argument: n

D     Decimal; convert n to base 10.
 g    Take the GCD of each decimal digit k and n.
      For each k, this yields k if and only if k divides n evenly.
   Q  Unique; yield n's decimal digits, deduplicated.
  ⁼   Test the results to both sides for equality.
```

Comment: There's also `gQV=` if you prefer an ASCII-only solution.

Answer (score 9):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
≠g;?z%ᵐ=h0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1HngnRr@yrVh1sn2GYY/P9vbGlo@h8A)

#### Explanation

```
≠             All digits are different
 g;?z         Zip the input with each of its digits
     %ᵐ       Map mod
       =      All results are equal
        h0    The first one is 0
```

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```
s=>![...s].some((e,i)=>s%e|s.search(e)<i)
```

Takes input as a string and returns `true` or `false` as appropriate. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @RickHitchcock. Other versions:

Takes input as a string and returns `0` or `1` (i.e. logical inverse) for 40 bytes:

```
s=>/(.).*\1/.test(s)|[...s].some(e=>s%e)
```

Takes input as a number and returns `0` or `1` for 43 bytes:

```
n=>/(.).*\1/.test(n)|[...''+n].some(e=>n%e)
```

Takes input as a number and returns `1` or `0` for 45 bytes:

```
n=>!/(.).*\1/.test(n)&![...''+n].some(e=>n%e)
```

Comment: I was unfamiliar with the \n option for back-referencing. +1. You can move the test logic to the some method to save a byte: `s=>![...s].some((e,i)=>s%e|s.search(e)<i)`

Comment: When I used `[...new Array(9999999)].map((_,n)=>n+1+"").filter(s=>![...s].some((e,i)=>s%e|s.search(e)<i)).length` I got `5081` instead of the expected `548`, so this is not correct as written. Really tight code, though.

Comment: Sorry, I retract my comment about this not being correct. My test code is not correct because the original poster expects that zeros have already been filtered out. With an extra `.filter(x => x.indexOf('0')===-1)` this returns 548 as promised.

Answer (score 6):

## C#, <s>87</s> 83 bytes

```c#
using System.Linq;s=>s.Distinct().Count()==s.Length&s.All(c=>int.Parse(s)%(c-48)<1)
```

<sup>I wrote this in notepad before testing in Visual Studio, where it worked fine, so just realised I'm now that level of nerd...</sup>

Full/Formatted Version:

```c#
using System;
using System.Linq;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Func<string, bool> f = s => s.Distinct().Count() == s.Length
                                  & s.All(c => int.Parse(s) % (c - 48) < 1);

        Console.WriteLine(f("7"));
        Console.WriteLine(f("126"));
        Console.WriteLine(f("54"));
        Console.WriteLine(f("55"));
        Console.WriteLine(f("3915"));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/378/)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
ÑÃÙQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MTDzYdnBv7/b2xpaAoA)

Same algorithm as [this answer to a related question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164415/6484).

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 54 bytes

Returns `False` when a number is a Lynch-Bell number. Takes strings as input. Came up with on my own but very similar to Rod's. I would've commented under his post but I don't have any reputation yet.

```python
lambda s:len({*s})<len(s)+any(int(s)%int(c)for c in s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3BDoIwEETvfMVeTLt6oSIaif6Jl4pUm@CWtDUpMX57paBG5rL7JpOZrvc3Q0VUx1Ns5f18keCqtiH@XLoXHtLncCWp55r88C7SqVEZCzVoAoexs8lTnO0YYvYjsd7OuNzMsZxhsRejkaXmkJqtpGvDRZ5jlcEgrYDlbNz0loePm1Qb8poezTdGxoPiU@ovNm0FjPEN)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Welcome! Like Rod's, your function throws an exception on input "10".

Comment: @CRDrost "You will be given a positive, whole number (that will never contain a 0) as input."

Comment: Right, I've posted comments everywhere else I complained about this, but I apparently missed this one. Sorry, retracted!

Comment: @CRDrost No worries!

Answer (score 5):

## Regex (ECMAScript), <s>194</s> <s>171</s> <s>167</s> <s>164</s> <s>155</s> <s>145</s> <s>142</s> 107 bytes

*-35 bytes (142 → 107) [thanks to H.PWiz](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57535240#57535240); this is a complete reimplementation. The primary sources of bytes saved are using* `tail = floor((tail + Digit) / 10) - Digit` *instead of* `tail = floor(tail / 10)` *, and "factoring" the assertions – reusing the expression at the end to mean two different things.*

`^(?!(x{1,9})(((?=(x*)((\1\4){9}x*))\5)*(?=(x*)(\7{9}$))\8\1|(?!\1*$))((?=(x*)((\1\10){9}x*))\11)*(x{10})*$)`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9PU8IwEMW/CnScstvSP3FAhRo4efDCQY9WZzIQ2mhIO0mASulnr@GAo7d97/fe7uwnOzCz1qK2kanFhutdpb74d6@p4sfBCy@emhrgRBdJ0H/AcghNS8azDgFgSaEJ3JCTfILtrHMC8ykGV5DfO/PGeQ85ObtqTgKn/vVI@lskxDXd8rRDF@uD5ISxrV6tFqoAjI0Uaw5342iCmBmaZsdSSA4gqeZsI4XigDikai8ltgWVsamlsDCKRpiJLYCiRSy5KmyJi9vzWZgVW4GgNdOGPysLxVv6jngF/C9QC7Ik8wtGW@rq6D2rA5NiM9BMFXw@8EKZbSsNmXikPBNhiO7gEEToeRjvmF2XkKQJ@r7XeLHmNWcWxJVoxNb4fu3etHD5jGT13hqrXSTrup5EZJqmPw)

Takes its input in unary, as a sequence of `x` characters whose length represents the number.

This was an interesting challenge to solve without molecular lookahead or variable-length lookbehind. The restrictions result in a completely different algorithm being used.

Note that the above version does not reject numbers that have a zero as at least one of their digits, as per the challenge's rules. It costs <s>2 bytes</s> 10 bytes to handle zero correctly, for a total of **<s>144</s> 117 bytes**:

`^(?!(x{0,9})(((?=(x*)((\1\4){9}x*))\5)*(?=(x*)(\7{9}$))\8\1|(?!\1*$))((?=(x*)((\1\10){9}x*))\11)*((x{10})+|(?!\1))$)x`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9BU8IwEIX/CnQY2G1paRxQoQZOHrxw0KPVmQyENhrSTBKgAv3tNYyDo7d973tvd/aD7ZldGaFdbLVYc7Ot1Cf/ag1V/NB55sVjrQGOdD4K23dYdKE@pcNpgwCwoFCHfshJPsbTtPEC8wmGV5DfebPnvfucnH01J6FX/3ok/S0S4pt@O0kbjH7iiD2s23B0xMRVL84IVQAmVooVh9thPEbMLE2zQykkB5DUcLaWQnFA7FK1kxJPBZWJ1VI4GMQDzMQGQNEikVwVrsT5zfks7JItQVDNjOVPykHxmr4hXgH/C9ScLMjsgtGVpjoET2rPpFh3DFMFn3WCSGabykAmHijPRBShPxjUQWK45syBwGTL3KoEg3iy/b72Lzm4fEEyvXPWGR/JmqZNYzJJ028)

The commented version below describes the **<s>144</s> 117 byte** version:

```
^           # tail = N = input number
(?!         # Negative lookahead - Assert that there's no way for the following to match:
    (x{0,9})                       # \1 = conjectured digit; tail -= \1
    # Assert one of the following two alternatives:
    (
        # Assert that \1 occurs as a digit of N, and chop it away (and all the digits
        # right of it) from tail, returning only the digits left of its found instance.
        (
            (?=
                (x*)((\1\4){9}x*)  # \4 = floor((tail + \1) / 10) - \1;
                                   # \5 = tool to make tail = \4
            )
            \5                     # tail = \4
        )*
        (?=
            (x*)(\7{9}$)           # assert tail % 10 == 0; \7 = tail / 10;
                                   # \8 = tool to make tail = \7
        )
        \8\1                       # tail = \7 - \1 (all the digits of N left of where \1
                                   #                 was found, minus \1)
    |
        # Assert that \1 is not a divisor of N
        (?!\1*$)
    )
    # Assert that \1 occurs as a digit in tail+\1, which will either be a second occurrence
    # found further left in N of an already-found occurrence, or any occurrence of a digit
    # that is not a divisor of N.
    (
        (?=
            (x*)((\1\10){9}x*)     # \10 = floor((tail + \1) / 10) - \1;
                                   # \11 = tool to make tail = \10
        )
        \11                        # tail = \10
    )*
    # Assert one of the following two alternatives:
    (
        # Assert tail > 0 and tail % 10 == 0, which means we've found an occurrence of \1
        # that isn't the leftmost digit
        (x{10})+
    |
        # Assert tail == 0 and tail != \1, which means we've found that \1 is the leftmost
        # digit of N and \1 != 0 (which needs to be asserted, otherwise we'd always find
        # a phantom occurrence of the digit 0 left of the leftmost digit of N)
        (?!\1)
    )$
)
x                                  # Prevent N=0 from being matched
```

The version above is very slow, so I'm keeping my **144 byte** solution here:

`^(?!(?=(x*)\1{9})(x{0,9})(?=(x{10})*$|(.*(?=\1$)((?=(x*)(\6{9}x*))\7)*?\B(?=(x*)(\8{9}\2$))\9))((?!\2*$)|\4((?=(x*)(\12{9}x*))\13)*\2(x{10})*$))`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/NbsIwEIRfBRCC3UBCnCJaSE2kSj1w4dAe61aywCRujRPZ5qckPDtNpEJ72t35ZjWaT77ndmVk4XxbyLUw21x/ie@LoVocWi8ifT4WACc6H3mXD0jakFA4eshIOT0jHMtw2MxGLEl4Rq9bQeDVNyNdhF8zsEntrhdk9@gl7OmmP9Q6i7o1mGJjb7PI62LFxn@vJLr@kjv0WHQLQrx4oxMGLn91RuoUMLBKrgRMhv4YMbY0jA@ZVAJAUSP4WkktALFN9U4pLFOqAlso6aDv9zGWGwBN00AJnboM51FVSbvkS5C04MaKhXaQvoXviFcg/gM9JwmZNRhdZvJDZ6H3XMl1y3CdilmrM1DxJjcQy0cqYjkYYB3YOXYCIwrBHUgMttytMjCIpe31irqSg6YFiYuds87Ulvh8voR@FIbhDw)

```
^           # tail = N = input number
(?!         # Negative lookahead - Assert that there's no way for the following to match:
    (?=(x*)\1{9})                # \1 = floor(N / 10)
    (x{0,9})                     # \2 = take a guess at a numeral that may occur as any
                                 #      digit of N, even the rightmost one; tail -= \2
    # Assert that \2 occurs as a digit in N, and if it does, identify the rest of N to
    # the left of that digit, so that we can set tail equal to it later (so we can later
    # assert that \2 is not duplicated).
    (?=
        (x{10})*$                # Skip the rest if we picked the rightmost digit of N
    |
        (                        # \4 = tool to make tail = \8
            .*(?=\1$)            # tail = \1
            # Loop through chopping away each rightmost decimal digit of tail, one by one
            (
                (?=
                    (x*)         # \6 = floor(tail / 10)
                    (\6{9}x*)    # \7 = tool to make tail = \6
                )
                \7               # tail = \6
            )*?                  # Only iterate until we find the first match of the
                                 # following:
            \B                   # Leave at least one digit remaining (to avoid
                                 # thinking we've found a zero-digit when there isn't
                                 # actually one)
            (?=(x*)(\8{9}\2$))   # \8 = floor(tail/10); \9 = tool to make tail = \8;
                                 # assert that tail % 10 == \2, i.e. that our guessed
                                 # digit matches the current rightmost digit of tail
            \9                   # tail = \8
        )
    )
    # \2 is now one of the decimal digits of N.
    # Assert that either of the following two alternatives could match, and in the
    # context outside of the negative lookahead, that neither of them can match:
    (
        # Assert tail is not divisible by \2. It doesn't matter that tail == N-\2
        # instead of N, because that doesn't alter tail's divisibility by \2.
        (?!\2*$)
    |                            # or...
        # Assert that \2 doesn't occur as any decimal digit left of where it was found
        \4                       # tail = \8 if \8 is set, otherwise no change; this
                                 #        relies on ECMAScript NPCG behavior.
        # Chop away any number (minimum 0) of rightmost decimal digits of tail
        (
            (?=(x*)(\12{9}x*))   # \12 = floor(tail / 10);
                                 # \13 = tool to make tail = \12
            \13                  # tail = \12
        )*                       # Iterate any number of times, minimum 0
        \2                       # tail -= \2
        (x{10})*$                # assert tail is divisible by 10
    )
)
```

## Regex (ECMAScript + `(?*)`), 81 bytes

`^(?!(?*(((?=(x*)(\3{9}(x*)))\4)+))((?!\5+$)|\1((?=(x*)(\8{9}x*))\9)*\5(x{10})*$))`

This challenge is much easier to solve with molecular lookahead; it's the version I implemented first.

Working on this alerted me to the presence of a bug in my regex engine [(now fixed)](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine/issues/6).

```
^           # tail = N = input number
(?!         # Negative lookahead - Assert that there's no way for the following to match:
    (?*     # Molecular lookahead - cycle through all possible matches of the following:
        (                            # \1 = tool to make tail = the final value of \3
            # Loop through chopping away each rightmost decimal digit of tail, one by one
            (
                (?=(x*)(\3{9}(x*)))  # \3 = floor(tail / 10); \4 = tool to make tail = \3;
                                     # \5 =       tail % 10
                \4                   # tail = \3
            )+                       # Iterate at least once, otherwise \5 could be unset
            # The above loop relies on ECMAScript no-empty-optional behavior. This
            # prevents it from matching when the final result of zero is again divided
            # by 10, which would yield a value of \5 = 0, making it look like one of N's
            # digits was zero and preventing all values of N from matching.
        )
    )
    # \5 is now one of the decimal digits of N, and tail==N again
    # Assert that either of the following two alternatives could match, and in the context
    # outside of the negative lookahead, that neither of them can match:
    (
        (?!\5+$)                     # Assert tail is not divisible by \5
    |                                # or...
        # Assert that the \5 doesn't occur as any decimal digit left of where it was found
        \1                           # tail = \3
        # Chop away any number (minimum 0) of rightmost decimal digits of tail
        (
            (?=(x*)(\8{9}x*))        # \8 = floor(tail / 10); \9 = tool to make tail = \8;
            \9                       # tail = \8
        )*                           # Iterate any number of times, minimum 0
        \5                           # tail -= \5
        (x{10})*$                    # assert tail is divisible by 10
    )
)
```

## Regex (ECMAScript 2018), 85 bytes

`^(?!((?=(x*)(\2{9}(x*)))\3)+((?<=(?=(?!\4+$))^.*)|((?=(x*)(\7{9}x*))\8)*\4(x{10})*$))`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5NT8JAEIb/ijQmO0Nh0yKJSll68sCFgx6thE27lDHrtu4uH0npb6@tiZHbm3memXk/5Um63FLtp6YqVOdElFjxqsqXSw1v3pIpuZXnXbeFdASQCriMEbJZ89wOCTF7wLCfL8XA0lE2D@8Rt3yM13/7sbcHOXvCcTaHSxNHLY57r9txpylXEE@mMWJi1feRrAJmlSw0GcWQ5332am28snvZqw2Z@ugXta1y5Rx3viDTIq8MsN@NiRarphSau1qTBzZlmNAewIiSa2VKf8DV7Holt5EbIFFL64brUL5HH4h/QN0Cs4rTeDFg9AdbnYO1OUlNxZ2VplSLuyDUyb6ykNBSqITCEPuHwSXgVtV9eSDkX9LnB7CIzU3x6uj52ZJXAC5lmWELxjAkTJyIk7bFLprOoij6AQ)

This is a port of the molecular lookahead version. The most direct port would be replacing `(?*A)B` with `A(?<=(?=B)^.*)`, but that would result in an 89 byte regex.

```
^           # tail = N = input number
(?!         # Negative lookahead - Assert that there's no way for the following to match:
    # Loop through chopping away each rightmost decimal digit of tail, one by one
    (
        (?=(x*)(\2{9}(x*)))      # \2 = floor(tail / 10); \3 = tool to make tail = \2;
                                 # \4 =       tail % 10
        \3                       # tail = \2
    )+                           # Iterate at least once, otherwise \4 could be unset
    # The above loop relies on ECMAScript no-empty-optional behavior. This prevents it
    # from matching when the final result of zero is again divided by 10, which would
    # yield a value of \4 = 0, making it look like one of N's digits was zero and
    # preventing all values of N from matching.

    # \4 is now one of the decimal digits of N, and tail==\2
    # Assert that either of the following two alternatives could match, and in the context
    # outside of the negative lookahead, that neither of them can match:
    (
        (?<=                     # Variable-length lookbehind - used to go back to start
            (?=
                # now tail==N again
                (?!\4+$)         # Assert tail is not divisible by \4
            )
            ^.*                  # Go back to start, then execute the above lookahead
        )
    |                            # or...
        # now tail==\2
        # Assert that the \4 doesn't occur as any decimal digit left of where it was found
        # Chop away any number (minimum 0) of rightmost decimal digits of tail
        (
            (?=(x*)(\7{9}x*))    # \7 = floor(tail / 10); \8 = tool to make tail = \7;
            \8                   # tail = \7
        )*                       # Iterate any number of times, minimum 0
        \4                       # tail -= \4
        (x{10})*$                # assert tail is divisible by 10
    )
)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/), 249 bytes

[Try it online!](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/513627304/)

I feel as though this could be improved by a few bytes, but I'm not sure...

```
when gf clicked
ask()and wait
set[C v]to()
set[N v]to(answer
repeat(length of(n
change[C v]by(1
add(letter(C)of(N))to[B v
end
say[T
repeat(C
set[D v]to(item(1)of[B v
delete(1)of[B v
if<<[B v]contains(D)?>or<not<((N)/(D))=(round((N)/(D)))>>>then
say(
```

Alternatively, 34 blocks.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 17 bytes

```
[:(<.-:~.)10&#.%]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o600bPR0rer0NA0N1JT1VGP/a3L5OekpaNiqKQMFtQxsDZX1atSU9JSq67i4UpMz8hXUQ4pKSzIq1SG8NAVjBUsFQwVTGFfHSsEcxjZUMFIwg2lzS8wpTkVoM1UwUUCwTRX@AwA)

Take input as list of digits.

- `10&#.%]` The list of quotients.  Returns floats.
- `(<.-:~.)` Does the unique of that list `~.` match `-:` the list formed by rounding every element down to an integer `<.`?

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>15</s> <s>14</s> <s>11</s> <s>10</s> 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ì®yUÃ¥Uìâ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=7K55VcOlVezi&input=WzcsMTI2LDU0LDU1LDM5MTVdCi1t)

Comment: `©!` -> `«` for -1 byte

Comment: Thanks, @JustinMariner; don't know how that went so long without being spotted! I found a shorter solution, though.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
D⁼QaDḍ$Ạ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/lUeOewESXhzt6VR7uWvD//39DIzMA)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>62</s> 48 bytes

```php
while($i=$argn[$k++])$r|=$argn%$i|$$i++;echo!$r;
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [test it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4bb7b82d9f391bb8862ca1308d60c3c6717bb43f). Empty output for falsy, `1` for truthy.

**breakdown**

```php
while($i=$argn[$k++])   # loop through digits
    $r|=                    # set $r to true if
        $argn%$i            # 1. number is not divisible by $i
        |$$i++;             # 2. or digit has been used before
echo!$r;                # print negated $r
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 61 bytes

```hs
(#)=<<show
(d:r)#n=notElem d r&&mod n(read[d])<1&&r#n
_#_=0<3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcrBCoIwGADg@57ih8VQmNCaK4rtICFeIrx0KpHBFCW3yRQ6RM@@unf@vkEvz26a4jvDcCmu1a2oSjjXNeDsg3r1iAlOlZTL4F8oMaeQYqecX8ups2AgEGK9AZeETpu7aVLJCAnYoRa3ait5tHp0oMB4BDCH0a2wAatn6OF@oGy3p/zIRPOPIqdCUMZ/h@esiV8)

Defines an anonymous function `(#)=<<show` which, given a number, returns `True` or `False`.

Comment: This function fails on the input 10.

Comment: Sorry, I am wrong about that -- I missed that you're not required to provide any answer for inputs that have 0s in them.

Answer (score 2):

## [ruby -n](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 40 bytes

```ruby
p gsub(/./){$'[$&]||$_.to_i%$&.hex}<?0*8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0Ahvbg0SUNfT1@zWkU9WkUttqZGJV6vJD8@U1VFTS8jtaLWxt5Ay@L/f3MuQyMzLlMTLlNTLmNLQ1MuSwszc2NDo3/5BSWZ@XnF/3XzAA)

Read in the number as a string. Substitute each character (digit) with a subsequent occurrence of that character, if present, or the whole number modulo that digit. This will result in a string of only `0`s if and only if this is a Lynch-Bell number. Why? If there's a repeated digit, every instance of the last stays the same, and since the input doesn't contain zeroes that means a non-zero digit. Otherwise, we're just checking whether every digit evenly divides the number.

Since there are no 8-or-more-digit Lynch-Bell numbers (formal proof: OEIS says so), checking whether the resulting string is lexicographically earlier than the string `'00000000'` is equivalent to checking whether it's all zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, <s>76</s> 74 bytes

*-2 bytes using `ROWS` instead of `COUNTA`*

```
=LET(n,LEN(A2),d,MID(A2,SEQUENCE(n),1),AND(ROWS(UNIQUE(d))=n,MOD(A2,d)=0))
```

[Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnBGANF6irExkYlu-?e=dn5d5s)

```
LET(                               'Assign Variables
n,LEN(A2)                          '   n = # of digits
d,MID(A2,SEQUENCE(n),1)            '   d = array of digits
AND(ROWS(UNIQUE(d))=n,MOD(A2,d)=0) 'Result
    ROWS(UNIQUE(d))=n              '   # unique d = n
                      MOD(A2,d)=0  '   number mod d = 0
AND(                             ) '   and all tests
```

Original

```
=LET(n,LEN(A2),d,MID(A2,SEQUENCE(n),1),AND(COUNTA(UNIQUE(d))=n,MOD(A2,d)=0))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 22 bytes

```
{&/~(t*t~?t:10\x)!\:x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqlpNv06jRKukzr7EytAgpkJTMcaqovZ/mrq5gqGRmYKpiYKpqYKxpaHpfwA)

- `(...t:10\x)` get the individual digits of the input, storing in `t`
- `(t*t~?t...)` if the digits aren't all unique, multiply them by 0 (otherwise leave them as-is)
- `(...)!\:x` mod the input by each of the digits (with `x mod 0` == `x`)
- `&/~` are all the remainders 0?

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 57 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 7.125 bytes

```
:₌Kf↔$f⁼
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwiOuKCjEtm4oaUJGbigbwiLCIiLCIxMjciXQ==)

Bitstring:

```
010100100010101011101010110011110100011101011011111010110
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 13 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
≍⊝⌊.÷-@0$"_".
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4omN4oqd4oyKLsO3LUAwJCJfIi4K4oi1ZiA3XzEyNl81NF81NV8zOTE1)

Not too bad, given the bulky syntax to convert a number into its decimal digits. The main idea is taken from [alephalpha's Nekomata answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266132/78410).

Note: the symbol for "match" (test if two arrays are structurally equal as a whole) has been changed from `≅` to `≍`.

Also, this code doesn't work when the input contains a 0, because division by 0 gives NaN, floor of NaN is still NaN, and two NaNs are equal.

```
≍⊝⌊.÷-@0$"_".    input: a positive integer
         $"_"     stringify the input
      -@0         subtract '0' from each char, giving decimal digits as numbers
     ÷       .    divide the original number by each digit
≍⊝⌊.             test if this array, floored and deduplicated, still equals itself
```

A version that also handles zero digits (giving falsy) in 15 bytes ([Try it](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4omN4oqaPTDiioPil7_iipstQDAkIl8iLgriiLVmIDdfMTI2XzU0XzU1XzM5MTVfMTI2MA==)):

```
≍⊚=0⊃◿⊛-@0$"_".
          -@0$"_"     decimal digits of input
     ⊃◿⊛       .    push (input % digits, classification of digits)
                      (classify: assign a unique index to each unique element)
 ⊚=0                 indices where input % digits == 0
≍                    match?
```

The final match gives 1 if and only if the number is Lynch-Bell, because:

- `indices where input % digits == 0` has the length equal to the number of digits if and only if `input % digits == 0` is all true,
- its result is precisely `0 1 2 ... x-1` where `x` is the number of digits in that case, and
- the classification is the same if and only if the digits are all unique.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
SÖP¹DÙQ*
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/@PC0gEM7XQ7PDNT6/9/Y0tAUAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 57 bytes

```
Tr@Boole[IntegerQ/@Union[s=#/IntegerDigits@#]]==Length@s&
```

Comment: You can save numerous bytes if you use the builtin `IsLynchBellNumber`

Comment: why don't you make the same offer to Martin?

Comment: @Okx but it's less fun that way.

Comment: @QBrute Can you take a joke?

Comment: @Okx It would have been more believable as `LynchBellNumberQ`. ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 66 bytes

This is a solution in Python 2, whose whole purpose is to output `True` for truthy and `False` for falsy:

```python
lambda n:len(set(n))==len(n)and not any((int(n)%int(x)for x in n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcqxCoNAEATQ3q/YRtwtNTEhgfsTmxM9FMycmCv061e3Ea4a3sysR5oiGg2u08X/@sETvssI/o@JIeKcAeIxEGIij4N5hm2lxS4hbrTTDLreum5WBq7elUhxq25emdtnzjbj41NboXoC)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 37 bytes

```
(.).*\1
0
.
<$&$*1>$_$*
<(1+)>\1+

^$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0NPU08rxpDLgEuPy0ZFTUXL0E4lXkWLy0bDUFvTLsZQm4srTuX/f3MuQyMzLlMTLlNTLmNLQ1MA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: The first stage replaces any duplicate digit with a zero. The second stage replaces each digit with its unary representation followed by the unary representation of the original number. The third stage then computes the remainder of the division of original number by each non-zero digit. If the number is a Lynch-Bell number then this will delete everything and this is tested for by the final stage.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, <s>260</s> <s>241</s> <s>201</s> 162 bytes

```
f([x])=1<2
f(x:xs)=not(x`elem`xs)&&(f xs)
r n i= n`mod`(read[(show n!!i)]::Int)==0
q n 0=r n 0 
q n i=r n i&&q n(i-1)
p n=length(show n)-1
s n=q n(p n)&&f(show n)
```

Explanation

```
f ([x]) = True                                           f function checks for                                                       
f (x:xs) = not(x `elem` xs) && (f xs)                    repeated digits              
r n i = n `mod` (read [(show n !! i)] :: Int) == 0       checks whether num is 
                                                         divisible by i digit
q n 0 = r n 0                                            checks wether n divisible
q n i = r n i && q n (i-1)                               by all of its digits                             
p n = length (show n) -                                  gets length of number                             
s n = (q n (p n)) && (f (show n))                        sums it all up!!!
```

Have significantly shortened thanx to [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG and Haskell golfing in particular! This answer can be considerably shortened by removing superfluous spaces, e.g. the ones around the equal signs or next to parenthesis.

Comment: You might also be interested in [Tips for golfing in Haskell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19255/tips-for-golfing-in-haskell) and the [Guide to Golfing Rules in Haskell](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11924/new-users-guides-to-golfing-rules-in-specific-languages/11935#11935).

Comment: @Laikoni Thanx for your advice! I'm looking into it

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, 17 bytes

CJam is the Java of golfing languages. It's even interpreted in Java!

```
{_Ab__L|=@@f%:+>}
```

#### Explanation:

```
{   e# Stack:              3915
_   e# Duplicate:          3915 3915
Ab  e# Digits in base 10:  3915 [3 9 1 5]
__  e# Duplicate twice:    3915 [3 9 1 5] [3 9 1 5] [3 9 1 5]
L|  e# Remove duplicates:  3915 [3 9 1 5] [3 9 1 5] [3 9 1 5]
=   e# Test equality:      3915 [3 9 1 5] 1
@@  e# Rotate twice:       1 3915 [3 9 1 5]
f%  e# Modulo each:        1 [0 0 0 0]
:+  e# Sum:                1 0
>   e# Greater than:       1
}   e# Output:             1 (truthy)
```

Answer (score 1):

### VBScript, 177 bytes

Hey all, this is my very first CG post, and first attempt, so hope I followed all the rules...

```
Function L(s)
dim i,j,k,m,n
j = Len(s)
redim a(j)
n = 0
for i = 0 to j-1
   A(i) = Mid(s,i+1,1)   
   m = m + s Mod A(i)   
   if j = 1 then         
   else                             
        for k = 0 to i - 1        
            if A(i)  = A(k) then n = n + 1   
        next
   end if
next
if m + n = 0 then L = "y" else L = "n"
End Function
```

This can be run from Notepad by adding a line at the end

```
Msgbox L(InputBox(""))
```

And then saving it as .vbs, then double click.

Explanation:

```
Function L(s)                  'creates the function "L" taking test number as input
dim i,j,k,t,m,n                'variables
j = Len(s)                     '"j" gets length of test number
redim a(j)                     'creates array "a", size is length of test number 
n = 0                          'sets repeat character counter "n" to zero
for i = 0 to j-1               'for length of string
   A(i) = Mid(s,i+1,1)         'each array slot gets one test number character
   m = m + s Mod A(i)          '"m" accumulates moduli as we test divisibility of each digit
   if j = 1 then               'if test number is of length 1, it passes (do nothing)
   else                        'otherwise, gotta test for repeats     
        for k = 0 to i - 1     'for each digit already in array, test against current digit   
            if A(i)  = A(k) then n = n + 1  
                               'repeat char counter "n" stores no of repeats  
        next                   'proceed through array looking for repeat  
   end if
next                           'test next digit for divisibility and repeats
if m + n = 0 then L = "y" else L = "n"      
                               'check for any repeats and moduli,
                               'then return yes or no for LynchBelledness
End Function
```

VBScript is a bit of blunt instrument for golfing, but hey, I haven't learned Ruby yet...

Comment: Can't you remove some of the whitespace like 'L="y"'

Comment: Technically, yes! I shoulda done that...btw, i'm looking at codegolf languages that might be cool to learn, but for most, the documentation is minimal to non-existent...can anyone recommend a good language that is well documented? Was trying out "Actually/Seriously" but hit some obstacles due to lack of doc....

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 10 bytes

```
qiRQKjQT{K
```

[Verify all the test cases.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=qiRQKjQT%7BK&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=7%0A126%0A54%0A55%0A3915&debug=0)

### How?

```
qiRQKjQT{K  ~ Full program.

     jQT    ~ The list of decimal digits of the input.
    K       ~ Assign to a variable K.
 iRQ        ~ For each decimal digit...
 i Q          ~ ... Get the greatest common divisor with the input itself.
        {K  ~ K with the duplicate elements removed.
q           ~ Is equal? Output implicitly.
```

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 11 bytes

```
&!f%sQsTQ{I
```

[Verify all the test cases.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%26%21f%25sQsTQ%7BI&input=12&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%227%22%0A%22126%22%0A%2254%22%0A%2255%22%0A%223915%22&debug=0)

### How?

```
&!f%sQsTQ{I  ~ Full program, with implicit input.

  f     Q    ~ Filter over the input string.
   %sQsT     ~ The input converted to an integer modulo the current digit.
             ~ Keeps it if it is higher than 0, and discards it otherwise.
 !           ~ Negation. If the list is empty, returns True, else False.
&        {I  ~ And is the input invariant under deduplicating? Output implicitly.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, <s>34</s> 29 bytes

```perl
$_=!grep$k{$_}++|"@F"%$_,/./g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lYxvSi1QCW7WiW@Vlu7RsnBTUlVJV5HX08//b@1arathqb1f0MjMy5zLlMTLmNLQ9N/@QUlmfl5xf91CxJzAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 24 bytes

```apl
{((,⍵)≡∪⍵)×∧/0=(⍎¨⍵)|⍎⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v1pDQ@dR71bNR50LH3WsArEOT3/UsVzfwFbjUW/foRUgkRogC0jX/k971DYBxO6b6un/qKv50HrjR20TgbzgIGcgGeLhGfz/Ue@qaqBaHXUrBXWdNJCuQyvUzdUV1A2NzICkqQmIMAUSxpaGpuoA)

Simple Dfn, can probably be golfed a bit more. Yield standard APL booleans 1 for truthy, 0 for falsy.

It's worth to mention that the function takes the arguments as strings rather than ints.

#### How:

```apl
{((,⍵)≡∪⍵)×∧/0=(⍎¨⍵)|⍎⍵} ⍝ Dfn, argument ⍵.
                      ⍎⍵  ⍝ Convert ⍵ to integer
                     |    ⍝ Modulus
                (⍎¨⍵)     ⍝ Each digit in ⍵
              0=          ⍝ Equals 0? Returns a vector of booleans
            ∧/            ⍝ Logical AND reduction
           ×              ⍝ multiplied by (the result of)
  (     ∪⍵)               ⍝ unique elements of ⍵
       ≡                  ⍝ Match
   (,⍵)                   ⍝ ⍵ as a vector; the Match function then returns 1 iff all digits in ⍵ are unique
```

Comment: `(,⍵)≡∪` → `(,=∪)`

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 86 bytes

```r
x=scan(,'');a=as.double;all(table(utf8ToInt(x))==1)&&all(!a(x)%%a(el(strsplit(x,""))))
```

Takes input as a string. I certainly feel like this is golfable.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8K2ODkxT0NHXV3TOtE2sVgvJb80KSfVOjEnR6MkEcjSKC1JswjJ98wr0ajQ1LS1NdRUUwNJKiYC@aqqiRqpORrFJUXFBTmZQBU6SkqaQPDf0MjsPwA)

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 62 bytes

Golf by Giuseppe

```r
all(table(d<-utf8ToInt(x<-scan(,''))-48)<2)&all(!strtoi(x)%%d)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzEnR6MkMSknVSPFRre0JM0iJN8zr0Sjwka3ODkxT0NHXV1TU9fEQtPGSFMNpFaxuKSoJD9To0JTVTVF87@hkdl/AA)

Comment: [63 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8W2tCTNIiTfM69Eo8JGtzg5MU9DR11dU1PXxMI6MSdHoyQxKSdVI0XTxkhTDcRXLC4pKsnP1KjQVFVN0fxvaGT2HwA).

Comment: @Giuseppe How you do it I'll never know...

Comment: Practice, haha. I started with minor golfs like substituting `strtoi` for `as.double`, then noticed that digits were being extracted twice (once with `utf8ToInt` and once with `strsplit`), so I got them once at the beginning (with `strsplit`), then tried to get rid of the `strtoi` entirely by using `utf8ToInt()-48` (which I didn't notice before, but that's also shorter than `strsplit`), but I wasn't able to get it down all the way.

Comment: Another failed approach was to try to collapse the `all(...)&all(...)` into one `all(...&...)`, which errored out. I did manage to find [62 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzEnR6MkMSknVSPFRre0JM0iJN8zr0Sjwka3ODkxT0NHXV1TU9fEQtPGSFMNpFaxuKSoJD9To0JTVTVF87@hkdl/AA) by better in-lining of assignments, though, so that's neat.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 50 bytes

```python
lambda n:all(int(n)%int(d)+n.count(d)<2for d in n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjEnRyMzr0QjT1MVRKVoaufpJeeXgpk2Rmn5RQopCpl5Cnma/wuKQArSNNTN1TU1ueA8QyMzFL6pCSrXFIVrbGkIEvj/HwA)

Returns `True` if the (zero-free) number is a Lynch-Bell number, `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 3 bytes

```
Ɗ¦ů
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJuqlLsgqWlJWm6FsuOdR1adnT9kuKk5GKo0IIN5lyGRmZcpiZcpqZcxpaGphBxAA)

```
Ɗ¦ů
Ɗ       Decimal digits
 ¦      Divided by, and check if the result are integers
  ů     Check if all elements are unique
```

Comment: Q: Is there a way that you could adjust this so it doesn't need a flag?  Or is the existence/nonexistence of the non-deterministic solutions 'invisible' from within the program?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Nekomata doesn't have truthy/falsy. so the flag `-e` is needed for every [tag:decision-problem] challenge.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen You can add an `n` (`\countValue`) to the end of the code so that it returns `1` and `0` ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FsuPdR1adnR93pLipORiqNiCDeZchkZmXKYmXKamXMaWhqYQcQA)). But they are not truthy/falsy [by this definition on meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/9288).

Comment: Surely 'non-fail' and 'fail' could be considered to be analogous to 'truthy' and 'falsy'?  So ```andThen``` behaves as "if X doesn't fail, then ..." [like this](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FuuPdR1adnS9UkhRaaqSyqH9S4qTkouhcgs2mHMZGplxmZpwmZpyGVsamkLEAQ), and ```if``` behaves as "if X fails, then ..." [like this](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FuuOdR1adnS9kltiTnGqkueS4qTkYqjUgg3mXIZGZlymJlymplzGloamEHEA)...

Comment: (in which case, ```Ɗ¦ů``` is already valid as a decision function as-is, returning 'non-fail' or 'fail', and the ```-e``` flag is just for pretty output, and not really required...)

Answer (score 0):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 9 bytes

```
ℚ₁₁₁ℚ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//8PcCesetcx61NQIZLWCqak9QAooBmRN@v/f0MgMAA)

-2 thanks to [Okx](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/26600/okx).

Hmm, there's a nice symmetry... `oO.O.O.Oo`

Comment: You can golf `D` to `ℚ` (uniquify, check for equality ignoring types)

Comment: Still room for golfing there ;)

Comment: @Okx Hmm...I don't see anything particularly interesting there.

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 51 bytes

prints zero for true and one for false

```php
for(;$c=$argn[$i++];$$c=1)$t|=$$c||$argn%$c;echo$t;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6tkaqpk/T8tv0jDWiXZFiwWrZKprR1rrQLkG2qqlNTYAlk1NWApVZVk69TkjHyVEuv//wE)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 62 bytes

prints zero for true and one for false

```php
for($a=$argn;$c=$a[$i];)$t|=strpos($a,$c)<+$i++||$a%$c;echo$t;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6tkaGSmZP0/Lb9IQyXRFixmrZIMZESrZMZaa6qU1NgWlxQV5BcDpXVUkjVttFUytbVralQSVVWSrVOTM/JVSqz//wcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 27 bytes

```
{$_%%.comb.all&&[!=] .comb}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WiVeVVUvOT83SS8xJ0dNLVrRNlYBzK/9b61QnFipkF6UWqBQrahvoK@gpqaQpqESr1mroxBnaGBg8B8A)

- `.comb` is a method which, when given no arguments, splits a string into its individual characters.  A number is implicitly converted into a string, and so `.comb` returns its digits.
- `.comb.all` is an and-junction of all of the digits.
- `$_ %% .comb.all` is an and-junction of the divisibility of the input argument `$_` by all of its digits.  For example, if `$_` is `123`, the junction is `all(True, False, True)`, which collapses to `False` in a truthy context.
- `[!=] .comb` reduces the digits of the input argument with the `!=` operator, which evaluates to `True` if the digits are all different.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby 2.4, 42 bytes

```
->x{(r=x.digits)|[]==r&&r.none?{|f|x%f>0}}
```

(No TIO yet, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org) 1.1, <s>98</s> <s>66</s> 59 bytes

```
{i->i.none{i.toInt()%(it-'0')>0}&&i.length==i.toSet().size}
```

### Beautified

```
{i ->
    // None of the digits are not factors
    i.none { i.toInt() % (it-'0') > 0 }
    // AND
    &&
    // None of the digits are repeated
    i.length == i.toSet().size
}
```

### Test

```
var L:(String)-> Boolean =
{i->i.none{i.toInt()%(it-'0')>0}&&i.length==i.toSet().size}
data class TestData(val input: String, val output: Boolean)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var inputs = listOf(
        TestData("7", true),
        TestData("126", true),
        TestData("54", false),
        TestData("55", false),
        TestData("3915", true)
    )

    for (test in inputs) {
        if (L(test.input) != test.output) {
            throw AssertionError(test.toString())
        }
    }
    println("Test Passed")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 39 bytes

```julia
f(x,d=digits(x))=rem.(x,d)==0*unique(d)
```

`rem.(x,d)` is a vector containing the remainders after dividing x by each digit in `x`. `0*unique(d)` is a vector with length equal to the number of unique digits, with all zero values. Check if they are equal.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P02jQifFNiUzPbOkWKNCU9O2KDVXDySmaWtroFWal1lYmqqRovnfIbG4OLWoRCFNw1yTC8ExNDJDcBXTNExNULmmyIqNLQ1NNf8DAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 95 bytes

```powershell
param($n)$a="$n"|% t*y;if($n-eq([int](($a|gu)-join''))){
($a|%{12%[int]"$_"})-contains0}else{0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVPUyXRVkklT6lGVaFEq9I6Mw0opptaqBGdmVcSq6GhkliTXqqpm5WfmaeurqmpWc0FElKtNjRSBatQUolXqtXUTc7PK0nMzCs2qE3NKU6tNqj9//@/oZExAA)

Comment: `54` and `1232` should be falsy

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 31 bytes

```apl
{∧/(0=⍺|⍨¨⍵)∧(⊢≡∪)⍵}∘(10⊥⍣¯1⊢)⍨
 ∧/ ⍝ reduction by logical AND
   0=⍺|⍨¨⍵ ⍝ divisibility check
     ∧ ⍝ logical AND
       (⊢≡∪)⍵ ⍝ check for unique digits
         ∘ ⍝ function composition operator (Beside)
           10⊥⍣¯1⊢ ⍝ convert to array of digits
             ⍨ ⍝ commute operator (Selfie), used to copy input to left side of the composed function
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqRx3L9TUMbB/17qp51Lvi0IpHvVs1gWIaj7oWPepc@KhjlSZQpPZRxwwNQ4NHXUsf9S4@tN4QKAkUXgE0QsGcK03B0MgMSJqagAhTIGFsaWgKAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, <s>88</s> 86 bytes

```
def f(n):
 s=""
 for i in n:
  if i in s or int(n)%int(i)!=0:return 0
  s+=i
 return 1
```

Fixed that it wasn't running with whitespace removed - thanks to @caird coinheringaahing

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833)! Your version without whitespace [doesn't work](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNI0/TSqHYVklJIS2/SCFTITNPIc9KITMNwixWAAnmlQBVqYKoTE1FWwMrhaLUktKiPAW3xJziVKDmYu1MmFBIUWnq//8A), but it's an [easy fix and golf](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNI0/Tikuh2FZJiUshLb9IIVMhM08hDyikkJkG4RQrgITzSoAqVUFUpqairYFVUWpJaVGeggFQYbG2bSaXAlTA8P9/AA)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thanks for checking, is there a syntax guide anywhere for writing functions without whitespace without messing them up and having them not run?

Comment: Not sure about a syntax guide but feel free to check out our [New users guide for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11925/66833) for more info

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Okay thanks. What actually is it about the syntax that isn't allowed?

Comment: So long as the program runs as is, it's a valid submission. As the program doesn't run when you remove the newlines, it isn't a valid submission

Answer (score 0):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/), 109 bytes

```
n=q-48
l=n.length
abs(\prod_{a=1}^l\prod_{b=a+1}^{l}(n[b]-n[a])(1-sign(mod(\sum_{c=1}^ln[c]10^{l-c},n).max)))
```

[View it in Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jvxx1yuvwu)

There's got to be a better way to do this, but I can't come up with it right now. This is sort of split up into a few sections:

```
n=q-48
```

This turns codepoints into digits for convenience's sake

```
\prod_{a=1}^l\prod_{b=a+1}^{l}(n[b]-n[a])
```

This checks if any two digits are equal, and if so, returns 0

```
\sum_{c=1}^ln[c]10^{l-c}
```

This turns the list of digits into the number

```
1-sign(mod(\sum_{c=1}^ln[c]10^{l-c},n).max)
```

This uses the previous section to check if any digit isn't divisible by the sum, and if so, returns 0

Then we turn this into a 1 if the result succeeds both tests and 0 if it fails one. We can cut out 5 bytes if we accept any non-zero number as true by removing the `abs(` from the start of the third equation and `)` from the end, but I'm not sure if negative numbers really count as truthy. We can also get rid of 6 bytes if we can accept a list of digits as input rather than a string.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 33 bytes

```javascript
s=>[...s].every(y=e=>y[e]^=s%e<1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HZDdasMwDIXv9xS7GU0IS7GlyjZp@iKlg9I5xaM0IxmFgN49O8qF5Z8jHX3yz/V1nW9T@f37fI7feR36de5P57Zt50ubX3laqqXP/Wk558tXP3/ko6vXbhinqvSuK0eXqWuaUpehGqrS7HZ1fRuf8/jI7WO8V6Xu3vb7d6deSVkPKho0alLn1R3Us5IoR1wZS7BwJmh0UCfYBfeAc2T1TlAQ1QuqUE8wIHOARgk2eGPUCnbBuyBXgtcAzwC/gLwIjwgtwiOR9dvCRgALtLZgjck6UzIM45GEEFDlrNwly0sGmZDskY2wMcLFk5ESkj2bkHAlm45sJLKZyCWDN2EbxwecGD3I6Em2jwEVGTAZLSUbN0Fg@yR2mIyNno2UoSiDdP0H)

If an `e` appears twice then `s%e<1` is still true, and `y[e]^=` returns 0