# How many Lynch-Bell numbers are there?

Tags: code-golf, number, base-conversion

### Challenge

Given an integer, `n`, as input where `36 >= n >= 2`, output how many Lynch-Bell numbers there are in base `n`.

The output must be in base 10.

### Lynch-Bell Numbers

A number is a Lynch-Bell numbers if:

- All of its digits are unique (no repetition of digits)
- The number is divisible by each of its digits
- It doesn't contain zero as one of its digits

Since, all of the digits have to be unique, and you have a finite set of single digit numbers in each base, there is a finite number of Lynch-Bell numbers.

For example, in base 2 there is only one Lynch-Bell number, `1`, since all other numbers either repeat digits or contain a 0.

### Examples

```
Input > Output
2 > 1
3 > 2
4 > 6
5 > 10
6 > 10
7 > 75
8 > 144
9 > 487
10 > 548
```

*Mathematica Online ran out of memory above base 10. You can use the following code to generate your own:*

```
Do[Print[i," > ",Count[Join@@Permutations/@Rest@Subsets@Range[#-1],x_/;And@@(x\[Divides]FromDigits[x,#])]&[i]],{i,10,36,1}]
```

### Winning

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Why do we need a dictionary? We don't need to output in that base.

Comment: @BetaDecay That will turns the problem into a kolmogorov-complexity one.

Comment: @user202729 Yep, I've edited it now

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Sorry I didn't read the problem specification carefully. Output ... in base `n`.

Comment: could you add an example `>10`?

Comment: The output does not actually need to be in base `n`, right? ("...output how many Lynch-Bell numbers there are in base `n`" appears to have caused some confusion.)

Comment: @JonathanAllan I see, I've cleared that up now

Comment: If only [2-36] need be supported we may as well list them all.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/129773/31716), [also related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/59014/31716)

Comment: That I've said, `No, up to 36 should be fine` will turns the problem into a kolmogorov-complexity one.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A034838 may be helpful.

Comment: Turns out that no one has managed to calculate `f(36)`. Make a fastest-code challenge based on this would be probably interesting.

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
Q⁼g
*`Ṗ©bç"®S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9qZWxsef//UeKBvGcKKmDhuZbCqWLDpyLCrlP///8z)

Another *O(n<sup>n</sup>)* solution.

### Explanation

```
Q⁼g  Helper link. Input: digits (LHS), integer (RHS)
Q    Unique (digits)
 ⁼   Match
  g  GCD between each digit and the integer

*`Ṗ©bç"®S  Main link. Input: integer n
*`         Compute n^n
  Ṗ        Pop, forms the range [1, n^n-1]
   ©       Store previous result in register
    b      Convert each integer to base n
     ç"    Call the helper link, vectorized, with
       ®   The register's value
        S  Sum
```

Comment: 16 bytes `ṖŒPḊŒ!€Ẏ⁼g¥"ḅ¥³S` and faster

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
*ḃ€’Q€Qḍḅ¥€⁸Ạ€S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/r4Y7mR01rHjXMDARSgQ939D7c0XpoKUioccfDXQuAjOD///@bAAA)

Complexity `O(nn)`.

Comment: Only in code-golf is an `O(N^N)` solution not only acceptable, but good.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Meh, I think we can pump those numbers up and get `O(N↑↑N)`

Comment: Should it be `O(N^(N+1))` because check the validity of each generated number takes `O(N)`? (although I don't understand Jelly)

Comment: @user202729 N+1 is just N in big-O notation.

Comment: @mbrig Of course I understand big-O notation, that (`N+1` is in `O(N)`) does not implies `N^(N+1)` is in `O(N^N)`.

Answer (score 3):

## Java, <s>222</s> <s>212</s> 190 bytes

-10 bytes thanks to Herman

-22 bytes thanks to Kevin

```
import java.util.*;a->{int c=0,i=1;A:for(;i<Math.pow(a,a);i++){Set g=new HashSet();for(char b:a.toString(i).toCharArray())if(!g.add(b)|b<49||i%a.parseInt(b+"",a)>0)continue A;c++;}return c;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
a -> {
    int count = 0;
    OUTER:
    for (int i = 1; i < Math.pow(a, a); i++) {
        Set<Character> found = new HashSet<>();
        for (char b : Integer.toString(i, a).toCharArray()) {
            if (!found.add(b) || b == 48 || i % Integer.parseInt(b + "", a) != 0) {
                continue OUTER;
            }
        }
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBRawIxDH72fkUmDNqdFge@zHqCDMYG88nH4UOu1zvrzrb0coqov/1W2YFgXpJ8yZd8yQ4POHZe213x25m9d4FgFzHRkqnFi0x8m9dGgaqxaWCFxsI5GfRgQ0jRHZwpYB9LbE3B2OpnAxiqht86B/dhZWsVGWfFRx/MvyzpSocR9MECSsg6HC/OxhKobDIy2atczkoXmDTzFdJWeHdkOEIuTZry81oTVJnVR/jEZhszxuWtW20xQD77drYS5P5lMRNpMXuPtWUIeGKcm5I9VQKLguX8ks@nb5eLeUbhMTQ6imJ5OhxG1mLClbNkbKthKVWaymvQ1AYLSl47eDCZJI/Q@tSQ3gvXkvBRC9WWlQK9r0@sv/2@8/a7n8mGcy6TwTW5dt30Dw)

Gets very slow for large numbers.

Comment: -10 bytes: `a->{int c=0,i=1;A:for(;i<Math.pow(a,a);i++){java.util.Set<Character>g=new java.util.HashSet<>();for(char b:Long.toString(i,a).toCharArray())if(!g.add(b)|b<49||i%Long.parseLong(b+"",a)>0)continue A;c++;}return c;}`

Comment: One of the first times I've seen a label used in a codegolf answer

Comment: `A:` and `continue A;` are 13 bytes while `{--c;break;}` is 12. Would that instroduce some bug I don't see?

Comment: This might be worth a separate answer, but you can loop through the digits in base n by each digit being `i%a` and `i/=a` at each loop. You can avoid the set by using an `int[]` and checking that `x[b]++<2`

Comment: `java.util.Set<Character>‌​g=new java.util.HashSet<>();` can be `import java.util.*;` + `Set g=new HashSet();`; `Long.toString` can be `a.toString`; and `Long.parseLong` can be `a.parseInt`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>86</s> <s>84</s> 77 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Ramillies*

```perl6
->\n{n-1+grep {.Set==$_&&.reduce(* *n+*)%%.all},map {|[X] (1..^n)xx$_},2..^n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtf1y4mrzpP11A7vSi1QKFaLzi1xNZWJV5NTa8oNaU0OVVDS0ErT1tLU1VVLzEnp1YnNxGoqiY6IlZBw1BPLy5Ps6JCJb5WxwjErv2fll@kAGRaKFQrFCdWKqRpqMRrKtT@BwA)

Works for n=8 on TIO.

Comment: I think you can save 2 bytes by doing `.all` instead of `all $_`.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>82</s> <s>79</s> 76 bytes

```
Count[Join@@Permutations/@Subsets@Range[#-1],x_/;x==x~FromDigits~#~GCD~x]-1&
```

Comment: How do you pass a number into this? (sorry, Mathematica is new to me)

Comment: Paste the function (e.g., to Wolfram sandbox), and then put `[<parameter>]` after that. With `parameter` being a number.

Comment: Can you add a TIO, or equivalent?

Comment: @Shaggy https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/025b270d-d293-4459-a8f4-2cfb7e769f21

Comment: Are f(5) and f(6) both really 10? That's odd...

Comment: @BetaDecay The link will likely to expire soon.

Comment: @user202729 Hm that's a shame

Comment: @BetaDecay It works for `2` and `10`.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Never mind, I was mistaken

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 24 bytes

```
;╗DR⌠╜DR╨i⌡M⌠;╜@¿♀%ΣY⌡MΣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/9/60dTpLkGPehY8mjoHSE9dkfmoZ6EvkA@UmONwaP@jmQ2q5xZHggTPLf7/3xwA)

### Explanation

This program consists of two main parts: the permutation generation, and the Lynch-Bell test. So, this explanation will look at each part separately, for greater clarity.

#### Generating Permutations

Input: `n` (an integer in `[2, 36]`)

Output: all partial and total permutations of `[1, n-1]` (sequences containing values from `[1, n-1]` without repetition whose length is in `[1, n-1]`)

```
;╗DR⌠╜DR╨i⌡M
;╗            store a copy of n in register 0
  DR          range(1, n)
    ⌠╜DR╨i⌡M  do the following for each element k in range:
     ╜DR        range(1, n)
        ╨       k-permutations of [1, n-1]
         i      flatten
```

#### Lynch-Bell Test

Input: a list of base-`n` integers, represented as lists of base-`n` digits

Output: the number of Lynch-Bell numbers in base `n`

```
⌠;╜@¿♀%ΣY⌡MΣ
⌠;╜@¿♀%ΣY⌡M   for each base-n digit list a:
 ;╜             duplicate a, push n
   @¿           convert a from base-n to decimal
     ♀%         modulo a with each of its base-n digits
       Σ        sum
        Y       boolean negation (1 if all modulo results are 0, else 0)
           Σ  sum (count the 1s in the resultant list)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 22 bytes

```
mLIBε0KÙ}ÙvyIöySIö%O_O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/18fT6dxWA@/DM2sPzyyr9Dy8rTIYSKj6x/v//28OAA)

`O_O` was also my face when this finally worked.

`<ÝIBJ0Kæ¦Ù€œ˜` is faster than the way I use to generate the numbers in the actual answer but randomly stops working for anything bigger than 7 (for no apparent reason?)

#### Explanation

```
mLIBε0KÙ}ÙvyIöySIö%O_O # (input = i)
m                      # Push i^i
 L                     # ...and get a range from one to this value
  IB                   # Map every element to their base i representation
    ε   }              # Map every element to ...
     0K                 # Itself without 0s
       Ù                # ...and only unique digits
         Ù             # Uniquify the resulting list
          v            # For each element...
           yIö          # Push it converted to base 10
              ySIö      # Push every digit of it converted to base 10 in a list
                  %     # Calculate the modulo for each digit
                   O    # Sum all results together
                    _   # Negate: Returns 0 for every positive number and 1 for 0
                     O  # Sum with the rest of the stack (Basically counting all Lynch-Bell-Numbers)
                       # Implicit print
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure a different approach can save more bytes, but in your current solution `ε0KÙ}` can be `0м€Ù` to save a byte.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 5, <strike>80</strike> 76 bytes (75 + `-p`)

```
$\+=!grep$_?$;%$_|$|{0,$_}++:1,@@until($@[$}++]+=1)%=$_ and++$;,$}=$}==$_}{
```

Abusing [`$;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$SUBSEP) for fun and profit. Times out on inputs > 8.

EDIT: -4 bytes by merging the two loops.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>80</s> 65 bytes

```ruby
->n{(1..n**n).count{|i|(d=i.digits n)-[0]==d|d&&d.sum{|j|i%j}<1}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLDkAwEADQq9iQVmKClYW6iFhgfEZiCO1COj17vfe46YuriUXHXlUAnOesYb4cWy8kCg0B0kb2TVgXfTkYg4JZhvC608shlB6hrUKIqgZoNCzjvHuxcidrb4cQfw)

Thanks to G B for -15 bytes.

Comment: This won't work for n>10 (because of "j.to_i")

Comment: Good catch, too bad it times out well before that :)

Comment: Anyway: you could call "digits" passing the base as argument and save a lot: ` ->n{(1..n**n).count{|i|(d=i.digits n)-[0]==d|d&&d.sum?{|j|i%j}<0}}`

Comment: Indeed I absolutely missed that digits has this parameter. But I see you had posted this as a separate answer and then deleted. I'd say, go ahead, you beat me to it :)

Comment: I think my answer is too similar, it's the same approach with a couple of shortcuts, mostly stolen code.

Comment: OK, then thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-x`, <s>25</s> 19 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)

```
pU õìU ËeDâ f myDìU
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/vyBU4fDWw2uAZHeqy@FFCmkKuZUuQP7//2ZcuhUA)

Comment: [20 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/vyBU4fDWw2uA5IrDHakRhxcppCnkVkYARf7/jzbSMdYx0THVMdMxj@XSzQUA)?

Comment: Or [19 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/vyBU4fDWw2uAZHeqy@FFCmkKuZUuQP7//2ZcuhUA) with the `-x` flag.

Comment: wow O_o i'm clearly terrible at golfing japt

Comment: You're doing well so far :) It takes time to get to grips with a new language, figure out all its features, tricks & quirks.

Comment: @Shaggy but when you use a new language as often as I do it should be expected that I'd be closer to optimal than like 25% XD

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>204</strike> 174 bytes

```python
lambda x,r=range,i=chain:sum(0**any(int(''.join(map(str,y)),x)%z for z in y)for y in i(*map(permutations,i(*[combinations(r(1,x),e)for e in r(x)]))))-1
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BbsIwEETPzVf4UmUduQjTG1L4kcLBUAcWYa@1WaQYxLendnplTqPRm9GkLBeK3/PAFBSKZyG6jQpDIpauGfr9fHPh@OvUZLhnF8/eYH@6OIzb8R5g3XUuZsAo0LarK2GE4BKMwiZrbSb9@VADsXoojCrranO1CF3lkudwFydIcTQl@zlROGL8D4DBlgXjl5qvNYZJH3TRl23eX54riwtbz8LGWKu3zUfi5eNz/ep3T/tqV4ULTgCNGgDL4vwH)

For each permutation of each element of powerset of range(1,n) (no zeros, unique), convert to numerical string to base n. Sum all that are divisible by each digit, subtract 1 due to powerset generating the empty set.

-30 bytes thanks to @ovs!

Comment: [184 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY7LasMwEEXX9VdoUzwyionSXcD9kkIZp3IywXownoCVkG93LHebWd2Bcy43ZbnE8LUMHL0icSwxjpMinyJLUw3dzzKi7/9QzYY7xnB2hrrTBSm0xfktDvajO043D/umwZCBgkBdt9dIATwmmIRN1trM@vOuhsjqriiorEvMJdKGJcf@JigUw2QITtH3FP5fYLCrbtzmuOIwzLrczlbvxy8FpQ0ts@FgrNXH6iPxtu@xf3bfD/us25XzKEBGDUBr4/IC)

Comment: [174 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY7BbsIwEETPzVf4UmUduQjTG1L4kcLBUAcWYa@1WaQYxLendnplTqPRm9GkLBeK3/PAFBSKZyG6jQpDIpauGfr9fHPh@OvUZLhnF8/eYH@6OIzb8R5g3XUuZsAo0LarK2GE4BKMwiZrbSb9@VADsXoojCrranO1CF3lkudwFydIcTQl@zlROGL8D4DBlgXjl5qvNYZJH3TRl23eX54riwtbz8LGWKu3zUfi5eNz/ep3T/tqV4ULTgCNGgDL4vwH)

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 117 bytes

```hs
f n=sum[1|x<-id=<<[mapM(\_->[1..n-1])[0..m]|m<-[0..n]],all(\y->[mod(sum(zipWith((*).(n^))[0..]x))y|c<-x,c==y]==[0])x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcuxDsIgFEDRX2FweJhCyuTC8w@cHejTkNamRKDE1oQa/h2r2x3umezyfHhf68giLu9gVMlauAG1NsGmC3R3cTZKyigUcdNKGagELX4ViRrrPXTbvoR5gN3Dx6WrWyeAI5cQb/xvKHO@lV6L3PSIGyGalnimGqyLDFl6ubiyAxvZqX4B) Works on TIO up to `n=7` before timing out.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 108 + 1 (`-p`) = 109 bytes

```perl
while(@a<$_){$r=%k=@a=();for($t=++$i;$t;$t=int$t/$_){push@a,$t%$_}$r||=!$_||$i%$_||$k{$_}++for@a;$r||$\++}}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxRCsIwEETPImwgJVbrR0FoF3IBbyCEfFQaWpqQrviR5OquqTAw8OYxYYprz/yZ3TpJbUcwTYKIYkFtUTbDy0cJhEqBG4Bq0G0EdD288N5nbc9AAkyBmDOewOQMTvxrSRUrVR@0HY4ZnkqVkpjvXx/I@W3n9tFfulvHbfgB)

It's a pig.  Not sure if it will do more than base 8 on TIO without timing out.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 144 bytes

```cs
n=>{int j,i,p;for(j=i=0;i++<~0UL;){p=i;var a=new List<int>();for(;p>0;p/=n)a.Add(p%n);j+=a.All(c=>c>0&&i%c<1&a.Count(x=>x==c)<2)?1:0;}return j;}
```

Goes through all the numbers from 0 to `ulong.MaxValue`, and selects those that are Lynch-Bell numbers in the specified base. Takes forever to run, even for 2, though if you set the `~0UL` part in the for loop to something smaller, you can get output for input up to 7 within a minute on TIO.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY5NS8QwGITv/RVhYbsJrTXrSTZ9IyIKCwXFD7zsJaQppi1vQ5rqQql/vWY9DMwDw8zo8UqPdn2aUJcWQx4lG1gR5BwtaXObO9EMnrZggQubZeUv/6gEmx1Y8a08UYDmh1R2DJcCSdl/XDjJhbsGZKq4r2vqtshEm0GkvqcapJY8Te1Wl/tUFQ/DhIGeQZ4BNCtv2N3@wMXiTZg8klYsq0hiq1H6i142O2KRHLF4Nap@Hx6xpqx4c70NdHfCHWPJnHx6G0xl0dDNEd0UyIHMfDnh8xQiRdhH2ORd3tB4u3hRfjS0Y4yJZFlv/wA)