# Excludivisible numbers

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic, integer

Given an integer `N`, output the `N`th positive number `K` with the following property in decimal base:

For each digit `I` at position `P` of `K`, the number formed from `K` by removing the `P`th digit (i.e. `I`) is divisible by `I`.

#### Example and remarks

`324` is such a number:

- `3` divides `24`
- `2` divides `34`
- `4` divides `32`

**Note 1:** we assume that the empty number is divisible by anything, like `0`. Therefore `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8` and `9` are valid.

**Note 2:** `K` cannot contain the digit `0`, since you cannot divide by `0`.

#### Inputs and outputs

- You may take the input as a function argument, through `STDIN`, etc.
- You may return the output from a function, through `STDOUT`, etc.
- You may index those numbers starting from `0` (in which case `N >= 0`) or from `1` (in which case `N > 0`), whichever suits you more.

#### Test cases

Those examples are indexed from `0`, so if you indexed from `1`, then add `1` to the numbers in the `N` column.

```
N    Output
0    1
4    5
8    9
15   77
16   88
23   155
42   742
47   1113
121  4244
144  6888
164  9999
```

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Here are [an implementation by @LeakyNun](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30327884#30327884) and [by @FryAmTheEggman](https://repl.it/C1WF) (both in Python) if you want more test cases.

Comment: [The first `10000` excludivisible numbers](http://pastebin.com/H2mK0kSu).

Comment: [The first `100000` (`1e5`) excludivisible numbers](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kckennylau/fac6fa657fc786461c7605d84df3ace7/raw/5b6787951db9adc8e06ef657bb997585d0eb4ab5/Excludivisible%2520Numbers%2520(PPCG-Q82864)).

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/41902/42963).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>21</s> 19 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
DLR©œ^€®ịDḌḍ@DPȧµ#Ṫ
```

Input is 1-indexed. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=RExSwqnFk17igqzCruG7i0ThuIzhuI1ARFDIp8K1I-G5qg&input=MTIy)

#### How it works

```
DLR©œ^€®ịDḌḍ@DPȧµ#Ṫ  Main link. No arguments.

                µ    Convert the chain to the left into a link.
                 #   Read n from STDIN and execute the link to the left for
                     k = 0, 1, 2, ... until n value return a truthy value.
D                      Convert D to base 10 (digit array).
 LR                    Construct the range from 1 to the length of the digit array.
   ©                   Copy the range to the register.
       ®               Yield the value of the register.
    œ^€                Take the multiset difference of each element of the range
                       and the range itself.
        ịD             Index into the digit array.
          Ḍ            Convert each list of digits to integer.
                       This yields all numbers with one suppressed digit.
           ḍ@D         Test each of these numbers for divisibility by the
                       suppressed digit from the digit array.
              P        Take the product of the resulting Booleans.
               ȧ       Logical AND with k (k would return 1).
                  Ṫ  Tail; extract the last (nth) element.
```

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 20

```
e.f!s.e.x%s.D`Zksb1`
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=e.f%21s.e.x%25s.D%60Zksb1%60&input=15&debug=0) or run the [Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=e.f%21s.e.x%25s.D%60Zksb1%60&input=15&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A5%0A9%0A16%0A17%0A24%0A43%0A48%0A122%0A145%0A165&debug=0)

N is 1-indexed for this answer.

Uses largely the same logic as my python script. Notable differences are using `.D` to delete the digit from the string during the test and using exception handling to deal with zero digits.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 26 bytes

```
e.f&!/J`Z\0!s%VsM.DLJUJjZT
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=e.f%26%21%2FJ%60Z%5C0%21s%25VsM.DLJUJjZT&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A5%0A9%0A16%0A17%0A24%0A43%0A48%0A122%0A145%0A165&debug=0)

```
e.f&!/J`Z\0!s%VsM.DLJUJjZT
e.f                          The n-th number (Z) where:
    !/J`Z\0                      Z does not contain "0"
   &                             and
           !s                    the following does not contain zero:
               sM.DLJUJ              generate the set of the digits removed
                       jZT           all the digits
             %V                      modulus in parallel
                                     if Z is 324,
                                     the first set would be [24,34,32]
                                     the second set would be [3,2,4]
                                     the third set would be [24%3, 34%2, 32%4]
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>82</s> <s>78</s> 76 bytes

```
f=(n,k=0)=>n?f(n-!eval(/0/.test(++k)+`${k}`.replace(/./g,"|'$`$''%$&")),k):k
```

Input is 1-indexed. Works by building up a string of the form `false|'24'%3|'34'%2|'32'%4` and evaluating it. Strings are used because they are still syntactically valid in the single-digit case.

The recursion limits this to about n=119. Iterative version for <s>88</s> <s>84</s> 82 bytes:

```
n=>{for(k=0;n;n-=!eval(/0/.test(++k)+`${k}`.replace(/./g,"|'$`$''%$&")));return l}
```

Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Dennis♦.

Comment: ``"|'$`$''%$&"`` saves two bytes.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks, I knew there had to be a better way to handle that edge case.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 93 bytes

```python
n=input();r=0
while n:r+=1;k=t=1;exec't&=(r/k/10*k+r%k)%(r/k%10or r)<1;k*=10;'*r;n-=t
print r
```

*Very* inefficient. Input is 1-indexed. Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/p7mOWN).

#### Alternate version, 100 bytes

The above code performs roughly **10<sup>x</sup>** divisibility tests where only **x** are required. At the cost of only **7 extra bytes**, efficiency can be improved dramatically, either by replacing `*r` with `` *len(`r`) `` or by refactoring the code as follows.

```python
n=input();r=0
while n:
 r+=1;k=t=1
 for _ in`r`:t&=(r/k/10*k+r%k)%(r/k%10or r)<1;k*=10
 n-=t
print r
```

This handles all test cases with ease, even on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/iqf7Nr).

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 90

```
f=->n,s=?0{0while s.next![?0]||s[1]&&/t/=~s.gsub(/\d/){eval"#$`#$'%#$&>0"};n<1?s:f[n-1,s]}
```

Similar approach to Neil's Javascript answer, but significantly longer due to a lack of implicit type conversion (except that booleans do get converted into strings by `gsub`, which is nice).

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 109 bytes

```
->n{i=s=1;n.times{s=?0;s="#{i+=1}"while s[?0]||(0...x=s.size).any?{|i|(s[0,i]+s[i+1,x]).to_i%s[i].to_i>0}};s}
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Hoon](https://github.com/urbit/urbit), 246 bytes

```
=+
x=0
|=
n/@
=+
k=<x>
=+
%+
levy
%+
turn
(gulf 0 (dec (lent k)))
|=
a/@
=+
(trim +(a) k)
=+
(rash (snag a p) dit)
?:
=(- 0)
|
=(0 (mod (fall (rust (weld (scag a p) q) dem) x) -))
(curr test &)
?:
=(- &)
?:
=(0 n)
x
$(n (dec n), x +(x))
$(x +(x))
```

Ungolfed:

```
=+  x=0
|=  n/@
=+  k=<x>
=+  %+  levy
  %+  turn  (gulf 0 (dec (lent k)))
  |=  a/@
  =+  (trim +(a) k)
  =+  (rash (snag a p) dit)
  ?:  =(- 0)
    |
  =(0 (mod (fall (rust (weld (scag a p) q) dem) x) -))
(curr test &)
?:  =(- &)
  ?:  =(0 n)
    x
  $(n (dec n), x +(x))
$(x +(x))
```

This...is really terrible. I feel dirty for posting this.

Set `k` to the string form of the current number, map over the list `[0...(length k)-1]` splitting the string at that index (`a`). Get the `a` character, parse it to a number, and if it's `0` return no. Get the prefix of `a` and weld it to the other half of the split, parse to a number, check if the index divides it evenly.

`++levy` returns yes iff calling the function on all the elements of the list is also yes. In this case, the function `++test` curried with yes, so it checks that all of the characters in `k` work.

If we're at the 0th value, we return the current number, or else we recurse with n decremented (and increment `x`)

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 199 bytes

```lua
n,m=1,...function e(n)for i=1,#n do x=n:sub(1,i-1)..n:sub(i+1)s=n:sub(i,i)if x==""or s=="0"or x%s~=0 then return x==""end end return true end while m+0>0 do n=n+1 m=m-(e(""..n)and 1 or 0)end print(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU7tCsIwDHyVUBFa1pUWBEGo7zJdxwIuk37gfvnqNXX7EZK73OXyKkOtpBfvtDFmKvTMuBIESWpaIyDzJ4Jxhc3TLZWHdBp7p4zZEXZOpWODGhVOLPRCsDVxt23YzunrLeQ5EMSQS6RdE2iEVgeXYwl//JnxFWDp7N22YPLUOVj80ssgheBkNbDKAZ@2qhneESnzw7XWy/UH)