# Is it a Self-divisor?

Tags: code-golf, math, division

## Task

Write a function or program that takes `n` as a parameter and prints the first `n` self-divisors.

## Definition of Self-divisor

A positive integer is called a “self-divisor” if every decimal digit of the number is a divisor of the number, that is, the number is evenly divisible by each and every one of its digits.

#### Example

For example, the number 128 is a self-divisor because it is evenly divisible by 1, 2, and 8. However, 26 is not a self-divisor because it is not evenly divisible by the digit 6. Note that 0 is not considered to be a divisor of any number, so any number containing a 0 digit is NOT a self-divisor. There are infinitely many self-divisors.

## Scoring

This is code-golf, so the shortest answer in bytes wins

Comment: This seems really familiar, I'm pretty sure I've golf this challenge here before, or at least one that determines if a number is a self-divisor, but I'm not finding it now.

Comment: Are we allowed to take the `index - 1`, as per [tag:sequence] defaults? (Or simply output the whole sequence)

Comment: @xnor I believe that is [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/41902/is-a-number-divisible-by-each-of-its-digits). Duplicate?

Comment: @dingledooper Thanks, too bad SE search doesn't show that on the first page of "divide digit".

Comment: I think this is a duplicate because the additional part of "output the first n" isn't enough to make it different. People should feel free to reopen if they feel otherwise. I guess there's an argument that the other question is too old and has weird rules?

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 16 bytes

05AB1E probably has some sort of slice, but I failed to find it.

```
∞ʒDSÖß}ʒ0å_}ηs<è
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9vc2FiaWX//@KInsqSRFPDlsOffcqSMMOlX33Ot3M8w6j//zM)

## Explanation

```
∞                [1, 2, 3, ...]
 ʒ               Filter all that satisfies:
  DS                 its DigitS
    Ö                is divisible
     ß}              ßy the original number.
       ʒ         Filter out ^ that satisfies:
        0å_}         0 is å digit of the output.
            ηs<è Trunctuatè by the input.
```

Comment: I think this is missing `1` in the output

Comment: @mathjunkie Probably fixed.

Comment: 8 bytes in the legacy version of 05AB1E: [`µNDSÖPD–`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0FY/l@DD0wJcHjVM/v/fyBQA) (The second and fourth bullet-points of [this 05AB1E tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166431/52210) are relevant.) PS: `£` is what you were probably looking for?