# I'm thinking of a number (Robber's thread)

Tags: code-challenge, cops-and-robbers

> [Cop's thread here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/140793/56656)

In this [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge cops will think of a positive integer.  They will then write a program or function that outputs one value when provided the number as input and another value for all other positive integer inputs.  Cops will then reveal the program in an answer keeping the number a secret.  Robbers can crack an answer by finding the number.

Your job as robbers is to find that number.  Once found you can make an answer here detailing the number and how you found it.  You should link the original answer being cracked in your answer.

Your score will be the number of cracks with more being better.

Comment: Are "hunches" good enough to post here, instead of definite proof?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire You should know that your answer works for sure.

Comment: But I must know it, I don't have to prove it with the program given in the cops thread? Can I prove it otherwise, using math for instance?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Sure that's fine.  As long as you know your answer is correct.  You need not actually run the program if it takes too long.

Answer (score 9):

## [Java, by okx](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140805/16236)

Note: the original challenge to which this post answers has been deleted, it's however still accessible with the link to anyone having the privilege to see deleted answers. The explanations below include what the challenge was about.

**Number: `18`**

The code is effectively looking for primes with the form 11<sup>2<sup>*n*</sup></sup>-2.

By [this Wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_known_prime_number#The_twenty_largest_known_prime_numbers), we know that the 20th largest known prime number has 2,900,832 digits. No prime with the form 11<sup>2<sup>*n*</sup></sup>-2 are in that list, so that digit number will be our limit.

All numbers of the form 11<sup>2<sup>*n*</sup></sup>-2 that have at most that many digits have this constraint: `n < 22`. [Factordb tells us](https://factordb.com/index.php?query=11%5E(2%5E22)-2) that 11<sup>2<sup>22</sup></sup>-2 has 4,367,918 digits. This is proof enough.

The code by okx limits us to `n` above 6.

So, let's do the list:

11<sup>2<sup>*n*</sup></sup>-2 is factorizable for `n` = [7](https://factordb.com/index.php?query=11%5E(2%5E7)-2), [8](https://factordb.com/index.php?query=11%5E(2%5E8)-2), [9](https://factordb.com/index.php?query=11%5E(2%5E9)-2), [10](https://factordb.com/index.php?query=11%5E(2%5E10)-2), [11](https://factordb.com/index.php?query=11%5E(2%5E11)-2), [12](https://factordb.com/index.php?query=11%5E(2%5E12)-2), [13](https://factordb.com/index.php?query=11%5E(2%5E13)-2), [14](https://factordb.com/index.php?query=11%5E(2%5E14)-2), [15](https://factordb.com/index.php?query=11%5E(2%5E15)-2), [16](https://factordb.com/index.php?query=11%5E(2%5E16)-2), [17](https://factordb.com/index.php?query=11%5E(2%5E17)-2), [19](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+(11%5E(2%5E19)-2)+prime), [20](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+(11%5E(2%5E20)-2)+prime) and [21](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+(11%5E(2%5E21)-2)+prime) (factors proofs are on factordb.com and wolfram alpha; factordb has some proofs that wolfram alpha hasn't and vice-versa).

The only value `n` for which we can't prove the factorization is 18 ([factordb](https://factordb.com/index.php?query=11%5E%282%5E18%29-2), [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+(11%5E(2%5E18)-2)+prime)).

So (a) if there is a prime number of the form 11<sup>2<sup>*n*</sup></sup>-2 with `n > 6`, then (b) `6 < n < 22`, and (c) I proved each number with such `n` is composite except for 18, so (d) the prime we're looking for has `n = 18`.

Note that I don't exclude that 11<sup>2<sup>18</sup></sup>-2 is composite. I haven't proved that that number is a prime: I only proved that if the OP thought about that number, it can only be 18. If that number is indeed a prime, congrats to okx for finding it :-)

#### However

There are no proof that 11<sup>2<sup>18</sup></sup>-2 is the only number, though. It's the only number in the range of numbers for which we can currently prove the primality.

So I don't exclude the fact that one day someone might prove that 11<sup>2<sup>51</sup></sup>-2 or 11<sup>2<sup>124</sup></sup>-2 is prime.

I therefore believe that the original entry by okx is invalid because there are no such proof that for `n` between 19 and the (2<sup>31</sup>-1)<sup>2<sup>31</sup>-1</sup> (the theoretical limit of Java's `BigInteger`), there are no other primes.

Comment: 11^(2^51) - 2 is divisible by 7. Or any odd `n`.

Comment: And iff `n` is divisible by `5`, `11^(2^n)-2` is divisible by `23`.

Comment: There's some [connection to Pascal's triangle](http://ideonexus.com/2011/11/11/powers-of-eleven-day/) here. "Each row of Pascal’s Triangle sums to the set of exponents of two {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024…}, and that’s interesting.

What’s more interesting? The digits of each row represent an exponent of eleven {11, 121, 1331, 14641, 161051, 1771561…}"

Or maybe I'm seeing patterns where none exist

Comment: Sorry guys, I bruteforced my way here. I haven't analyzed in details ;)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire  Oh please, you could have let us go on a wild goose chase for a day or three ;)

Comment: @JollyJoker that's just from the binomial theorem: (10+1)^n = sum (nCr) 10^r

Comment: Damn, the original challenge got deleted. Am I required to delete this answer as well?

Comment: Probably you should.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I think you _should_ be okay.  The solution took the same amount of effort, regardless of the original post.

Answer (score 9):

## [Perl 6, by Ramillies](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140851/69059)

```
11
```

The function `series($x)` is simply the first 108 terms of the Taylor series for `e^x` evaluated at `i*(x % 8*π)`.  Since `e^2πi = 1`, this reduces to simply `e^ix`: the `% 8*π` serves only to bound the error of the truncated series.

The `∫` function integrates the provided `Callable` in the interval `[0,2π]` using the trapezoid method.  The integrand in question is `(e^ix)^11/(e^inx)`, or simply `e^(11-n)ix`.  This integrates to 0 in that interval for all `n != 11`.  At `n = 11`, the integrand reduces to simply `1`.  Hence the answer is `11`, and the desired output is `6.28`.

While `11` is the only answer in theory, the sampling in the integral is imperfect.  Consequently, any integer of the form `87931k+11` should work.

Comment: Very nicely done! You surprised me with the last paragraph however. I'll put it to some thought.

Comment: Ah, I now see the problem. I'm afraid I can't remove it however (even if I use intervals of different widths, you would use the product of the widths as a coefficient for your `k`)... Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 8):

## Python 3, [Erik Brody Dreyer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140841/72175)

#### Number: `105263157894736842`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v0LBViEzr6C0REOTq6AoM69EA4QrNLWMFGxBMkB2tK5hrHZFtIEVkNbU/P/f0MDUyMzY0NTcwtLE3NjMwsQIAA)

---

#### How?

Everyone's favorite tool: OEIS!

1. Go to [oeis.org](http://www.oeis.org)
2. Search ["last digit first doubles number"](https://oeis.org/search?q=last+digit+first+doubles+number&sort=&language=&go=Search)
3. Find [Entry A087502](https://oeis.org/A087502) entitled

   > Smallest positive integer which when written in base n is doubled when the last digit is put first.
4. Find the base 10 entry (105263157894736842)
5. Confirm it works

Comment: Can't comment on Erik's post due to lack of rep. Welp, can only hope he sees this :)

Comment: Not sure if I would have thought of OEIS in this case, but just a few days ago I saw [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lHDCAIsyb8)

Answer (score 8):

## [Tampio, fergusq](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140810)

**Number: `27`**

The program prints `nolla` for 27 and `"1" negatiivisena` for all other inputs. It times out on TIO, unfortunately, but works offline.

Whew, this was a fun one to work through. Wiktionary and [this Finnish dictionary I found online](http://www.suomienglantisanakirja.fi/liitt%C3%A4%C3%A4) actually helped a surprising amount, as a lot of Tampio syntax relies on inflection.

I first tried translating the program into Haskell-like pseudocode, but the "case system" of Tempio and how function calls worked kept tripping me up. Eventually, I ended up running all of the code from the definition of `sata` downward, which gave me surprisingly easily that `sata == 55`, and `funktio` wasn't difficult to reverse engineer from there as it was simple arithmetic that could be deduced from trial and error.

Comment: Can someone help me comment this on the original post, by the way? My rep is way too low for that - thanks!

Comment: I've left a comment on the original.

Comment: @WheatWizard thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## [JavaScript, by Eli R](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140884)

The number is `7464822360768511`

I first disabled the anti-debugging function (by overwriting `Function.prototype.constructor` to a function with evals any code except `debugger`) then debugged the guess function by stepping into it.

From what I understood the guess function initializes a random number generator on a fixed seed then generate a random number and compare it to the input. As the input isn't used in the random number generation it can be ignored allowing to skip directly to the result.

Comment: Amazing job. That's exactly how it works.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), [Erik the Outgolfer's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140800/59487)

**Number: `134`**

The following program:

```
5ȷ2_c⁼“ḍtṚøWoḂRf¦ẓ)ṿẒƓSÑÞ=v7&ðþạẆ®GȯżʠṬƑḋɓḋ⁼Ụ9ḌṢE¹’
```

can be cracked using the number `134`. This outputs `0` for all numbers except for `134`, which gives `1`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AXMAjP9qZWxsef//Nci3Ml9j4oG84oCc4biNdOG5msO4V2/huIJSZsKm4bqTKeG5v@G6ksaTU8ORw549djcmw7DDvuG6oeG6hsKuR8ivxbzKoOG5rMaR4biLyZPhuIvigbzhu6Q54biM4bmiRcK54oCZ////MTM0)**

---

## How did I find it?

TBH, I have no idea how it works. I have added `Ç€G` at the end and mapped over `[1...1000]` to see where the `1` is. Then, I ran  script to count the number of zeros before the `1`.

Comment: This just checks that `(500-x) choose (x)` is equal to `11087887200298332182662619677215658902328839774316188391031942332464244226619146288405430113510542767630`, which it is for `x=134` (as you found).

Answer (score 5):

## Ly, [LyricLy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140838/56725)

Answer: 239

I already wrote two Ly programs, so this wasn't too difficult.
I think I would have somehow used the result from the loop in case someone tries to remove it. BTW, the fragment `nI` means that it doesn't always terminate successfully.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2, Sisyphus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140904/48934)

```python
print~~[all([c[1](c[0](l))==h and c[0](l)[p]==c[0](p^q) for c in [(str,len)] for o in [2] for h in [(o*o*o+o/o)**o] for p,q in [(60,59),(40,44),(19,20),(63,58),(61,53),(12,10),(43,42),(1,3),(35,33),(37,45),(17,18),(32,35),(20,16),(22,30),(45,43),(48,53),(58,59),(79,75),(68,77)]] + [{i+1 for i in f(r[5])}=={j(i) for j in [q[3]] for i in l} for q in [(range,zip,str,int)] for r in [[3,1,4,1,5,9]] for g in [q[1]] for s in [[p(l)[i:i+r[5]] for p in [q[2]] for i in [r[5]*u for f in [q[0]] for u in f(r[5])]]] for l in s + g(*s) + [[z for y in [s[aprint~~[all([c[1](c[0](l))==h and c[0](l)[p]==c[0](p^q) for c in [(str,len)] for o in [2] for h in [(o*o*o+o/o)**o] for p,q in [(60,59),(40,44),(19,20),(63,58),(61,53),(12,10),(43,42),(1,3),(35,33),(37,45),(17,18),(32,35),(20,16),(22,30),(45,43),(48,53),(58,59),(79,75),(68,77)]] + [{i+1 for i in f(r[5])}=={j(i) for j in [q[3]] for i in l} for q in [(range,zip,str,int)] for r in [[3,1,4,1,5,9]] for g in [q[1]] for s in [[p(l)[i:i+r[5]] for p in [q[2]] for i in [r[5]*u for f in [q[0]] for u in f(r[5])]]] for l in s + g(*s) + [[z for y in [s[i+a][j:j+r[0]] for g in [q[0]] for a in g(r[0])] for z in y] for k in [[w*r[0] for i in [q[0]] for w in i(r[0])]] for i in k for j in k] for f in [q[0]]]) for l in [int(raw_input())]][0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVHtbuIwEHyV/IyTlS7@tivlSSzfKaIFDFESEhCCqn116nV8AlUoWs/srL0zTLfzfhzY4zHNYTh/f7uu70u3cdSXG9f4siekbfdFN7wXGbvJt206T39PpNiOc7EpwlC4cjnP0H8MxCdyTCRbwX5VjFX81eOfkVTVuHYmOK091YC0BErRgBCxUgusiVVxkAYrBcmRZ0CRFxwEQwzIcgk8VQ1CIquB4hRnwBGzBqjCGnGaliBQL8x6qzTr69qCRr0yoDXxvqgL9xlqmnYNuOm2nJ305KttPw9lWAM4JAsnx71/CvuvdM725m7YfcA9TIAxxaxzTHNqOw4URPwk2HzHLt9JM15W4YR/QXgLNW6RI8xK9vq6w351ScQ2C5osuLz48JnrkVui3V1ZLQRtu3tq3NLw4kLdeXd4O8SHm18r/scd4l2JguzujsxtPR9XA9cK@y@LPueviEOef5EcnyEf/W9Hnjz3dzHXmPT1Xximy7kk8ZYoeTwoU4JrK42xUjEqNOdaWCORl5pabhSzhjOhJNWKMqkNt4Ipy6PWSCmMVpZxqjk1Ms7YHw)

Answer:

```python
126437958895621473374985126457193862983246517612578394269314785548769231731852649
```

### Explanation

Slightly less convoluted:

```python
print~~[all(
	[len(str(l))==81 and str(l)[p]==str(p^q)
		for p,q in [(60,59),(40,44),(19,20),(63,58),(61,53),(12,10),(43,42),(1,3),(35,33),(37,45),(17,18),(32,35),(20,16),(22,30),(45,43),(48,53),(58,59),(79,75),(68,77)]
	]
	+
	[{i+1 for i in range(9)}=={int(i) for i in l}
		for s in [[str(l)[9*u:9*u+9] for u in range(9)]]
			for l in s + zip(*s) + [[z for y in [s[i+a][j:j+3] for a in range(3)] for z in y] for k in [[w*3 for w in range(3)]] for i in k for j in k]]) for l in [int(raw_input())]][0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU/LbsIwEDzDV@Rokz3EXj8r5Usst4rUVyAKaQJCUJVfp14biVaytTvjnfHOdD587kd5u01zPx6u19ANA1uvwvA2suUws4HztnWi6sbXquAwxbaldnr@4uvV6n0/VxN8Vf1YBWYa0J4DUw0olarwIJtUDYJ2VAVoJF6CIF4hKEkYiEUNmKsFpYm1IEiFEpCwbEAYqglntQZF88oVV@3K79aDpXnjwFoe16t06hTqu69FRfv2tO3cjR9vzPOftv1O2VnPH2/Dzz3ZknOFe3S/OT6lW/uYR49/bWL6pGgGopeqri79xDYLT10Il6w4Z7sl9HUXw/ZpW2Nx6h5OyAt1Iepc@l3Z4rTBDE//puNj7V1ut7mNseTJ2wQKOHenl36cjgfGkyo08XYT0ii0XjvntZFCWUSrvNPEays8OiO9Q6mMFtYIqa1Dr6TxmGad1spZ4yUKi8LppPG/)

Firstly, this part:

```python
[len(str(l))==81 and str(l)[p]==str(p^q)
        for p,q in [(60,59),(40,44),(19,20),(63,58),(61,53),(12,10),(43,42),(1,3),(35,33),(37,45),(17,18),(32,35),(20,16),(22,30),(45,43),(48,53),(58,59),(79,75),(68,77)]
]
```

checks if the sudoku is in the following form:

```python
.2.|...|...
...|6..|..3
.74|.8.|...
-----------
...|..3|..2
.8.|.4.|.1.
6..|5..|...
-----------
...|.1.|78.
5..|..9|...
...|...|.4.
```

Then this part checks for validity:

```python
[{i+1 for i in range(9)}=={int(i) for i in l}
        for s in [[str(l)[9*u:9*u+9] for u in range(9)]]
            for l in s + zip(*s) + [[z for y in [s[a][j:j+3] for a in range(3)] for z in y] for k in [[w*3 for w in range(3)]] for i in k for j in k]]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth, Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140797/41024)

```
hqQl+r@G7hZ@c." y|çEC#nZÙ¦Y;åê½9{ü/ãÑª#¤
ØìjX\"¦Hó¤Ê#§T£®úåâ«B'3£zÞz~Ð£ë"\,a67Cr@G7hZ
```

[Try it here.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hqQl%2Br%40G7hZ%40c.%22+y%08%7C%C3%A7%C2%85%C2%87EC%23nZ%C3%99%C2%A6Y%3B%C3%A5%C3%AA%C2%BD%C2%819%06%7B%C3%BC%2F%C3%A3%C3%91%C2%8A%C2%AA%23%06%C2%95%12%C2%A4%0A%C3%98%C3%AC%1AjX%5C%22%C2%8E%0F%C2%93%C2%A6H%C3%B3%C2%90%C2%A4%C3%8A%23%1D%0B%1D%C2%A7T%C2%85%C2%A3%04%07%10%C2%99%1D%C2%AE%18%C3%BA%C3%A5%C2%91%C3%A2%0B%C2%91%C2%ABB%14%273%C2%A3z%C3%9Ez~%C2%81%C3%90%16%C2%A3%C3%AB%19%22%5C%2Ca67Cr%40G7hZ&input=9&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10&debug=0) Number: `9`

Comment: Well done! It lived long

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I just removed the `hqQ` part :p

Comment: That's weird. I tried 9 but it didn't work. That was before it was temporarily deleted, though, so it may not originally have been 9.

Comment: @Shaggy Me too, but after it was undeleted.

Answer (score 3):

## [Swift 3, TheIOSCoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140808/59487)

**Number: `387849`.**

This returns `222` for the number above, and `212` for others.

**[Test Here.](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59a461bddcc75d533468baac)**

---

## How?

The relation is quite obvious: `.pi*123456.0` multiplies `3.1415...` by `123456.0` and converts it to an Integer. This means it is equal to `387848`. Then, it checks if the parameter equals the number above incremented by `1` (`n==1+...`). The value is `387848 + 1`, which is `387849`...

Answer (score 3):

## [Java, Sleafar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140945/69059)

```
23
```

The program traces `n` iterations of a fractal, and checks whether a specific point is removed in the `n`th iteration.  In each iteration, each segment is replaced by eight smaller segments in the following pattern:

```
  +
  |
+-+
|
+-+-+
    |
  +-+
  |
  +
```

Since no points are ever added to the line `y=.5` after the first iteration, I only had to handle the set of points included along this line.  This set is similar to the construction of the Cantor set, but with the middle half removed instead of the middle third.

The program I used to crack it:

```java
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Main {

        public static int f(BigDecimal x) {
                BigDecimal[] result = x.divideAndRemainder(BigDecimal.ONE);
                if (result[0].compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0 || result[0].compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(3)) == 0) {
                        return 1+f(result[1].multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(4)));
                }
                return 0;
        }

	public static void main(String[] args) {
		BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(args[0]);
		System.out.println(f(x));
	}
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVHBToQwFDzTr3jHEmMD6GWz4aBxj0qy68kNhwoFi20hpSAbl2/Hkt0NqBjn8pK@mel0WtCWXpcVU0X6PgxcVqU2UNhDIql5I/c8f2AJl1SsEaqaV8ETSASta3ikXMEnQnDGeVkbauzgykCGJzV0riXDD0z7fQya1Y0wEEJHUt7ylN2pdMukvSZlemZFoqeNu/7lxTPAJ4u9F5OklBXV7LmcC18228iFMAQPjkf4h9xS0bAowzfuSbKU/wLNTKMV@FfZJYIfE2knr8RhyfTWdRee0KM/jL2J2yPkfK@6LXkKY014ZzRXua2S6rwe8zrO/AdstYp9zErHI88WYKM4zu5QGyZJ2RhSWRsjFM5wN8Z0etQPw0D8lR8EwSrwvwA)

Comment: This is correct, congratulations!

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, [flawr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140817/56725)

I think the number is 12018.

I found it by defining in PARI/GP `f(x,k)=1/x^2-1/x^(2-1/k)` and `g(k)=sumpos(x=1,f(x,k))-sumpos(x=12345679,f(x,k))` and some binary searching.

I don't like that one could trivially transform the program into one that returns the number and uses the same time and memory as the original program needs for any input.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak, Nitrodon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140875/56656)

The number is:

```
1574
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVAxDoAgDPxOb3Aw0biQfsQ46GBiNA6uxLdjC4gYkbsUerSXwnSMy17N27g6Z5gKqxfIggL2DBww6AGqBKRLrzwx@eTtwp6CxU3yXrHENwtL8ySfzO8jIY6UD5NYdnzCr/2rKoiGLcXHyPeJqtrPDvYwrJlUw2ofGXsyJIdzdds1Fw)

Here's the program I use to crack it

```hs
n!(0:_)=n
n!a=(n+1)!zipWith(+)a(tail a++[0])
main=print$0![45646,253224,392678,8676,-24]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoMwEADAe17RgIeEpJCucbWFvKMHCWUPgotxEc2pn48zK13bUkprok34/GwSJZqSEfey@s/Hl@tqnCVTicuDnJtDtmonlnScLLULeo4DRvQw9ADR92/AcfITjuifEHNrNw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Java, user902383](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/140793/im-thinking-of-a-number-cops-thread/140959#140959)

The secret number is `3141592`

Explanation:

After expanding all the `\u00xx` escapes, you get:

```
public class Mango {
static void convert(String s){for(char c : s.toCharArray()){ System.out.print("\\u00"+Integer.toHexString(c));}}
public static void main(String[] args) {int x  = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
double a= x/8.-392699;double b = Math.log10((int) (x/Math.PI+1))-6;
System.out.println((a/b==a/b?"Fail":"OK" ));
}}
```

(the `convert` method isn't used).

This computes some floating point math on the result, and then requires that `a/b` isn't equal to itself. The number for which that is true is `nan`, which is produced by `0/0`. It turns out that if `a` is 0, then `b` is `log10(0/pi + 1)` which is also 0, so `a` has to be 0 and x has to be `392699*8`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), [user71546](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144843/78410)

```
def check(x):
    if x < 0 or x >= 5754820589765829850934909 or pow(x, 18446744073709551616, 5754820589765829850934909) != 2093489574700401569580277 or x % 4 != 1:
        return "No way ;-("
    return "Cool B-)"

print(check(141421356237))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/BCsJADETv/YpYELqgkN1NNrtqPejdfxBtaVG6pVSsX19bevHinDLDC8m0n76KjR3He1HCrSpuj2xQuwQm1SUMcACE2E3DMQcWJm@QfRDH3gTPGCwFDDPRxnc2bEB7IidEKFYwMGun3eb/poJVDmY2PrCQIBJqdoE9GpHl8hpopvTy1ayu6F9dA@klwvv6gf02S5Pf/BzjE05blSZJ29VNny3FNGky2rIzVpQaxy8)

The number is **141421356237**.

The other three numbers which satisfy the first two conditions are 1459265341309891512760823, 5754820589765688429578672, and 4295555248455938338174086.

#### How I solved it

The gist of this challenge is to find the number that meets the following, given the prime `p = 5754820589765829850934909` and a value `a = 2093489574700401569580277`:

- `0 <= x < p`
- `x ** (2 ** 64) % p == a`
- `x % 4 == 1`

The second one can be rephrased to "find the [modular square root](http://www.mersennewiki.org/index.php/Modular_square_root) of modular square root of ... (64 times) of `a` modulo `p`."

Since the given prime is 5 modulo 8, we can use the following formula from the above link (though I couldn't find the reference that supports it):

\$ v = (2a)^{(p-5)/8} \mod p \$

\$ i = 2av^2 \mod p \$

\$ r = av(i-1) \mod p \$

\$ r' = p - r \$

Then we have two output values `r` and `r'` for an input value `a`. But not every number has such a square root, so we have to check if `r*r % p == a` is actually met.

So I wrote a quick J script to find the 64th modular square roots.

```
p =: 5754820589765829850934909x
a =: 2093489574700401569580277x
powmod =: p&|@^

f =: monad define
for. i.64 do.
  v =: p | (2*a) powmod (p-5)%8
  i =: p | 2*a*v*v
  x =: p | a*v*i-1    NB. Apply the above formula
  a =: (a=p|x*x) # x  NB. Filter by actually being the modular square root
  a =: a, p-a         NB. Concat r with r'
  a
end.
)

res =: f ''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZBdasQgFIXf7yoOLW1@mIhJNepAoHQBXUJBMIEMTJQppD6ka081NA8i5/su54q3/fOD4YmhmDBcC1zwewVHOntIAFJJoTsutVG91J3Rkps3YbiJZLPvctRGKqE4F7yVvZGad0pFCv7n7l0eCq/b@xdR3oC7X6yDG6d5GWnyD4aZ9QLOMwLWYxobyq62Ff4bytDI6kUnP58@6Xqt14TiiTKYmzah42GlHcIW61jhGfGE9oLQ2JxoXByjiugxfmczoSiOr6j2RKhsMUCk1hRyQ7r@AA)

`res` has the four values shown above; the last filtering by modulo 4 gives the answer.

Comment: Link to "module square root" is dead.