# Is it a Munchausen Number?

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem

A *Munchausen Number* in base \$b\$, also known as a [Perfect digit-to-digit invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_digit-to-digit_invariant) or PDDI is a peculiar type of positive integer where the sum of its base-\$b\$ digits raised to themselves is equal to the number itself. They are named for the fictional [Baron Munchausen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baron_Munchausen), who apparently hoisted himself up via his own ponytail to save himself from drowning. A related concept is [Narcissistic numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15244/test-a-number-for-narcissism).

For instance, \$1\$ is trivially a Munchausen number in every base because \$1^1=1\$. Additionally, every positive integer is a base-1 Munchausen number by definition.

More interestingly, \$3435\$ is a base-10 Munchausen number because \$3^3+4^4+3^3+5^5=3435\$, and in fact is [the only other base-10 Munchausen number](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.3038v2.pdf).

A partial list of Munchausen numbers in every base up to 35 can be found on the OEIS as sequence [A166623](https://oeis.org/A166623).

Given a positive integer \$n>0\$, determine if it is a Munchausen number in any base \$b\geq2\$.

### Rules

- Default I/O rules apply, so:

  - Full program or functions are acceptable.
  - Input can be from STDIN, as a function argument, and output can be to STDOUT, as a function return value, etc.
- Default loopholes apply.
- The output must be one of two distinct, consistent results. So `TRUE` is fine for truthy and `FALSE` is fine for falsy, but you can reverse that or return `None` for truthy and `1` for falsy or whatever. Please specify the selected results in your answer.
- Your answer has to work at least theoretically for any positive integer.
- Munchausen numbers use the convention \$0^0=1\$, so \$2\$ is a base-2 Munchausen number as \$1^1+0^0=2\$. Your code must follow this convention.
- Explanations are strongly encouraged, even though submissions will most likely use the brute-force search method.
- Using esoteric languages earns you brownie points since Munchausen was apparently a strange person.

### Test Cases

```
Truthy
1 (all bases)
2 (base 2)
5 (base 3)
28 (base 9 and base 25)
29 (base 4)
55 (base 4)
3435 (base 10)
923362 (base 9)
260 (base 128)
257 (base 64 and base 253)

Falsy
3
4
591912
3163
17
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in each language (in bytes) wins!

Comment: Can we assume the maximum base we need to calculate is 35/36?

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart no you may not; `determine if it's a Munchausen number in any base b≥2.`

Comment: How about just guessing "no."  There are a countably infinite number of integers and a provably finite number of Munchausens, so    probability of choosing a Munchausen number is   (n)/(Infinity) = 0 .   //ducks and runs

Answer (score 13):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
LвDmOQZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9o7HZ4gou9koKunYKS/X@fC5tccv0Do/7rxPw35DLiMuUysuAysuQyBTJMzbmMzAy4jE2MTbmMuUy4jA3NjLkMzQE)

The larger test cases will time out on TIO.

**Explanation**

```
L         # push range [1 ... input]
 в        # convert input to a digit list in each of these bases
  Dm      # raise each digit to the power of itself
    O     # sum each
     Q    # check each for equality with input
      Z   # max
```

Comment: How is this filtering base-1 from the results?

Comment: @Shaggy: With this base conversion, all numbers are **1** in base-1. The only number that will return true for `1^1` is **1**.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
bŻ*`§ċ⁸Ị
```

Yields `0` for Munchausen and `1` otherwise.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/p6G6thEPLj3Q/atzxcHfX////jSwA)**
Or [see the first five hundred positive integers split up](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9qZWxsef//YsW7KmDCp8SL4oG44buK/8OH4oKsVCxA4bifQMKlUv//NTAw) as `[[Munchausen], [non-Munchausen]]`.

#### How?

```
bŻ*`§ċ⁸Ị - Link: integer, n
 Ż       - zero-range -> [0,1,2,3,4,...,n]
b        - (n) to base (vectorises)
   `     - with left as both arguments:
  *      -   exponentiation (vectorises)
    §    - sums
     ċ   - count occurrences of:
      ⁸  -   n
       Ị - is insignificant (abs(x) <= 1)
```

---

Alternative for `1` for Munchausen and `0` otherwise:

```
bŻ*`§ċ>1
```

Comment: Um... why do I think that your previous version was valid and this one is invalid?

Comment: I think my previous version was invalid since it did not say that `1` was Munchausen.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>33</s></sup> <sup><s>28</s></sup> 27 bytes

```
e.1#.i.@>:^~@(#.inv ::1)"0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/U/UMlfUy9RzsrOLqHDSAzLwyBSsrQ00lg9j/mlypyRn5ChppSgaaCoYKRgqmCkYWCkaWCqamCsYmxqbI0sYKJgqG5grGhmbG/wE)

- `e.` is the input an element of...
- `1#.` the sum of each row of...
- `i.@>: ... ]` 0..input and the input itself, passed as left and right args to...
- `^~@(#.inv)"0` convert the right arg (input) to each base in the left arg and raise each result elementwise to itself `^~@`.
- `::1` finally this is needed because you can't convert uniquely to base 1, so it errors.  in this case, we simply return 1, which won't match for any number *except* 1, which is what we want

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>72</s> 69 bytes

-1 byte thanks to digEmAll

```r
function(x){for(b in 1+1:x)F=F|!sum((a=x%/%b^(0:log(x,b))%%b)^a)-x;F}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzRCsIwDEXf/Yr6UEhw4rJs00722s8YrIPKYHYwHRTUb6@6vOTe3JybJfk2@TUMz3EOEPHl5wWcGoOiAzURbWvf@8d6B@jbqE/adZA303yDmDlErR12PR7j1X7SAB4IM@Wh2GYl/iJiJJOQSxZjCuZa8KLORasz4u7/jLe9lKIhQwIy1XKhH5i@)

Outputs `TRUE` for Munchausen numbers and `FALSE` otherwise.

`x%/%b^(0:log(x,b))%%b)` converts `x` to base `b`, and the for loop does the rest of the work (reassigning `F`, which  is `FALSE` by default).

We need to allow the base `b` to go all the way to `x+1` instead of `x` to handle the case `x=1`.

Comment: [71 using a for loop](https://tio.run/##JYzBCoMwEETv/Yp4COyipW6iaWPxms8QjJAitBFshUDpt6ete9mZnX2zaw59DlucXvMSIeE7LCt4MUdBJXUJXe/K4rk9AMY@yZP0A9TdfblBqjyilB6HEY/pWrhPniAAYSUCqH227C8sljMOdaPZWKW1YVyZmrU9Ix7@z/S@N1y0ZIlBTYYv9APzFw "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @digEmAll Thanks! I shaved off another 2 bytes by using booleans instead of integers.

Comment: I was trying to understand what you changed to save 2 bytes from mine besides changing `+` with `|` and removing `!`, then I realized I wrote 71 but my code was actually 70 :D

Comment: Great idea using | BTW !

Comment: @digEmAll Oh yes, I didn't even think to check your byte count! :)

Comment: Redefining `F` as potentially `TRUE` seems even worse than using `F` as a counter...

Comment: ahah, yes... assigning F/T to other boolean values makes me really guilty :D

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES7), 60 bytes

Returns a Boolean value.

```javascript
n=>(F=b=>(g=n=>n&&g(n/b|0)+(n%=b)**n)(n)==n||b<n&&F(b+1))(2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hdBLbsIwEAbgPafIpskMUcnDITQS7jIn6A5Y2DSkRdYEYahUKXdPnQaF1K5aLyzr96cZj4/iQ@j9@f10eaTmteoOvCP@DCWXZq@5OZPv10CRbGMMgR64xPmcEAg5p7aVa3NfggwTREix2zekG1UtVFNDsHk5Xy9vn7sAZ9P8AAZ73yuKPBBKeVLoStsqnapeeKlNlg5hTpWnmxlJ4ZDCJpnTaPkvYRkb0EiS2DZFyljez/XHY/J4aHUvY0aY/VDBljalUPqXr2VoJ5mTsCR3WbJC7L4A)

#### Commented

```javascript
n =>                   // n = input
  ( F = b =>           // F = recursive function taking a base b
    ( g = n =>         //   g = recursive function taking an integer n
      n &&             //     if n is not equal to 0:
        g(n / b | 0) + //       do a recursive call with floor(n / b)
        (n %= b) ** n  //       and add (n mod b) ** (n mod b)
    )(n)               //   initial call to g with the original value of n
    == n ||            //   return true if the result is equal to n
    b < n &&           //   otherwise, if b is less than n:
      F(b + 1)         //     try with b + 1
  )(2)                 // initial call to F with b = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 bytes

```
õ@ìXÄ x_pZ
øN
```

Saved one byte thanks to @Shaggy

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9UDsWMQgeF9wWgr4Tg&input=NQ)

Comment: @Shaggy Fixed at the cost of a byte

Comment: You can get that byte back by replacing `ÃÃøU` with `<newline>øN`.

Comment: @Shaggy Nice trick with `N`, I never used it before!

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 51 bytes

```perl6
{?grep {$_==sum [Z**] .polymod($^a xx*)xx 2},^$_+2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHfCoIwFAfg@99TnIsR/onIc9zMC@k9ihQhlWCmTILJ8NnX962DsybOO51GamK4T25YKaiuabbfTM9Hlr3osi52n5d3otqevM9S74mPc6u6nI84Lo4S@/kOW0oBRFu/05jkqktxxAIMDb6Ba2gNKUWjZhHDYHMF6wqCElIYQVH9AQ)

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                                                 } # Anonymous code block
 ?grep {                                  }         # Do any
                                           ,^$_+2   # Of the bases from 2 to n+1
            sum                              # Have the sum of
                      .polymod($^a xx*)      # The digits of n in that base
                [Z**]                  xx 2  # Raised to the power of themselves
        $_==                                 # Equal to the original number?
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 50 bytes

TIO timed out on 591912. Somehow edges out Perl by 1 byte... (at time of writing)

```ruby
->n{(2..n+1).any?{|b|n.digits(b).sum{|d|d**d}==n}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBDoIwEADA@76CAAfA0NhdCnIAH6KGSBpIDxZiy4G0/bp15nvMZ1yGZ6xH7QpkTF94yd76vDs/e82kWpU1xVwyc3ycl15WlQzDoEOI@2FNkmb5NCaZWx75xOw2qVdIIwcEAXgD7EEIoIYE9EjUImB7BRQdEDRAvCXgHfy23apNm1jrPw)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (dzaima/APL)](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), <s>23</s> 13 bytes

```apl
⊢∊⊂+.*⍨⍤⊤⍨¨2…
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfyf9qhtgsb/R12LHnV0Pepq0tbTetS74lHvkkddS4CMQyuMHjUs@6/J9ahvKlBh2qEVhgpGCqYKRhYKRpYKpqYKxibGQJ6ZgYKRqTlCkbGCiYKxoZmxgqH5fwA)

Thanks to Adám, ngn and dzaima, we managed to shave 10 bytes off this answer by using dzaima/APL.

Prefix tacit function. Munchausen numbers return 1, else 0.

#### How

```apl
⊢∊⊂+.*⍨⍤⊤⍨¨2… ⍝ Prefix tacit function, argument will be called ⍵

             2… ⍝ Generate the integer sequence [2..⍵]
          ⊤⍨¨  ⍝ Convert ⍵ to each base in the vector
     +.*⍨⍤      ⍝ Raise each digit of each element in the vector to itself, then sum
⊢∊⊂            ⍝ Check if ⍵ is in the resulting vector.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 65 bytes

```
#<2||!Tr[Check[#^#,1]&/@#~IntegerDigits~i]~Table~{i,2,#}~FreeQ~#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBC4IwFMDxzxIPPL2obU4LKoQi6JbgTQyWPOaj9LDWSd1XX3b8w@/fG99Rbzy3JtpjhIOcplXl6nNH7auGB6Bokk0B4TZ4suQubNl/AjehMs83hZFRIszh6ojKAEm8Ox58UX6ZfA3rky3g/49iYRrlDuUetUaVqqWyLUqdo8IUlcgUinyO8Qc)

*-4 bytes from @attinat*

Comment: [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##FctBC4IwFMDxzxIPPL2obU4LKoQi6JbgTQyWPOaj9LDWSd1XX3b8w@/fG99Rbzy3JtpjhIOcplXl6nNH7auGB6Bokk0B4TZ4suQubNl/AjehMs83hZFRIszh6ojKAEm8Ox58UX6ZfA3rky3g/49iYRrlDuUetUaVqqWyLUqdo8IUlcgUinyO8Qc) which also included [some bugfixes](https://tio.run/##XY7LCoMwEEX3fkUgIFECPqBLQWg33fXhTiKkMmhoja1JV6Xz6zaWVmp3M@few0wnbQudtKqW48hC3VviADGyAzco3YSBtxuUtiWtKK5bqM8Y@@LD3vuU8Fh8YX507n5R5389j4VxFWdZQtjtDsaqXhNzhTqYjxVDlLOFFeVbbaGBYaMaZU1JeYoHqRtAKgKfEJKvxCz/PJZMKsWFjEpgIU8XwIfiKadP38nj@AI)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) `-lm`, <s>79</s> 75 bytes

```c
f(n,b,i,g,c){for(g=b=1;b+++~n;g*=!!c)for(c=i=n;c-=pow(i%b,i%b),i/=b;);n=g;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU7daoMwGL3PU9iCkNQjNUnjJlmeZOtFTZvwQRtLFQYT9@hzuvXunMP582X0fp4DT2hBiPBiDN2DR9c6aduiKL6TjTu32Xix6t6RS9aX7t59csqXTN4K0N61Vtjkop3m24kSFyOjNGTDpR/696MbmYSCgXqFamAM9EEbNErrWkHVFZR5AdM4wDSykQpa1hpy0SbL1t21jFxl6a2nr0sX@F@z2D9ZJSwVhWDZ/bE4A9/m9TnLzx9pi/8LdMQzs0AhLJsYm398uJ5iP5fX2y8)

Returns `0` for Munchausen numbers, and `1` otherwise.

---

#### also 75 bytes

```c
a,b;f(n){for(a=b=1;b+++~n;a*=g(n)!=n);n=a;}g(n){n=n?g(n/b)+pow(n%b,n%b):0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU5dS8MwFH3Pr6iDQq65Y02yVOs1@EN0D0m3lMCWjrUgWOpPt6a6hwvn6x5Ou@3adlkcego8wRT6G3fWW0leCPGdyD3aLhsPNgEl62he2ZRsestg50Fc@0@eSo/54KWiebm4mDhMLKaxGE/DOLwf7MQkKjSonlE1aAzqvTbYKK1rhaquUJknZBr3aBrZSIVa1hpl1mZi66a1LNqK4usQv0594H/NsLuzCigKAay43nIy8E1ZH4vy@JE2@D8hHvD@kyEAsZmx5acNZ9cNy/Z8@QU)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 17 bytes

```
Ｎθ¬Φθ⁼θΣＥ↨θ⁺²ιＸλλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oroCgzr0TDL79Ewy0zpwQkqKPgWliamFMMYgWX5mr4JhZoOCUWp4L4ATmlxRpGOgqZmppATn45UH2OjkKOJgRY//9vZGr@X7csBwA) Link is to verbose version of code. My 16-byte attempt didn't work but that might be a bug in Charcoal, so watch this space. Outputs `-` unless the number is a Munchausen number. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ                  Input `n` as a number
   Φθ               Try bases `2` .. `n+1`
       Σ            Sum of
         ↨θ         `n` converted to base
           ⁺²ι      Next trial base
        Ｅ           Each digit
              Ｘλλ   Raised to its own power
     ⁼              Equals
      θ             `n`
  ¬                 Logical Not
```

Comment: 16 bytes using the newer version of Charcoal on ATO: `Ｎθ⊙θ⁼θΣＥ↨θ⁺²ιＸλλ` [Attempt This Online](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iOSOxKDk_MWfBgqWlJWm6FjdDPfMKSkv8SnOTUos0CjWtuQKKMvNKNBzzKjUKdRRcC0sTc4pBrODSXA3fxAINp8TiVBA_IKe0WMNIRyFTUxPIyS8H6s7RUcjRBAPrJcVJycVQK5ZHK-mW5SjFLjYyNYeIAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs `-` for a Munchausen number, nothing if not.

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 99 bytes

```cs
n=>Enumerable.Range(2,n).Any(x=>{int g=0,t=n;for(;t>0;t/=x)g+=(int)Math.Pow(t%x,t%x);return g==n;})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hdDNS8MwFADw@/6KMBASrP1KVy0xBQ/upCAieJge0pJ2hfoKSYod4t9e45hzTREDubz83kdeqS9K3YzrHsrrBoxXdF2bV3wEnt9C/yaVKFrpPwqoJY49IP4N7PDA8w@LUc1Dz3BgVacwM3nITMAHUp9zbF/JvTBb/6F7x@Zs8OwlTEnTK7BpNueTjGzxrBoj7xqQeLl5Ur3Z7l6X5DRc4YgQhvYnCBAWbYsKoaUmExRP0DdA8VSs5oI6Na5@yFFkjshmInG6rP4TNKEHcxRROCVZTGm6/9Gfg6Thoc9vETv@4nSfL7BZi1bPF0qJE0jcAI3SGYoubWT8Ag)

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 61 bytes

```
_#0=0
b#n|m<-mod n b=m^m+b#div n b
f n=elem n$1:map(#n)[2..n]
```

Returns `True` for Munchausen and `False` otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcvBCoJAEIDhu08xsB6KJnFn3DWjfRKxUFSSnFEqOvXuW507/vD91/ZxG@Y5xovJQ550Rt9y2svSg0IX5Cy7zvTT61fJCBqGeRDQ1B6lXTdGtzVlmTZR2kkhQL8kAOt90iek8BUwQm2R0CEdkCp0DrlghxUxe0LyOZIrm/@JsUC2ntGWTfwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>83</s> 81 bytes

```python
def f(n,b=2):
 s=0;m=n
 while m:k=m%b;s+=k**k;m/=b
 return s==n or b<n>0<f(n,b+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYztCoMgFIb/exXCGGSNLbWP9eEups2RlBpqjK7eRSzszw4ceF7Oe55pcb1WxAs5aeOgXSxY92q5M/w5Gyu0GoUULsLpNsi/@Bu@I3XpGEE1gJaljWQKwE8vRg5lPTB57hqbsCGOh0beWAeg4W42au0yBbWBXaseabtJEoz8ZIRyqxMjsCO5H7hIQ6AZzUOqCKUF@VMlefkL4TtcMwROO@cVrvBBQ3FxaOIS@S8)

Returns `1` for truthy and `0` for falsey. Because of the recursion, can't practically deal with `591912`, but it works in the abstract.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>66</s> 65 bytes

```perl6
{$^a==1||[+] map {$a==[+] map {$_**$_},$a.polymod($_ xx*)},2..$a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZm@79aJS7R1tawpiZaO1YhN7FAoVoFyEdw4rW0VOJrdVQS9Qrycypz81M0VOIVKiq0NGt1jPT0VBJr/1tzpeUXKRjq6RkbKOjaKagkKlRzcRYnViooAZlAgeo0oFitkjVX7X8A)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 88 bytes

```
f=n=>{for(b=2;n-b++;){for(c=0,r=n;r;r=(r-a)/b)c+=(a=(r%b))**a;if(n==c)return 1}return 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 109 bytes

```
procedure m(n)
every k:=2to n&{i:=n;s:=0
while{a:=i%k;a<:=1;s+:=a^a;0<(i/:=k)}
n=s&return 1}
return n=1|0
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7RCsIwDEWf7VdEQWlx4Lrq1M58iSgUV7BMM@mmIuq3a1BBH0zI5ULIuQmbmh6PQ6w3vjxGD3tJSviTjxeoLGZtDTS4BotUNBZTcd6Gnb86i6FfFW5hURfN0KJbuyJdyDCyWKm7IGwG0bfHSKDv4uMI9S0VnsrfNBdIKgFc78xzDK1v5F52lzqBLIEJ64xnzpa9GRvWeWZMzsssT1km05VKoMf9Jr0YUnX@Y00CY@bonI3@XnZenz0B)

Times out for `591912`. [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon) treats `0^0` as an overflow and that's why I need an additional check for zero.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╡!←!║╝âñoêû►╦ä▓
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=b5211b21babc83a46f889610cb84b2&i=1%0A2%0A5%0A28%0A29%0A55%0A3435%0A260%0A257%0A%0A3%0A4%0A3163%0A17&a=1&m=2)

Takes very long for the larger test cases.

Explanation:

```
{^xs|E{c|*m|+x=m|a Full program, unpacked
                   Implicitly input x
{              m   Map over bases [1 .. x]
 ^                   Increment base (effectively mapping over [2 .. x+1])
  xs                 Tuck x below base
    |E               Get digits of x in base
      {   m          Map over digits:
       c|*             copy and power
           |+        Sum
             x=      sum = x?
                |a Check if any element in array is true
                   Implicit output
```