# Test if given number is a Reverse Keith?

Tags: code-golf, number

Slighty inspired by my previous challenge regarding [Keith Numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9319/test-if-given-number-if-a-keith-number/) I want to propose a challenge to create a function that takes an integer and gives back a true or false depending on the number is a Reverse Keith number or not.

A reverse Keith uses the same little algorithm as Keith numbers, but ends up with it's starting number in reverse.

For example 12 is a Reverse Keith number

> **12**
>
> 1 + 2 = 3
>
> 2 + 3 = 5
>
> 3 + 5 = 8
>
> 5 + 8 = 13
>
> 8 + 13 = **21**

Comment: Can a number ending in zero be a reverse Keith number?

Comment: Iszi I don't think so.

Comment: Bah. That's going to force a little bloat in the code.

Comment: For those needing test cases: http://oeis.org/A097060

Comment: I've got a couple of questions after looking at some older questions on this site: 1) I noticed that some solutions use command switches. Are these allowed and if so do they count against the length of the solution? The way codegolf.com worked, if I wanted to add the loop switch `-n` to a Perl script, I'd have to add `#!perl -n` to the first line, and thus adding 10 characters to the length of the solution. 2) When this assignment (and others) ask for a true/false value, is a 1/0 output acceptable for languages which don't use explicit true/false for boolean values?

Answer (score 3):

### APL (28)

```
⍙∊{1↓⍵,+/⍵}⍣{⊃⍺≥⍙∘←⍎⌽∆}⍎¨∆←⍞
```

Using more or less the same method as [TwiNight did in the other question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9326) but reversing the number.

Explanation:

- `∆←⍞`: read a line as text, store in `∆`
- `⍎¨`: evaluate each character
- `{1↓⍵,+/⍵}`: add the sum of the list to the end of the list, and drop the first item,
- `⍣`: until
- `{⊃⍺≥⍙∘←⍎⌽∆}`: the first item on the list is greater or equal to `⍙`, which is the evaluation (`⍎`) of the reverse (`⌽`) of `∆`.
- `⍙∊`: see if `⍙` is contained in the final list.

Comment: I always wonder how people can write APL.

Comment: @moose: you need a special keyboard layout

Comment: Not only the symbols ... you also have to know what the symbols mean. I can't even see control structures / loops / IO / variable declaration in that code.

Comment: @moose: It's not really hard. There's only about 80 symbols. They are visually distinct, most have at least a semi-obvious visual meaning, and even the ones that don't are internally consistent. For example, if you know that `⍎` is *eval*, it's not hard to remember that `⍕` is *format*. I find it a lot easier to read and write than Golfscript.

Comment: You used non-ascii even for variable names!!!(;°Д°)

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, <s>126</s> <s>111</s> 110 chars

```
$r=reverse$_=shift;$l=@n=split//;while(1){$t=0;$t+=$_ for@n[-$l..-1];push@n,$t;die"true\n"if$r==$t;last if$t>$r}die"false\n";
```

Should be some room for improvement.

Updated with tips from Dom Hastings:

```
$r=reverse$_=shift;$l=@n=/./g;push(@n,$t=eval join'+',@n[-$l..-1])&&$r==$t&&die"true\n"while$r>$t;die"false\n"
```

You forgot that `$t` isn't being assigned a value with your suggestion, so that adds 3 characters if I want to use that in the following comparisons (it's still cheaper than using `$n[-1]` twice). However, I can save those by changing `split//` to `/./g`.

Slight improvement:

```
$r=reverse$_=shift;$l=@n=/./g;push@n,$t=eval join'+',@n[-$l..-1]and$r==$t&&die"true\n"while$r>$t;die"false\n"
```

Replaced `&&` operators with lower precedence `and` to be able to drop parentheses around call to `push`. Saves one character.

Comment: Hi Flesk, thought I'd contribute a few extra savers:
changing:
    `$t=0;$t+=$_ for@n[-$l..-1];push@n,$t`
to:
    `push@n,eval join'+',@n[-$l..-1]`

saves a few bytes and changing:
    `die"true\n"if$r==$t`
to:
    `$r==$t&&die"true\n"`

-0 char change, but now can use another statement modifier, changing:
    `while(1){...last if$t>$r}`
to:
    `...while$r>=@n[-1]`

all those (and dropping the last semi-colon) should save you 15 chars in total!

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll definitely reuse `eval join'+'` in the future.

Comment: @DomHastings: I updated my answer with your suggestions.

Comment: Ah, nice catch with `split//` to `s/./g`, glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica <s>157</s> 96

```
f = (d = IntegerDigits@#; r = FromDigits@Reverse@d; 
NestWhile[Rest@Append[#, Tr@#] &, d, Max@# < r &][[-1]] == r) &
```

Based on code by [Anton Vrba](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/IntegerSequences/KeithNumber.nb) and considerably streamlined by @ssch.

```
f[11]  
f[12]
f[20]
f[24]
```

> False
> True
> False
> True

Comment: Something's wrong here. The numbers you have appear to be a series of Keith Numbers - not Reverse Keith Numbers. From [Wikipedia's article on Keith Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_number#Examples), under Examples: `14, 19, 28, 47, 61, 75, 197, 742, 1104, 1537, 2208, 2580, 3684, 4788, 7385, 7647, 7909...`. I don't know certainly about the rest, but I tested 14 and it definitely is *not* a Reverse Keith Number. Its progression jumps from 37 to 60, where it would need to pass through 41 to be a Reverse Keith Number. `1+4=5, 4+5=9, 5+9=14, 9+14=23, 14+23=37, 23+37=60`

Comment: Fair enough.  I grabbed the wrong code.

Comment: A real hint should have been when the "find all" bit didn't produce the example given in the question, 12. ;-)

Comment: I rolled back to an earlier, correct version.

Comment: You can drop it down to 93  `(
  d = IntegerDigits[#];
  r = FromDigits@Reverse@d;
  NestWhile[Rest@Append[#, Tr@#] &, d, Max@# < r &][[-1]] == r
  ) &`

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell: <strike>149</strike> 135

Mostly derived from my original [Keith Number Checker](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15243/9387). I'm sure there's still some work to be done.

```
$k=+(($j=($i=+(read-host))-split''|?{$_})[99..0]-join'');While($x-lt$k){$x=0;$j|%{$x+=$_};$null,$j=$j+$x}$x-eq$k-and$i-gt9-and$i%10-ne0
```

I definitely need to double-check for redundant parenthesis and semicolons. It's possible one of the casts to integer is unnecessary. One thing I might also need to spend time on is finding out if I can avoid false-positives without `-and$i%10-ne0`.

<strike>It'd be really nice if there was a reliable way to do a left-shift-and-append that's shorter than `$null,$j=$j;$j=@($j);$j+=$x`.</strike>

> **EDIT:** Found it! `$null,$j=$j+$x`

Cleanup $x between runs, and also $i, $j, $k when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

### Game Maker Language, <strike>129</strike> 136

Make this the function/script `f` and compile with uninitialized variables as 0.

```
a=argument0;while(a>0){b*=10b+=(a mod 10)b div 10}k[]=1k[1]=1while(k[c]<b){c+=1k[c]=k[c-1]+k[c-2]}while(e<c){e+=1if k[e]==b r=1}return r
```

It returns `true` or `false`; call with `f(any number you want)`

**Edit #1** Corrected invalid operators `%` and `/=` with `mod` and `div`.

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 106

This version only works for `0 < x < 100` though.

```
k x=(last$takeWhile((>=)x)(let f=(map(Data.Char.digitToInt)$reverse$show x)++zipWith(+)f(tail f)in f))==x
```

**TODO:** check up on [Test if given number if a Keith number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9319/test-if-given-number-if-a-keith-number/) and implement a proper algorithm.

Comment: So... this only works on the first 6 Reverse Keith numbers? Kinda weak.

Comment: yeah, I didn't really have the algorithm down yet when I wrote this, and since it was 3 AM I decided to call it quits.